# How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, clone, javascript-objects

I have an object `x`. I'd like to copy it as object `y`, such that changes to `y` do not modify `x`. I realized that copying objects derived from built-in JavaScript objects will result in extra, unwanted properties. This isn't a problem, since I'm copying one of my own literal-constructed objects.

How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: Definitely support @Niyaz! Shortlink: http://tinyurl.com/JSCopyObject

Comment: For JSON, I use `mObj=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));`

Comment: I really don't get why no one suggests `Object.create(o)`, it does everything the author asks?

Comment: @froginvasion Probably because it's not supported in IE8 and under.

Comment: @Wynand That's not a good argument at all. There are lots of polyfills for `Object.create` that can be found, as for instance: https://www.refheap.com/90006

Comment: @froginvasion Fair enough, although I could argue that OP wanted an "elegant" [_sic_] way and not everyone would necessarily agree that using a polyfill fits that description. I was just trying to provide you with _a_ possible reason why `Object.create` hasn't been suggested (if that's the case), which is why I wrote "Probably". Regardless, I'm in favor of polyfills and recently looked at [this](http://qr.net/HZCC) one incidentally, which is similar to your snippet. If you're after better feedback you could also consider adding your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Object.create works great if you want to copy your object's prototype.

Comment: ```var x = { deep: { key: 1 } }; var y = Object.create(x); x.deep.key = 2;```

After doing this, `y.deep.key` will also be 2, hence Object.create CAN NOT BE USED for cloning...

Comment: @froginvasion - because it doesn't work even for flat objects? (Chrome 45). You just get `__proto__`, not a clone...

Comment: `Object.create` does not get you `__proto__`, it gets you a new object, with it's prototype pointing to the argument, thus creating a chain. I agree that it is maybe not a real 'clone' in the traditional sense, but depending on the situation `Object.create` is much more consistent than using various cloning techniques used below. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: how about `var newObj = (function(){ return oldObj; }());`

Comment: @r3wt that will not work... Please post only after doing basic test of  the solution..

Comment: here a **benchmark** of different solutions: http://jsben.ch/#/bWfk9

Comment: @RubenStolk why OP cannot store object into new variable ?
like `var copyobject=object `??

Comment: @Mahi That does not copy the object. It creates a new variable and makes it point to the same object.

Comment: @LordLoh. what if you're in a javascripting environment where you can't import libraries like JSON. Apple's Quartz Composer Editor for example, not sure about Adobe CC scripting.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign - just tried this on the chrome developer terminal - `oj1={}; oj1.p1=222; oj2={}; Object.assign(oj2,oj1); oj2.p1=555; oj1.p1;` - this will show `222` Also answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36177142/482176

Comment: @LordLoh. Seems like I can call JSON.parse and JSON.stringify after all inside QC. Core functions after all. Also i did find this polyfill on the reference page and links to more advanced polyfills JSON2 and JSON3: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: `{...original}`

Comment: If you are suggesting Object.create() then you know very little about JS. Object.create will not clone the object X.  Y = Object.create(X) does this and nothing more: Creates a new object Y with X as its prototype. The object X will become the prototype of Object Y. That is not what you want. At all. Because X's methods and data are not copied to Y, they are referenced, Y holds a reference to X's data and methods. How wrong can you be!?

Comment: Recently answered it over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442750/4442322)

Comment: See [developer.mozilla.org's JavaScript/Reference of assign#Deep_Clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone).

Comment: This should create a copy: `let y = {...x};`

Comment: you can use clone method of lodash, or use spread operator
let x = {}
let y = {some value}

x = {...x, ...y}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416020/deep-copy-in-es6-using-the-spread-syntax/72191043#72191043

Answer (score 1973, accepted):

#### 2022 update

There's a new JS standard called [structured cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone). It works in many browsers (see [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=structuredClone)).

```js
const clone = structuredClone(object);
```

### Old answer

To do this for any object in JavaScript will not be simple or straightforward. You will run into the problem of erroneously picking up attributes from the object's prototype that should be left in the prototype and not copied to the new instance. If, for instance, you are adding a `clone` method to `Object.prototype`, as some answers depict, you will need to explicitly skip that attribute. But what if there are other additional methods added to `Object.prototype`, or other intermediate prototypes, that you don't know about? In that case, you will copy attributes you shouldn't, so you need to detect unforeseen, non-local attributes with the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method.

In addition to non-enumerable attributes, you'll encounter a tougher problem when you try to copy objects that have hidden properties. For example, `prototype` is a hidden property of a function. Also, an object's prototype is referenced with the attribute `__proto__`, which is also hidden, and will not be copied by a for/in loop iterating over the source object's attributes. I think `__proto__` might be specific to Firefox's JavaScript interpreter and it may be something different in other browsers, but you get the picture. Not everything is enumerable. You can copy a hidden attribute if you know its name, but I don't know of any way to discover it automatically.

Yet another snag in the quest for an elegant solution is the problem of setting up the prototype inheritance correctly. If your source object's prototype is `Object`, then simply creating a new general object with `{}` will work, but if the source's prototype is some descendant of `Object`, then you are going to be missing the additional members from that prototype which you skipped using the `hasOwnProperty` filter, or which were in the prototype, but weren't enumerable in the first place. One solution might be to call the source object's `constructor` property to get the initial copy object and then copy over the attributes, but then you still will not get non-enumerable attributes. For example, a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object stores its data as a hidden member:

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

var d1 = new Date();

/* Executes function after 5 seconds. */
setTimeout(function(){
    var d2 = clone(d1);
    alert("d1 = " + d1.toString() + "\nd2 = " + d2.toString());
}, 5000);
```

The date string for `d1` will be 5 seconds behind that of `d2`. A way to make one `Date` the same as another is by calling the `setTime` method, but that is specific to the `Date` class. I don't think there is a bullet-proof general solution to this problem, though I would be happy to be wrong!

When I had to implement general deep copying I ended up compromising by assuming that I would only need to copy a plain `Object`, `Array`, `Date`, `String`, `Number`, or `Boolean`. The last 3 types are immutable, so I could perform a shallow copy and not worry about it changing. I further assumed that any elements contained in `Object` or `Array` would also be one of the 6 simple types in that list. This can be accomplished with code like the following:

```
function clone(obj) {
    var copy;

    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
            copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        copy = {};
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}
```

The above function will work adequately for the 6 simple types I mentioned, as long as the data in the objects and arrays form a tree structure. That is, there isn't more than one reference to the same data in the object. For example:

```
// This would be cloneable:
var tree = {
    "left"  : { "left" : null, "right" : null, "data" : 3 },
    "right" : null,
    "data"  : 8
};

// This would kind-of work, but you would get 2 copies of the 
// inner node instead of 2 references to the same copy
var directedAcylicGraph = {
    "left"  : { "left" : null, "right" : null, "data" : 3 },
    "data"  : 8
};
directedAcyclicGraph["right"] = directedAcyclicGraph["left"];

// Cloning this would cause a stack overflow due to infinite recursion:
var cyclicGraph = {
    "left"  : { "left" : null, "right" : null, "data" : 3 },
    "data"  : 8
};
cyclicGraph["right"] = cyclicGraph;
```

It will not be able to handle any JavaScript object, but it may be sufficient for many purposes as long as you don't assume that it will just work for anything you throw at it.

Comment: This is missing symbol keys and symbol values. Nowadays, using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` is better.

Comment: **structuredClone** is [only 75% compatible globally](https://caniuse.com/?search=structuredClone)

Comment: In Nodejs, `structuredClone(object)` works for node v17.0.0 and later.

Comment: Update on @JoshuaDavid, currently supported in 82.57% of all browsers.

Comment: If you want to use  `structuredClone(object)` you need to install the node version 17.0.29 at least, you can use this command `npm i --save-dev @types/node@17.0.29`

Comment: what if I want to `clone` the `object` and also want to `append` something to it?

Comment: Ran into issues using this function on mobile devices..
- iOS 11,12,13,14, not working on Safari and Google Chrome. (works on iOS 15,16)
- Android 12, 11, 10, 9 on SamsungInternet browser (chrome works).

Comment: Sadly it does not clone symbols, even unique ones not (where it could just make a new reference to them). :-(

Comment: Please note that `structuredClone` cannot clone `Proxy` objects, you must clone the raw object: `const b = structuredClone(toRaw(a.value));`

Answer (score 1163):

If you do not use `Date`s, functions, undefined, regExp or Infinity within your object, a very simple one liner is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`:

```js
const a = {
  string: 'string',
  number: 123,
  bool: false,
  nul: null,
  date: new Date(),  // stringified
  undef: undefined,  // lost
  inf: Infinity,  // forced to 'null'
}
console.log(a);
console.log(typeof a.date);  // Date object
const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(clone);
console.log(typeof clone.date);  // result of .toISOString()
```

This works for all kind of objects containing objects, arrays, strings, booleans and numbers.

See also [this article about the structured clone algorithm of browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm) which is used when posting messages to and from a worker. It also contains a function for deep cloning.

Comment: sometimes the best answers are the simplest. genius.

Comment: Helpful, but when comparing objects which contains other objects, I ran through unexpected behaviour when two exactly equal objects where not taken as equals. used JSON.stringify(x) == JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))) to fix it. For some reason, comparing as strings works perfectly as expected when comparing, could not match otherwise.

Comment: @AgustinL.Lacuara You cannot compare complex datatypes in JS.  `a={};b={}; a==b`  is `false`. But after `a=b` it becomes `true`, because it is not only identical but it is the same object.

Comment: does the job, but, this is goes against any good programming practice. 
In brazil, we call that a 'Gambiarra'

Answer (score 840):

In ECMAScript 6 there is [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method, which copies values of all enumerable own properties from one object to another. For example:

```
var x = {myProp: "value"};
var y = Object.assign({}, x);
```

But be aware **this is a shallow copy** - nested objects are still copied as reference.

Answer (score 815):

With jQuery, you can **shallow copy** with [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend):

```
var copiedObject = jQuery.extend({}, originalObject)
```

subsequent changes to the `copiedObject` will not affect the `originalObject`, and vice versa.

Or to make a **deep copy**:

```
var copiedObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, originalObject)
```

Answer (score 330):

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone):

- If you want shallow copy, use `Object.assign({}, a)`
- For "deep" copy, use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))`

There is no need for external libraries but you need to check [browser compatibility first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: The problem happens when you have functions in your object JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))

Answer (score 149):

## An elegant way to clone a Javascript object in one line of code

An `Object.assign` method is part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard and does exactly what you need.

```
var clone = Object.assign({}, obj);
```

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.

[Read more...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

The **polyfill** to support older browsers:

```
if (!Object.assign) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object, 'assign', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function(target) {
      'use strict';
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert first argument to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);
      for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[i];
        if (nextSource === undefined || nextSource === null) {
          continue;
        }
        nextSource = Object(nextSource);

        var keysArray = Object.keys(nextSource);
        for (var nextIndex = 0, len = keysArray.length; nextIndex < len; nextIndex++) {
          var nextKey = keysArray[nextIndex];
          var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nextSource, nextKey);
          if (desc !== undefined && desc.enumerable) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: this will only perform a shallow "cloning"

Comment: I learned the hard way that `objA = objB;` causes all kinds of headaches. This seems to have solved the problem, at least for now...

Answer (score 143):

There are many answers, but none that mentions [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) from ECMAScript 5, which admittedly does not give you an exact copy, but sets the source as the prototype of the new object.

Thus, this is not an exact answer to the question, but it is a one-line solution and thus elegant. And it works best for 2 cases:

1. Where such inheritance is useful (duh!)
2. Where the source object won't be modified, thus making the relation between the 2 objects a non issue.

Example:

```
var foo = { a : 1 };
var bar = Object.create(foo);
foo.a; // 1
bar.a; // 1
foo.a = 2;
bar.a; // 2 - prototype changed
bar.a = 3;
foo.a; // Still 2, since setting bar.a makes it an "own" property
```

Why do I consider this solution to be superior? It's native, thus no looping, no recursion. However, older browsers will need a polyfill.

Comment: This is prototypal inheritance, not cloning. These are completely different things. The new object doesn't have any of it's own properties, it just points to the prototype's properties. The point of cloning is to create a fresh new object that doesn't reference any properties in another object.

Answer (score 101):

There are several issues with most solutions on the internet. So I decided to make a follow-up, which includes, why the accepted answer shouldn't be accepted.

### starting situation

I want to **deep-copy** a Javascript `Object` with all of its children and their children and so on. But since I'm not kind of a normal developer, my `Object` has *normal* `properties`, `circular structures` and even `nested objects`.

So let's create a `circular structure` and a `nested object` first.

```
function Circ() {
    this.me = this;
}

function Nested(y) {
    this.y = y;
}
```

Let's bring everything together in an `Object` named `a`.

```
var a = {
    x: 'a',
    circ: new Circ(),
    nested: new Nested('a')
};
```

Next, we want to copy `a` into a variable named `b` and mutate it.

```
var b = a;

b.x = 'b';
b.nested.y = 'b';
```

You know what happened here because if not you wouldn't even land on this great question.

```
console.log(a, b);

a --> Object {
    x: "b",
    circ: Circ {
        me: Circ { ... }
    },
    nested: Nested {
        y: "b"
    }
}

b --> Object {
    x: "b",
    circ: Circ {
        me: Circ { ... }
    },
    nested: Nested {
        y: "b"
    }
}
```

Now let's find a solution.

### JSON

The first attempt I tried was using `JSON`.

```
var b = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( a ) );

b.x = 'b';
b.nested.y = 'b';
```

Don't waste too much time on it, you'll get `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

### Recursive copy *(the accepted "answer")*

Let's have a look at the accepted answer.

```
function cloneSO(obj) {
    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        var copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        var copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
            copy[i] = cloneSO(obj[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        var copy = {};
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = cloneSO(obj[attr]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}
```

Looks good, heh? It's a recursive copy of the object and handles other types as well, like `Date`, but that wasn't a requirement.

```
var b = cloneSO(a);

b.x = 'b';
b.nested.y = 'b';
```

Recursion and `circular structures` doesn't work well together... `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

### native solution

After arguing with my co-worker, my boss asked us what happened, and he found a simple *solution* after some googling. It's called `Object.create`.

```
var b = Object.create(a);

b.x = 'b';
b.nested.y = 'b';
```

This solution was added to Javascript some time ago and even handles `circular structure`.

```
console.log(a, b);

a --> Object {
    x: "a",
    circ: Circ {
        me: Circ { ... }
    },
    nested: Nested {
        y: "b"
    }
}

b --> Object {
    x: "b",
    circ: Circ {
        me: Circ { ... }
    },
    nested: Nested {
        y: "b"
    }
}
```

... and you see, it didn't work with the nested structure inside.

### polyfill for the native solution

There's a polyfill for `Object.create` in the older browser just like the IE 8. It's something like recommended by Mozilla, and of course, it's not perfect and results in the same problem as the *native solution*.

```
function F() {};
function clonePF(o) {
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}

var b = clonePF(a);

b.x = 'b';
b.nested.y = 'b';
```

I've put `F` outside the scope so we can have a look at what `instanceof` tells us.

```
console.log(a, b);

a --> Object {
    x: "a",
    circ: Circ {
        me: Circ { ... }
    },
    nested: Nested {
        y: "b"
    }
}

b --> F {
    x: "b",
    circ: Circ {
        me: Circ { ... }
    },
    nested: Nested {
        y: "b"
    }
}

console.log(typeof a, typeof b);

a --> object
b --> object

console.log(a instanceof Object, b instanceof Object);

a --> true
b --> true

console.log(a instanceof F, b instanceof F);

a --> false
b --> true
```

Same problem as the *native solution*, but a little bit worse output.

### the better (but not perfect) solution

When digging around, I found a similar question ([In Javascript, when performing a deep copy, how do I avoid a cycle, due to a property being "this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728412/in-javascript-when-performing-a-deep-copy-how-do-i-avoid-a-cycle-due-to-a-pro)) to this one, but with a way better solution.

```
function cloneDR(o) {
    const gdcc = "__getDeepCircularCopy__";
    if (o !== Object(o)) {
        return o; // primitive value
    }

    var set = gdcc in o,
        cache = o[gdcc],
        result;
    if (set && typeof cache == "function") {
        return cache();
    }
    // else
    o[gdcc] = function() { return result; }; // overwrite
    if (o instanceof Array) {
        result = [];
        for (var i=0; i<o.length; i++) {
            result[i] = cloneDR(o[i]);
        }
    } else {
        result = {};
        for (var prop in o)
            if (prop != gdcc)
                result[prop] = cloneDR(o[prop]);
            else if (set)
                result[prop] = cloneDR(cache);
    }
    if (set) {
        o[gdcc] = cache; // reset
    } else {
        delete o[gdcc]; // unset again
    }
    return result;
}

var b = cloneDR(a);

b.x = 'b';
b.nested.y = 'b';
```

And let's have a look at the output...

```
console.log(a, b);

a --> Object {
    x: "a",
    circ: Object {
        me: Object { ... }
    },
    nested: Object {
        y: "a"
    }
}

b --> Object {
    x: "b",
    circ: Object {
        me: Object { ... }
    },
    nested: Object {
        y: "b"
    }
}

console.log(typeof a, typeof b);

a --> object
b --> object

console.log(a instanceof Object, b instanceof Object);

a --> true
b --> true

console.log(a instanceof F, b instanceof F);

a --> false
b --> false
```

The requirements are matched, but there are still some smaller issues, including changing the `instance` of `nested` and `circ` to `Object`.

> The structure of trees that share a leaf won't be copied, they will become two independent leaves:

```
        [Object]                     [Object]
         /    \                       /    \
        /      \                     /      \
      |/_      _\|                 |/_      _\|  
  [Object]    [Object]   ===>  [Object]    [Object]
       \        /                 |           |
        \      /                  |           |
        _\|  |/_                 \|/         \|/
        [Object]               [Object]    [Object]
```

### conclusion

The last solution using recursion and a cache, may not be the best, but it's a **real** deep-copy of the object. It handles simple `properties`, `circular structures` and `nested object`, but it will mess up the instance of them while cloning.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/einfallstoll/N4mr2/)

Comment: so the conlcusion is to avoid that problem :)

Comment: @mikus until there's a *real* specification which covers more than just the basic use cases, yes.

Comment: An okay analysis of the solutions provided above but the conclusion drawn by the author indicates that there is no solution to this question.

Comment: It is shame that JS not includes native clone function.

Comment: Among all the top answers, I feel this is close to the correct one.

Comment: I'm using `the better (but not perfect) solution` and when working with [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), an additional if must be added after: `if (o instanceof Array) { /*...*/ }`: `else if (o instanceof Set) { result = new Set(); for (var i of o) { result.add(i); } }`

Answer (score 80):

If you're okay with a shallow copy, the underscore.js library has a [clone](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) method.

```
y = _.clone(x);
```

or you can extend it like

```
copiedObject = _.extend({},originalObject);
```

Comment: Thanks. Using this technique on a Meteor server.

Comment: To get started quickly with lodash, I'd recommend learning npm, Browserify, as well as lodash. I got clone to work with  'npm i --save lodash.clone' and then 'var clone = require('lodash.clone');' To get require to work, you need something like browserify. Once you install it and learn how it works, you’ll use 'browserify yourfile.js > bundle.js;start chrome index.html' every time you run your code (instead of going into Chrome directly). This gathers your file and all the files you required from the npm module into bundle.js. You can probably save time and automate this step with Gulp though.

Answer (score 78):

**OK,** imagine you have this object below and you want to clone it:

```
let obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3}; //ES6
```

or

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3}; //ES5
```

the answer is mainly depeneds on which **ECMAscript** you using, in `ES6+`, you can simply use `Object.assign` to do the clone:

```
let cloned = Object.assign({}, obj); //new {a:1, b:2, c:3};
```

or using spread operator like this:

```
let cloned = {...obj}; //new {a:1, b:2, c:3};
```

But if you using `ES5`, you can use few methods, but the `JSON.stringify`, just make sure you not using for a big chunk of data to copy, but it could be one line handy way in many cases, something like this:

```
let cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
//new {a:1, b:2, c:3};, can be handy, but avoid using on big chunk of data over and over
```

Comment: Can you please give example of what `big chunk of data` would equate to?  100kb? 100MB? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @user1063287, that basically the bigger data, the performnce worse... so it really depends, not a kb, mb or gb, it's more about how many times you wanna do that also... Also it won't work for functions and other stuffs...

Comment: `Object.assign` makes a shallow copy (just as the spread, @Alizera)

Comment: You can't use let in es5 :^) @Alireza

Answer (score 62):

### Update 06 July 2020

There are three (3) ways to clone objects in JavaScript. As objects in JavaScript are reference values, you can't simply just copy using the =.

The ways are:

```
const food = { food: 'apple', drink: 'milk' }


// 1. Using the "Spread"
// ------------------

{ ...food }


// 2. Using "Object.assign"
// ------------------

Object.assign({}, food)


// 3. "JSON"
// ------------------

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(food))

// RESULT:
// { food: 'apple', drink: 'milk' }
```

This can be used as a reference summary.

Comment: And this adds what new/unique information to this question?

Comment: The `JSON` approach would remove any methods of the object

Comment: To create a string from an object and then parsing that string into another object just to copy the object is a kind of Monty Python's style of programming :-D

Comment: This only works for object literals and objects that can be represented as such, but *not* for generic "objects" like you encounter in OO languages.
This seems to be what the OP asked for thus that's OK, but it' not a universal solution for every kind of object.

Comment: The spread operator and Object.assign fail for objects with a hierarchy, ie. nested objects. JSON.parse/stringify works, but as mentioned does not copy methods.

Comment: the spread syntax is syntactical sugar (for Object.assign in this case). this answer is misleading. –

Comment: The spread operator still copies the values by reference.

Answer (score 47):

One particularly inelegant solution is to use JSON encoding to make deep copies of objects that do not have member methods. The methodology is to JSON encode your target object, then by decoding it, you get the copy you are looking for.  You can decode as many times as you want to make as many copies as you need.

Of course, functions do not belong in JSON, so this only works for objects without member methods.

This methodology was perfect for my use case, since I'm storing JSON blobs in a key-value store, and when they are exposed as objects in a JavaScript API, each object actually contains a copy of the original state of the object so we can calculate the delta after the caller has mutated the exposed object.

```
var object1 = {key:"value"};
var object2 = object1;

object2 = JSON.stringify(object1);
object2 = JSON.parse(object2);

object2.key = "a change";
console.log(object1);// returns value
```

Comment: Why don't functions belong to JSON? I've seen them transfered as JSON more then once...

Comment: Functions are not part of the JSON spec becuase they are not a secure (or smart) way to transfer data, which is what JSON was made for.  I know the native JSON encoder in Firefox simply ignores functions passed to it, but I'm not sure about the behavior of others.

Comment: @mark: `{ 'foo': function() { return 1; } }` is a literal-constructed object.

Comment: @abarnert functions are not data. "Function literals" is a misnomer - since functions can contain arbitrary code, including assignments and all sort of "non-serializable" things.

Answer (score 43):

You can simply use a [spread property](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread/blob/master/Spread.md) to copy an object without references. But be careful (see comments), the 'copy' is just on the lowest object/array level. Nested properties are still references!

---

**Complete clone:**

```
let x = {a: 'value1'}
let x2 = {...x}

// => mutate without references:

x2.a = 'value2'
console.log(x.a)    // => 'value1'
```

**Clone with references on second level:**

```
const y = {a: {b: 'value3'}}
const y2 = {...y}

// => nested object is still a references:

y2.a.b = 'value4'
console.log(y.a.b)    // => 'value4'
```

---

JavaScript actually does not support deep clones natively. Use an utility function. For example Ramda:

> http://ramdajs.com/docs/#clone

Comment: This not working... it would work probably when x will be an array for instance x= [ 'ab','cd',...]

Comment: This works, but bear in mind this is a SHALLOW copy, therefore any deep references to others objects remain references!

Comment: A partial clone can also happen in this way:
`const first = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'};
const second = {...{a} = first}`

Answer (score 40):

```
const objClone = { ...obj };
```

Be aware that **nested objects** are still copied **as a reference.**

Comment: Thanks for the hint that nested objects are still copied as a reference! I almost got crazy when debugging my code because I modified nested properties on the "clone" but the original got modified.

Comment: This is ES2016, not 2018, and this answer was given [two years earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41183504/1269037).

Comment: so what if i want copy of nested property  as well

Comment: @SunilGarg To copy nested property as well you can use 
 `const objDeepClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Answer (score 30):

From this article: [How to copy arrays and objects in Javascript](https://greywyvern.com/?post=363) by Brian Huisman:

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
  var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
  for (var i in this) {
    if (i == 'clone') continue;
    if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
      newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
    } else newObj[i] = this[i]
  } return newObj;
};
```

Comment: This is close, but doesn't work for any object. Try cloning a Date object with this. Not all properties are enumerable, so they will not all show up in the for/in loop.

Comment: Adding to the object prototype like this broke jQuery for me.  Even when I renamed to clone2.

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011 The code above had a bug in it where it created a global variable called 'i' '(for i in this)', rather than '(for var i in this)'. I have enough karma to edit and it and fix it so I did.

Comment: @Calvin: this should be created an a non-enumerable property, otherwise 'clone' will appear in 'for' loops.

Comment: why isn't `var copiedObj = Object.create(obj);` a great way as well?

Comment: @Dany What if the cloned object had a property called `info` and the `info` object has properties, including a `weight` property. Then assigning `myclone.info.weight` would modify the prototype, because it *reads* `info` from the prototype then assigns to the `weight` property of that.

Answer (score 29):

For those using AngularJS, there is also direct method for cloning or extending of the objects in this library.

```
var destination = angular.copy(source);
```

or

```
angular.copy(source, destination);
```

More in angular.copy [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)...

Comment: This is a deep copy FYI.

Answer (score 27):

```
function clone(obj) {
    if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object')
        return obj;    
    var temp = new obj.constructor(); 
    for(var key in obj)
        temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);    
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: This answer is pretty close, but not quite correct. If you try cloning a Date object, you will not get the same date because the call to the Date constructor function initializes the new Date with the current date/time. That value isn't enumerable and won't be copied by the for/in loop.

Comment: Not perfect, but nice for those basic cases. E.g. allowing simple cloning of an argument that can be a basic Object, Array or String.

Comment: Upvoted for correctly calling the constructor using `new`. The accepted answer does not.

Comment: works on node everything else ! still left reference links

Comment: The recursive thought is great.But If the value is array,it will work?

Answer (score 26):

A.Levy's answer is almost complete, here is my little contribution: **there is a way how to handle recursive references**, see this line

`if(this[attr]==this) copy[attr] = copy;`

If the object is XML DOM element, we must use **cloneNode** instead

`if(this.cloneNode) return this.cloneNode(true);`

Inspired by A.Levy's exhaustive study and Calvin's prototyping approach, I offer this solution:

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
  if(this.cloneNode) return this.cloneNode(true);
  var copy = this instanceof Array ? [] : {};
  for(var attr in this) {
    if(typeof this[attr] == "function" || this[attr]==null || !this[attr].clone)
      copy[attr] = this[attr];
    else if(this[attr]==this) copy[attr] = copy;
    else copy[attr] = this[attr].clone();
  }
  return copy;
}

Date.prototype.clone = function() {
  var copy = new Date();
  copy.setTime(this.getTime());
  return copy;
}

Number.prototype.clone = 
Boolean.prototype.clone =
String.prototype.clone = function() {
  return this;
}
```

See also Andy Burke's note in the answers.

Comment: `Date.prototype.clone = function() {return new Date(+this)};`

Answer (score 25):

## Performance

Today 2020.04.30 I perform tests of chosen solutions on Chrome v81.0, Safari v13.1 and Firefox v75.0 on MacOs High Sierra v10.13.6.

I focus on speed of copy DATA (object with simple type fields, not methods etc.). The solutions A-I can make only shallow copy, solutions J-U can make deep copy.

#### Results for shallow copy

- solution `{...obj}` (A) is fastest on chrome and firefox and medium fast on safari
- solution based on `Object.assign` (B) is fast on all browsers
- jQuery (E) and lodash (F,G,H) solutions are medium/quite fast
- solution `JSON.parse/stringify` (K) is quite slow
- solutions D and U are slow on all browsers

[image]

#### Results for deep copy

- solution Q is fastest on all browsers
- jQuery (L) and lodash (J) are medium fast
- solution `JSON.parse/stringify` (K) is quite slow
- solution U is slowest on all browsers
- lodash (J) and solution U crash on Chrome for 1000 level deep object

[image]

### Details

For choosen solutions: 
[A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950864/860099) 
[B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30042948/860099)
C(my)
[D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497485/860099)
[E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5164215/860099)
[F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11024936/860099)
[G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13850856/860099)
[H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11024936/860099)
[I](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/860099)
[J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57504513/860099)
[K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10869248/860099)
[L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5164215/860099)
[M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728400/860099)
[N](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728395/860099)
[O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1042676/860099)
[P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33273256/860099)
[Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648941/860099)
[R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648941/860099)
[S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029912/860099)
[T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11462081/860099)
[U](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53737490/860099),
 I perform 4 tests

- shallow-small: object with 10 non-nested fields - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/0xk9l5ci9x/1)
- shallow-big: object with 1000 non-nested fields - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/t0k9l64319/1)
- deep-small: object with 10 levels-nested fields - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/pvk9l6pzfj/1)
- deep-big: object with 1000 levels-nested fields - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/euk9l6x9jx/1)

Objects used in tests are show in below snippet

```js
let obj_ShallowSmall = {
  field0: false,
  field1: true,
  field2: 1,
  field3: 0,
  field4: null,
  field5: [],
  field6: {},
  field7: "text7",
  field8: "text8",
}

let obj_DeepSmall = {
  level0: {
   level1: {
    level2: {
     level3: {
      level4: {
       level5: {
        level6: {
         level7: {
          level8: {
           level9: [[[[[[[[[['abc']]]]]]]]]],
  }}}}}}}}},
};

let obj_ShallowBig = Array(1000).fill(0).reduce((a,c,i) => (a['field'+i]=getField(i),a) ,{});


let obj_DeepBig = genDeepObject(1000);



// ------------------
// Show objects
// ------------------

console.log('obj_ShallowSmall:',JSON.stringify(obj_ShallowSmall));
console.log('obj_DeepSmall:',JSON.stringify(obj_DeepSmall));
console.log('obj_ShallowBig:',JSON.stringify(obj_ShallowBig));
console.log('obj_DeepBig:',JSON.stringify(obj_DeepBig));




// ------------------
// HELPERS
// ------------------

function getField(k) {
  let i=k%10;
  if(i==0) return false;
  if(i==1) return true;
  if(i==2) return k;
  if(i==3) return 0;
  if(i==4) return null;
  if(i==5) return [];
  if(i==6) return {};  
  if(i>=7) return "text"+k;
}

function genDeepObject(N) {
  // generate: {level0:{level1:{...levelN: {end:[[[...N-times...['abc']...]]] }}}...}}}
  let obj={};
  let o=obj;
  let arr = [];
  let a=arr;

  for(let i=0; i<N; i++) {
    o['level'+i]={};
    o=o['level'+i];
    let aa=[];
    a.push(aa);
    a=aa;
  }

  a[0]='abc';
  o['end']=arr;
  return obj;
}
```

Below snippet presents tested solutions and shows differences between them

```js
function A(obj) {
  return {...obj}
}

function B(obj) {
  return Object.assign({}, obj); 
}

function C(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce( (a,c) => (a[c]=obj[c], a), {})
}

function D(obj) {
  let copyOfObject = {};
  Object.defineProperties(copyOfObject, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
  return copyOfObject;
}

function E(obj) {
  return jQuery.extend({}, obj) // shallow
}

function F(obj) {
  return _.clone(obj);
}

function G(obj) {
  return _.clone(obj,true);
}

function H(obj) {
  return _.extend({},obj);
}

function I(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

function J(obj) {
  return _.cloneDeep(obj,true);
}

function K(obj) {
 return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

function L(obj) {
  return jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj) // deep
}

function M(obj) {
  if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object')
    return obj;    
  var temp = new obj.constructor(); 
  for(var key in obj)
    temp[key] = M(obj[key]);    
  return temp;
}

function N(obj) {
  let EClone = function(obj) {
    var newObj = (obj instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
    for (var i in obj) {
      if (i == 'EClone') continue;
      if (obj[i] && typeof obj[i] == "object") {
        newObj[i] = EClone(obj[i]);
      } else newObj[i] = obj[i]
    } return newObj;
  };

 return EClone(obj);
};

function O(obj) {
    if (obj == null || typeof obj != "object") return obj;
    if (obj.constructor != Object && obj.constructor != Array) return obj;
    if (obj.constructor == Date || obj.constructor == RegExp || obj.constructor == Function ||
        obj.constructor == String || obj.constructor == Number || obj.constructor == Boolean)
        return new obj.constructor(obj);

    let to = new obj.constructor();

    for (var name in obj)
    {
        to[name] = typeof to[name] == "undefined" ? O(obj[name], null) : to[name];
    }

    return to;
}

function P(obj) {
  function clone(target, source){

      for(let key in source){

          // Use getOwnPropertyDescriptor instead of source[key] to prevent from trigering setter/getter.
          let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key);
          if(descriptor.value instanceof String){
              target[key] = new String(descriptor.value);
          }
          else if(descriptor.value instanceof Array){
              target[key] = clone([], descriptor.value);
          }
          else if(descriptor.value instanceof Object){
              let prototype = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(descriptor.value);
              let cloneObject = clone({}, descriptor.value);
              Reflect.setPrototypeOf(cloneObject, prototype);
              target[key] = cloneObject;
          }
          else {
              Object.defineProperty(target, key, descriptor);
          }
      }
      let prototype = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(source);
      Reflect.setPrototypeOf(target, prototype);
      return target;
  }
  return clone({},obj);
}

function Q(obj) {
    var copy;

    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
            copy[i] = Q(obj[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        copy = {};
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = Q(obj[attr]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}

function R(obj) {
    const gdcc = "__getDeepCircularCopy__";
    if (obj !== Object(obj)) {
        return obj; // primitive value
    }

    var set = gdcc in obj,
        cache = obj[gdcc],
        result;
    if (set && typeof cache == "function") {
        return cache();
    }
    // else
    obj[gdcc] = function() { return result; }; // overwrite
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        result = [];
        for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
            result[i] = R(obj[i]);
        }
    } else {
        result = {};
        for (var prop in obj)
            if (prop != gdcc)
                result[prop] = R(obj[prop]);
            else if (set)
                result[prop] = R(cache);
    }
    if (set) {
        obj[gdcc] = cache; // reset
    } else {
        delete obj[gdcc]; // unset again
    }
    return result;
}

function S(obj) {
    const cache = new WeakMap(); // Map of old - new references

    function copy(object) {
        if (typeof object !== 'object' ||
            object === null ||
            object instanceof HTMLElement
        )
            return object; // primitive value or HTMLElement

        if (object instanceof Date) 
            return new Date().setTime(object.getTime());

        if (object instanceof RegExp) 
            return new RegExp(object.source, object.flags);

        if (cache.has(object)) 
            return cache.get(object);

        const result = object instanceof Array ? [] : {};

        cache.set(object, result); // store reference to object before the recursive starts

        if (object instanceof Array) {
            for(const o of object) {
                 result.push(copy(o));
            }
            return result;
        }

        const keys = Object.keys(object); 

        for (const key of keys)
            result[key] = copy(object[key]);

        return result;
    }

    return copy(obj);
}

function T(obj){
    var clonedObjectsArray = [];
    var originalObjectsArray = []; //used to remove the unique ids when finished
    var next_objid = 0;

    function objectId(obj) {
        if (obj == null) return null;
        if (obj.__obj_id == undefined){
            obj.__obj_id = next_objid++;
            originalObjectsArray[obj.__obj_id] = obj;
        }
        return obj.__obj_id;
    }

    function cloneRecursive(obj) {
        if (null == obj || typeof obj == "string" || typeof obj == "number" || typeof obj == "boolean") return obj;

        // Handle Date
        if (obj instanceof Date) {
            var copy = new Date();
            copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
            return copy;
        }

        // Handle Array
        if (obj instanceof Array) {
            var copy = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
                copy[i] = cloneRecursive(obj[i]);
            }
            return copy;
        }

        // Handle Object
        if (obj instanceof Object) {
            if (clonedObjectsArray[objectId(obj)] != undefined)
                return clonedObjectsArray[objectId(obj)];

            var copy;
            if (obj instanceof Function)//Handle Function
                copy = function(){return obj.apply(this, arguments);};
            else
                copy = {};

            clonedObjectsArray[objectId(obj)] = copy;

            for (var attr in obj)
                if (attr != "__obj_id" && obj.hasOwnProperty(attr))
                    copy[attr] = cloneRecursive(obj[attr]);                 

            return copy;
        }       


        throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
    }
    var cloneObj = cloneRecursive(obj);



    //remove the unique ids
    for (var i = 0; i < originalObjectsArray.length; i++)
    {
        delete originalObjectsArray[i].__obj_id;
    };

    return cloneObj;
}

function U(obj) {
  /*
    Deep copy objects by value rather than by reference,
    exception: `Proxy`
  */

  const seen = new WeakMap()

  return clone(obj)

  function defineProp(object, key, descriptor = {}, copyFrom = {}) {
    const { configurable: _configurable, writable: _writable }
      = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, key)
      || { configurable: true, writable: true }

    const test = _configurable // Can redefine property
      && (_writable === undefined || _writable) // Can assign to property

    if (!test || arguments.length <= 2) return test

    const basisDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(copyFrom, key)
      || { configurable: true, writable: true } // Custom…
      || {}; // …or left to native default settings

    ["get", "set", "value", "writable", "enumerable", "configurable"]
      .forEach(attr =>
        descriptor[attr] === undefined &&
        (descriptor[attr] = basisDesc[attr])
      )

    const { get, set, value, writable, enumerable, configurable }
      = descriptor

    return Object.defineProperty(object, key, {
      enumerable, configurable, ...get || set
        ? { get, set } // Accessor descriptor
        : { value, writable } // Data descriptor
    })
  }

  function clone(object) {
    if (object !== Object(object)) return object /*
    —— Check if the object belongs to a primitive data type */

    if (object instanceof Node) return object.cloneNode(true) /*
    —— Clone DOM trees */

    let _object // The clone of object

    switch (object.constructor) {
      case Array:
      case Object:
        _object = cloneObject(object)
        break

      case Date:
        _object = new Date(+object)
        break

      case Function:
        const fnStr = String(object)

        _object = new Function("return " +
          (/^(?!function |[^{]+?=>)[^(]+?\(/.test(fnStr)
            ? "function " : ""
          ) + fnStr
        )()

        copyPropDescs(_object, object)
        break

      case RegExp:
        _object = new RegExp(object)
        break

      default:
        switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(object.constructor)) {
          //                              // Stem from:
          case "[object Function]":       // `class`
          case "[object Undefined]":      // `Object.create(null)`
            _object = cloneObject(object)
            break

          default:                        // `Proxy`
            _object = object
        }
    }

    return _object
  }


  function cloneObject(object) {
    if (seen.has(object)) return seen.get(object) /*
    —— Handle recursive references (circular structures) */

    const _object = Array.isArray(object)
      ? []
      : Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(object)) /*
        —— Assign [[Prototype]] for inheritance */

    seen.set(object, _object) /*
    —— Make `_object` the associative mirror of `object` */

    Reflect.ownKeys(object).forEach(key =>
      defineProp(_object, key, { value: clone(object[key]) }, object)
    )

    return _object
  }


  function copyPropDescs(target, source) {
    Object.defineProperties(target,
      Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(source)
    )
  }
}
 
// ------------------------
// Test properties
// ------------------------


console.log(`  shallow deep  func  circ  undefined date  RegExp bigInt`)

log(A);
log(B);
log(C);
log(D);
log(E);
log(F);
log(G);
log(H);
log(I);
log(J);
log(K);
log(L);
log(M);
log(N);
log(O);
log(P);
log(Q);
log(R);
log(S);
log(T);
log(U);

console.log(`  shallow deep  func  circ  undefined date  RegExp bigInt
----
LEGEND:
shallow - solution create shallow copy
deep - solution create deep copy
func - solution copy functions
circ - solution can copy object with circular references
undefined - solution copy fields with undefined value
date - solution can copy date
RegExp - solution can copy fields with regular expressions
bigInt - solution can copy BigInt
`)


// ------------------------
// Helper functions
// ------------------------


function deepCompare(obj1,obj2) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj1)===JSON.stringify(obj2);
}

function getCase() { // pure data case
  return { 
    undef: undefined,
    bool: true, num: 1, str: "txt1",    
    e1: null, e2: [], e3: {}, e4: 0, e5: false,
    arr: [ false, 2, "txt3", null, [], {},
      [ true,4,"txt5",null, [], {},  [true,6,"txt7",null,[],{} ], 
        {bool: true,num: 8, str: "txt9", e1:null, e2:[] ,e3:{} ,e4: 0, e5: false}
      ],
        {bool: true,num: 10, str: "txt11", e1:null, e2:[] ,e3:{} ,e4: 0, e5: false}
    ], 
    obj: { 
        bool: true, num: 12, str: "txt13",
        e1: null, e2: [], e3: {}, e4: 0, e5: false,
        arr: [true,14,"txt15",null,[],{} ],
        obj: { 
          bool: true, num: 16, str: "txt17",
          e1: null, e2: [], e3: {}, e4: 0, e5: false,
          arr: [true,18,"txt19",null,[],{} ],
          obj: {bool: true,num: 20, str: "txt21", e1:null, e2:[] ,e3:{} ,e4: 0, e5: false}
      } 
    } 
  };
}

function check(org, copy, field, newValue) {
  copy[field] = newValue;
  return deepCompare(org,copy); 
}

function testFunc(f) {
 let o = { a:1, fun: (i,j)=> i+j };
  let c = f(o);
  
  let val = false
  try{
    val = c.fun(3,4)==7;
  } catch(e) { }
  return val;
} 

function testCirc(f) {
 function Circ() {
    this.me = this;
  }

  var o = {
      x: 'a',
      circ: new Circ(),
      obj_circ: null,
  };
  
  o.obj_circ = o;

  let val = false;

  try{
    let c = f(o);  
    val = (o.obj_circ == o) && (o.circ == o.circ.me);
  } catch(e) { }
  return val;
} 

function testRegExp(f) {
  let o = {
    re: /a[0-9]+/,
  };
  
  let val = false;

  try{
    let c = f(o);  
    val = (String(c.re) == String(/a[0-9]+/));
  } catch(e) { }
  return val;
}

function testDate(f) {
  let o = {
    date: new Date(),
  };
  
  let val = false;

  try{
    let c = f(o);  
    val = (+new Date(c.date) == +new Date(o.date));
  } catch(e) { }
  return val;
}

function testBigInt(f) {
  let val = false;
  
  try{
    let o = {
      big: 123n,
    };
  
    let c = f(o);  
  
    val = o.big == c.big;
  } catch(e) { }
  
  return val;
}

function log(f) {
  let o = getCase();  // orginal object
  let oB = getCase(); // "backup" used for shallow valid test
  
  let c1 = f(o); // copy 1 for reference
  let c2 = f(o); // copy 2 for test shallow values
  let c3 = f(o); // copy 3 for test deep values

  let is_proper_copy = deepCompare(c1,o);  // shoud be true
  
  // shallow changes
  let testShallow = 
    [ ['bool',false],['num',666],['str','xyz'],['arr',[]],['obj',{}] ]
    .reduce((acc,curr)=> acc && check(c1,c2,curr[0], curr[1]), true );
  
  // should be true (original object shoud not have changed shallow fields)
  let is_valid = deepCompare(o,oB); 

  // deep test (intruduce some change)
  if (c3.arr[6]) c3.arr[6][7].num = 777;
  
  let diff_shallow = !testShallow; // shoud be true (shallow field was copied)
  let diff_deep = !deepCompare(c1,c3);    // shoud be true (deep field was copied)
  let can_copy_functions = testFunc(f);
  let can_copy_circular = testCirc(f);
  let can_copy_regexp = testRegExp(f);
  let can_copy_date = testDate(f);
  let can_copy_bigInt = testBigInt(f);
  
  let has_undefined = 'undef' in c1; // field with undefined value is copied?  
  let is_ok = is_valid && is_proper_copy;
  let b=(bool) => (bool+'').padEnd(5,' '); // bool value to formated string
  
  testFunc(f);
  
  if(is_ok) {
    console.log(`${f.name} ${b(diff_shallow)}   ${b(diff_deep)} ${b(can_copy_functions)} ${b(can_copy_circular)} ${b(has_undefined)}     ${b(can_copy_date)} ${b(can_copy_regexp)}  ${b(can_copy_bigInt)}`)
  } else {
    console.log(`${f.name}: INVALID ${is_valid} ${is_proper_copy}`,{c1})
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>

This snippet only presents tested solutions and show differences between them (but it no make performence tests)
```

Below there are example results for Chrome for shallow-big object

[image]

Comment: What if the object contains window/globalThis or a reference to itself, or contains a Proxy?
structuredClone - crashes if the object contains a Proxy, a window or a reference to itself.
Everything else - crashes if the object contains window or 
a reference to itself.

Comment: @weroro partial solution: for objects with circular references use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61798003/860099) to serialise object to string and deserialise it (however I see some bugs with deserialisation for "windows" object - not all path-keys are proprely replaced in result... feel free to improve that solution). However - in that approach only data will be copied - not method/functions etc.

Answer (score 24):

Using Lodash:

```
var y = _.clone(x, true);
```

Comment: OMG it would be insane to reinvent cloning. This is the only sane answer.

Comment: I prefer `_.cloneDeep(x)` as it essentially is the same thing as above, but reads better.

Answer (score 23):

In ES-6 you can simply use Object.assign(...).
Ex:

```
let obj = {person: 'Thor Odinson'};
let clone = Object.assign({}, obj);
```

A good reference is here:
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/object-assign-es6/

Comment: It does not deep clone the object.

Comment: That's an assignment, not a copy.  clone.Title = "just a clone" means that obj.Title = "just a clone".

Comment: @HoldOffHunger You are mistaken. Check it in your browser's JS console ( `let obj = {person: 'Thor Odinson'}; let clone = Object.assign({}, obj); clone.title = "Whazzup";`)

Comment: @collapsar: That is precisely what I checked, then console.log(person) will be "Whazzup", not "Thor Odinson".  See August's comment.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Does not happen in Chrome 60.0.3112.113 nor in Edge 14.14393; August's comment does not apply as the values of primitive types of `obj`'s properties are indeed cloned. Property values that are Objects themselves will not be cloned.

Comment: Why did you feel the need to post [yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object/30042948#30042948) another [Object.assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object/40470792#40470792) answer to a question that already had a ton of answers? You answer doesn't help anyone; it only clutters the page. Please consider deleting it - you'll get a [special badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7609/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-disciplined-badge)!

Answer (score 21):

Interested in cloning simple objects:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json_original));`

Source : [How to copy JavaScript object to new variable NOT by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359093/how-to-copy-javascript-object-to-new-variable-not-by-reference?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Very nice - simple.

Comment: @MattH: this answer was already given [in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10869248/1269037). did you see it? Mohammed, did you check for existing answers before duplicating one of them?

Comment: well thats one   way. ty never thought of that

Answer (score 19):

## Structured Cloning

**2022 update:** The [`structuredClone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) global function is already available in Node 17, Deno 1.14, and most major browsers (see [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=structuredClone)).

You *can* use the same structured clone mechanism that the HTML standard includes for sending data between realms.

```
const clone = structuredClone(original);
```

See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10916838/157247) for more details.

Comment: +1 for giving an idea in what form it might become builtin, eventually—even if unusable right now.

Answer (score 18):

```
let clone = Object.assign( Object.create( Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)), obj)
```

ES6 solution if you want to (shallow) clone a **class instance** and not just a property object.

Comment: How this is different from `let cloned = Object.assign({}, obj)` ?

Comment: @ceztko When `obj` is a class instance, `Object.assign()` does not clone e.g. class methods (because they are not enumerable).

Answer (score 17):

You can clone an object and remove any reference from the previous one using a single line of code. Simply do:

```
var obj1 = { text: 'moo1' };
var obj2 = Object.create(obj1); // Creates a new clone without references

obj2.text = 'moo2'; // Only updates obj2's text property

console.log(obj1, obj2); // Outputs: obj1: {text:'moo1'}, obj2: {text:'moo2'}
```

For browsers / engines that do not currently support Object.create you can use this polyfill:

```
// Polyfill Object.create if it does not exist
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        var F = function () {};
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Comment: +1 `Object.create(...)` seems definitely the way to go.

Comment: Perfect answer. Maybe you could add an explanation for `Object.hasOwnProperty`? That way people know how to prevent searching the prototype link.

Comment: Works well but what browsers does the polyfill work in?

Comment: If there are objects or arrays in the original obj1, and they change the objects or arrays in the new obj2, it will be modified obj1's copies because they're stored by reference.  Example:

`
var obj1 = { thing: {} };  
var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);  
obj2.thing.innerThing = 'test';  
console.log(obj1)  
`

The output will be that obj1 and obj2 are now  
`{ thing: { innerThing: "test" } }`

Comment: This is creating obj2 with a obj1 as it's prototype.  It only works because you are shadowing the `text` member in obj2.  You are not making a copy, just deferring to the prototype chain when a member is not found on obj2.

Comment: @Quinthexadec setting `obj2`'s properties creates "own" properties on `obj2`' and does not modify `obj1`'s.

Comment: This does NOT create it "without references", it just moves the reference to the prototype. It's still a reference. If a property changes in the original so will the prototype property in the "clone". It's not a clone at all.

Answer (score 15):

New answer to an old question!  If you have the pleasure of having using ECMAScript 2016 (ES6) with [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), it's easy.

```
keepMeTheSame = {first: "Me!", second: "You!"};
cloned = {...keepMeTheSame}
```

This provides a clean method for a shallow copy of an object.  Making a deep copy, meaning makign a new copy of every value in every recursively nested object, requires on of the heavier solutions above.

JavaScript keeps evolving.

Comment: it doesn't work when you have functions defined on objects

Comment: as far as I see spread operator only works with iterables -   [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) says:  
`var obj = {'key1': 'value1'};`  
`var array = [...obj]; // TypeError: obj is not iterable`

Comment: @Oleh  so use  `  {... obj} instead of  [...obj];`

Comment: @manikantgautam I was using Object.assign() before, but now indeed object spread syntax is supported in latest Chrome, Firefox (still not in Edge and Safari). Its ECMAScript proposal... but Babel does support it as far as I can see, so probably its safe to use.

Answer (score 14):

I think there is a simple and working answer. In deep copying there are two concerns:

1. Keep properties independent to each other.
2. And keep the methods alive on cloned object.

So I think one simple solution will be to first serialize and deserialize and then do an assign on it to copy functions too.

```
let deepCloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source));
let merged = Object.assign({}, source);
Object.assign(merged, deepCloned);
```

Although this question has many answers, I hope this one helps too.

Comment: Although if I am permitted to import lodash, I prefer using lodash `cloneDeep`.

Comment: I'm using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source)). Always working.

Comment: @Misha, this way you will miss the functions. The term 'works' has many meanings.

Comment: And keep in mind that, the way I have mentioned, only the functions of the first layer will be copied. So If we have some objects inside each other, then the only way is to copy field by field recursively.

Answer (score 14):

For a deep copy and clone, JSON.stringify then JSON.parse the object:

```
obj = { a: 0 , b: { c: 0}};
let deepClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
obj.a = 5;
obj.b.c = 5;
console.log(JSON.stringify(deepClone)); // { a: 0, b: { c: 0}}
```

Comment: pretty clever... any downsides to this approach?

Answer (score 11):

(The following was mainly an integration of @[Maciej Bukowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029912), @[A. Levy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694), @[Jan Turoň](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9023088), @[Redu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37503916)'s answers, and @[LeviRoberts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object/53737490#comment96229185_53737490), @[RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360#comment42972840_9023088)'s comments, many thanks to them!!!)

**Deep copy**? — YES! (mostly);
**Shallow copy**? — NO! (except `Proxy`).

I sincerely welcome everyone to test `clone()`.
In addition, `defineProp()` is designed to easily and quickly *(re)define or copy* any type of descriptor.

## Function

```
function clone(object) {
  /*
    Deep copy objects by value rather than by reference,
    exception: `Proxy`
  */

  const seen = new WeakMap()

  return clone(object)


  function clone(object) {
    if (object !== Object(object)) return object /*
    —— Check if the object belongs to a primitive data type */

    if (object instanceof Node) return object.cloneNode(true) /*
    —— Clone DOM trees */

    let _object // The clone of object

    switch (object.constructor) {
      case Array:
      case Object:
        _object = cloneObject(object)
        break

      case Date:
        _object = new Date(+object)
        break

      case Function:
        _object = copyFn(object)
        break

      case RegExp:
        _object = new RegExp(object)
        break

      default:
        switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(object.constructor)) {
          //                                  // Stem from:
          case "[object Function]":
            switch (object[Symbol.toStringTag]) {
              case undefined:
                _object = cloneObject(object) // `class`
                break

              case "AsyncFunction":
              case "GeneratorFunction":
              case "AsyncGeneratorFunction":
                _object = copyFn(object)
                break

              default:
                _object = object
            }
            break

          case "[object Undefined]":          // `Object.create(null)`
            _object = cloneObject(object)
            break

          default:
            _object = object                  // `Proxy`
        }
    }

    return _object
  }


  function cloneObject(object) {
    if (seen.has(object)) return seen.get(object) /*
    —— Handle recursive references (circular structures) */

    const _object = Array.isArray(object)
      ? []
      : Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(object)) /*
        —— Assign [[Prototype]] for inheritance */

    seen.set(object, _object) /*
    —— Make `_object` the associative mirror of `object` */

    Reflect.ownKeys(object).forEach(key =>
      defineProp(_object, key, { value: clone(object[key]) }, object)
    )

    return _object
  }
}


function copyPropDescs(target, source) {
  Object.defineProperties(target,
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(source)
  )
}


function convertFnToStr(fn) {
  let fnStr = String(fn)
  if (fn.name.startsWith("[")) // isSymbolKey
    fnStr = fnStr.replace(/\[Symbol\..+?\]/, '')
  fnStr = /^(?!(async )?(function\b|[^{]+?=>))[^(]+?\(/.test(fnStr)
    ? fnStr.replace(/^(async )?(\*)?/, "$1function$2 ") : fnStr
  return fnStr
}

function copyFn(fn) {
  const newFn = new Function(`return ${convertFnToStr(fn)}`)()
  copyPropDescs(newFn, fn)
  return newFn
}



function defineProp(object, key, descriptor = {}, copyFrom = {}) {
  const { configurable: _configurable, writable: _writable }
    = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, key)
    || { configurable: true, writable: true }

  const test = _configurable // Can redefine property
    && (_writable === undefined || _writable) // Can assign to property

  if (!test || arguments.length <= 2) return test

  const basisDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(copyFrom, key)
    || { configurable: true, writable: true } // Custom…
    || {}; // …or left to native default settings

  ["get", "set", "value", "writable", "enumerable", "configurable"]
    .forEach(attr =>
      descriptor[attr] === undefined &&
      (descriptor[attr] = basisDesc[attr])
    )

  const { get, set, value, writable, enumerable, configurable }
    = descriptor

  return Object.defineProperty(object, key, {
    enumerable, configurable, ...get || set
      ? { get, set } // Accessor descriptor
      : { value, writable } // Data descriptor
  })
}
```

### // Tests

```
const obj0 = {
  u: undefined,
  nul: null,
  t: true,
  num: 9,
  str: "",
  sym: Symbol("symbol"),
  [Symbol("e")]: Math.E,
  arr: [[0], [1, 2]],
  d: new Date(),
  re: /f/g,
  get g() { return 0 },
  o: {
    n: 0,
    o: { f: function (...args) { } }
  },
  f: {
    getAccessorStr(object) {
      return []
        .concat(...
          Object.values(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(object))
            .filter(desc => desc.writable === undefined)
            .map(desc => Object.values(desc))
        )
        .filter(prop => typeof prop === "function")
        .map(String)
    },
    f0: function f0() { },
    f1: function () { },
    f2: a => a / (a + 1),
    f3: () => 0,
    f4(params) { return param => param + params },
    f5: (a, b) => ({ c = 0 } = {}) => a + b + c
  }
}

defineProp(obj0, "s", { set(v) { this._s = v } })
defineProp(obj0.arr, "tint", { value: { is: "non-enumerable" } })
obj0.arr[0].name = "nested array"


let obj1 = clone(obj0)
obj1.o.n = 1
obj1.o.o.g = function g(a = 0, b = 0) { return a + b }
obj1.arr[1][1] = 3
obj1.d.setTime(+obj0.d + 60 * 1000)
obj1.arr.tint.is = "enumerable? no"
obj1.arr[0].name = "a nested arr"
defineProp(obj1, "s", { set(v) { this._s = v + 1 } })
defineProp(obj1.re, "multiline", { value: true })

console.log("\n\n" + "-".repeat(2 ** 6))




console.log(">:>: Test - Routinely")

console.log("obj0:\n ", JSON.stringify(obj0))
console.log("obj1:\n ", JSON.stringify(obj1))
console.log()

console.log("obj0:\n ", obj0)
console.log("obj1:\n ", obj1)
console.log()

console.log("obj0\n ",
  ".arr.tint:", obj0.arr.tint, "\n ",
  ".arr[0].name:", obj0.arr[0].name
)
console.log("obj1\n ",
  ".arr.tint:", obj1.arr.tint, "\n ",
  ".arr[0].name:", obj1.arr[0].name
)
console.log()

console.log("Accessor-type descriptor\n ",
  "of obj0:", obj0.f.getAccessorStr(obj0), "\n ",
  "of obj1:", obj1.f.getAccessorStr(obj1), "\n ",
  "set (obj0 & obj1) .s :", obj0.s = obj1.s = 0, "\n ",
  "  → (obj0 , obj1) ._s:", obj0._s, ",", obj1._s
)

console.log("—— obj0 has not been interfered.")

console.log("\n\n" + "-".repeat(2 ** 6))




console.log(">:>: Test - More kinds of functions")

const fnsForTest = {
  f(_) { return _ },
  func: _ => _,
  aFunc: async _ => _,
  async function() { },
  async asyncFunc() { },
  aFn: async function () { },
  *gen() { },
  async *asyncGen() { },
  aG1: async function* () { },
  aG2: async function* gen() { },
  *[Symbol.iterator]() { yield* Object.keys(this) }
}

console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(fnsForTest).map(k =>
  `${String(k)}:
  ${fnsForTest[k].name}-->
    ${String(fnsForTest[k])}`
).join("\n"))

const normedFnsStr = `{
  f: function f(_) { return _ },
  func: _ => _,
  aFunc: async _ => _,
  function: async function() { },
  asyncFunc: async function asyncFunc() { },
  aFn: async function () { },
  gen: function* gen() { },
  asyncGen: async function* asyncGen() { },
  aG1: async function* () { },
  aG2: async function* gen() { },
  [Symbol.iterator]: function* () { yield* Object.keys(this) }
}`

const copiedFnsForTest = clone(fnsForTest)
console.log("fnsForTest:", fnsForTest)
console.log("fnsForTest (copied):", copiedFnsForTest)
console.log("fnsForTest (normed str):", eval(`(${normedFnsStr})`))
console.log("Comparison of fnsForTest and its clone:",
  Reflect.ownKeys(fnsForTest).map(k =>
    [k, fnsForTest[k] === copiedFnsForTest[k]]
  )
)

console.log("\n\n" + "-".repeat(2 ** 6))




console.log(">:>: Test - Circular structures")

obj0.o.r = {}
obj0.o.r.recursion = obj0.o
obj0.arr[1] = obj0.arr

obj1 = clone(obj0)
console.log("obj0:\n ", obj0)
console.log("obj1:\n ", obj1)

console.log("Clear obj0's recursion:",
  obj0.o.r.recursion = null, obj0.arr[1] = 1
)
console.log(
  "obj0\n ",
  ".o.r:", obj0.o.r, "\n ",
  ".arr:", obj0.arr
)
console.log(
  "obj1\n ",
  ".o.r:", obj1.o.r, "\n ",
  ".arr:", obj1.arr
)
console.log("—— obj1 has not been interfered.")


console.log("\n\n" + "-".repeat(2 ** 6))




console.log(">:>: Test - Classes")

class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

class Boy extends Person { }
Boy.prototype.sex = "M"

const boy0 = new Boy
boy0.hobby = { sport: "spaceflight" }

const boy1 = clone(boy0)
boy1.hobby.sport = "superluminal flight"

boy0.name = "one"
boy1.name = "neo"

console.log("boy0:\n ", boy0)
console.log("boy1:\n ", boy1)
console.log("boy1's prototype === boy0's:",
  Object.getPrototypeOf(boy1) === Object.getPrototypeOf(boy0)
)
```

## References

1. [`Object.create()` | MDN](https://mdn.io/Object/create)
2. [`Object.defineProperties()` | MDN](https://mdn.io/Object/defineProperties)
3. [Enumerability and ownership of properties | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#Detection_Table)
4. [TypeError: cyclic object value | MDN](https://mdn.io/Errors/Cyclic_object_value)

## Language tricks used

1. [Conditionally add prop to object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40560953)

Comment: Since `Symbol("a") === Symbol("a")` is `false`, shouldn’t `clone(Symbol("a"))` use `Symbol(object.description)` to create a new symbol? Or would this have too weird of an impact on well-known symbols?

Comment: @SebastianSimon  Your consideration is very comprehensive! And your last sentence is ***more* correct**, e.g. `(new Map)[Symbol.iterator]` vs `(new Map)[Symbol(Symbol.iterator.description)]`.

Answer (score 10):

> ***[Use lodash _.cloneDeep().](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)***

***Shallow Copy: lodash _.clone()***

*A shallow copy can be made by simply copying the reference.*

```
let obj1 = {
    a: 0,
    b: {
        c: 0,
        e: {
            f: 0
        }
    }
};
let obj3 = _.clone(obj1);
obj1.a = 4;
obj1.b.c = 4;
obj1.b.e.f = 100;

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1));
//{"a":4,"b":{"c":4,"e":{"f":100}}}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj3));
//{"a":0,"b":{"c":4,"e":{"f":100}}}
```

[image: Shallow Copy: lodash _.clone()]

***Deep Copy: lodash _.cloneDeep()***

*fields are dereferenced: rather than references to objects being copied*

```
let obj1 = {
    a: 0,
    b: {
        c: 0,
        e: {
            f: 0
        }
    }
};
let obj3 = _.cloneDeep(obj1);
obj1.a = 100;
obj1.b.c = 100;
obj1.b.e.f = 100;

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1));
{"a":100,"b":{"c":100,"e":{"f":100}}}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj3));
{"a":0,"b":{"c":0,"e":{"f":0}}}
```

[image: Deep Copy: lodash _.cloneDeep()]

Answer (score 9):

The most correct to copy object is use `Object.create`:

```js
Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
```

Such notation will make identically the same object with correct prototype and hidden properties.

Comment: yes but depends what you want (you might want to plain "copy" the prop _values_, *not* the actual prop descriptor refs...), and depending on the source obj you might need an `Object.assign` on top of this to get enumarable properties in as well (i.e plain old key-value pairs set on the object, unrelated to prototype and "dynamic" described props.

Answer (score 8):

This is an adaptation of A. Levy's code to also handle the cloning of functions and multiple/cyclic references - what this means is that if two properties in the tree which is cloned are references of the same object, the cloned object tree will have these properties point to one and the same clone of the referenced object. This also solves the case of cyclic dependencies which, if left unhandled, leads to an infinite loop. The complexity of the algorithm is O(n)

```
function clone(obj){
    var clonedObjectsArray = [];
    var originalObjectsArray = []; //used to remove the unique ids when finished
    var next_objid = 0;

    function objectId(obj) {
        if (obj == null) return null;
        if (obj.__obj_id == undefined){
            obj.__obj_id = next_objid++;
            originalObjectsArray[obj.__obj_id] = obj;
        }
        return obj.__obj_id;
    }

    function cloneRecursive(obj) {
        if (null == obj || typeof obj == "string" || typeof obj == "number" || typeof obj == "boolean") return obj;

        // Handle Date
        if (obj instanceof Date) {
            var copy = new Date();
            copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
            return copy;
        }

        // Handle Array
        if (obj instanceof Array) {
            var copy = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
                copy[i] = cloneRecursive(obj[i]);
            }
            return copy;
        }

        // Handle Object
        if (obj instanceof Object) {
            if (clonedObjectsArray[objectId(obj)] != undefined)
                return clonedObjectsArray[objectId(obj)];

            var copy;
            if (obj instanceof Function)//Handle Function
                copy = function(){return obj.apply(this, arguments);};
            else
                copy = {};

            clonedObjectsArray[objectId(obj)] = copy;

            for (var attr in obj)
                if (attr != "__obj_id" && obj.hasOwnProperty(attr))
                    copy[attr] = cloneRecursive(obj[attr]);                 

            return copy;
        }       


        throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
    }
    var cloneObj = cloneRecursive(obj);



    //remove the unique ids
    for (var i = 0; i < originalObjectsArray.length; i++)
    {
        delete originalObjectsArray[i].__obj_id;
    };

    return cloneObj;
}
```

Some quick tests

```
var auxobj = {
    prop1 : "prop1 aux val", 
    prop2 : ["prop2 item1", "prop2 item2"]
    };

var obj = new Object();
obj.prop1 = "prop1_value";
obj.prop2 = [auxobj, auxobj, "some extra val", undefined];
obj.nr = 3465;
obj.bool = true;

obj.f1 = function (){
    this.prop1 = "prop1 val changed by f1";
};

objclone = clone(obj);

//some tests i've made
console.log("test number, boolean and string cloning: " + (objclone.prop1 == obj.prop1 && objclone.nr == obj.nr && objclone.bool == obj.bool));

objclone.f1();
console.log("test function cloning 1: " + (objclone.prop1 == 'prop1 val changed by f1'));
objclone.f1.prop = 'some prop';
console.log("test function cloning 2: " + (obj.f1.prop == undefined));

objclone.prop2[0].prop1 = "prop1 aux val NEW";
console.log("test multiple references cloning 1: " + (objclone.prop2[1].prop1 == objclone.prop2[0].prop1));
console.log("test multiple references cloning 2: " + (objclone.prop2[1].prop1 != obj.prop2[0].prop1));
```

Comment: As of September 2016, this is the *only* correct solution to the question.

Answer (score 8):

I've had an issue when copying objects. This is because when you do following, you're only making a 'reference' to the object and when the source object value is updated later, the copy object that was cloned also changes value because it was merely a 'reference' and  hence you see multiple values of the last changes to the source object.

```
let x = { a: 1 };
let y = x; // y is a reference to x, so if x changes y also changes and v/v
```

So, to tackle this issue you do the following:

```
let y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)); //see Note below
```

The other way to prevent references is by doing the following:

```
let x = { a: 1 };
let y = Object.assign({}, x); // Object.assign(target, ...sources)

y.a = 2;
console.log(x); // { a: 1 }
console.log(y); // { a: 2 }
```

Note: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#warning_for_deep_clone

Comment: `Object.assign` is not a candidate for deep copy. It works only if the properties are value types - like in the example - but for references it basically performs a shallow copy, as clearly indicated by the other answer. So the last part of this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add to all the `Object.create` solutions in this post, that this does not work in the desired way with nodejs.

In Firefox the result of

```
var a = {"test":"test"};
var b = Object.create(a);
console.log(b);´
```

is

`{test:"test"}`.

In nodejs it is

```
{}
```

Comment: This is prototypal inheritance, not cloning.

Comment: @d13 while your argument is valid, note that there is no standardized way in JavaScript to clone an object. This is prototypical inheritance, but it can be used as clones nevertheless if you understand the concepts.

Comment: @froginvasion. The only problem with using Object.create is that nested objects and arrays are just pointer references to the prototype's nested objects and arrays. http://jsbin.com/EKivInO/2/edit?js,console. Technically a "cloned" object should have its own unique properties that are not shared references to properties on other objects.

Comment: @d13 okay, I see your point now. But what I meant is that too many people are alienated with the concept of prototypical inheritance, and to me fail to learn how it works. If I'm not mistaken,  your example can be fixed by just calling `Object.hasOwnProperty` to check whether you own the array or not. Yes this does add additional complexity to deal with prototypical inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

```
function clone(src, deep) {

    var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
    if(!src && typeof src != "object"){
        //any non-object ( Boolean, String, Number ), null, undefined, NaN
        return src;
    }

    //Honor native/custom clone methods
    if(src.clone && toString.call(src.clone) == "[object Function]"){
        return src.clone(deep);
    }

    //DOM Elements
    if(src.nodeType && toString.call(src.cloneNode) == "[object Function]"){
        return src.cloneNode(deep);
    }

    //Date
    if(toString.call(src) == "[object Date]"){
        return new Date(src.getTime());
    }

    //RegExp
    if(toString.call(src) == "[object RegExp]"){
        return new RegExp(src);
    }

    //Function
    if(toString.call(src) == "[object Function]"){
        //Wrap in another method to make sure == is not true;
        //Note: Huge performance issue due to closures, comment this :)
        return (function(){
            src.apply(this, arguments);
        });

    }

    var ret, index;
    //Array
    if(toString.call(src) == "[object Array]"){
        //[].slice(0) would soft clone
        ret = src.slice();
        if(deep){
            index = ret.length;
            while(index--){
                ret[index] = clone(ret[index], true);
            }
        }
    }
    //Object
    else {
        ret = src.constructor ? new src.constructor() : {};
        for (var prop in src) {
            ret[prop] = deep
                ? clone(src[prop], true)
                : src[prop];
        }
    }

    return ret;
};
```

Comment: `if(!src && typeof src != "object"){`. I think that should be `||` not `&&`.

Answer (score 6):

Since [mindeavor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49695/mindeavor) stated that the object to be cloned is a 'literal-constructed' object, a solution might be to simply *generate* the object multiple times rather than cloning an instance of the object:

```
function createMyObject()
{
    var myObject =
    {
        ...
    };
    return myObject;
}

var myObjectInstance1 = createMyObject();
var myObjectInstance2 = createMyObject();
```

Answer (score 6):

I've written my own implementation. Not sure if it counts as a better solution:

```
/*
    a function for deep cloning objects that contains other nested objects and circular structures.
    objects are stored in a 3D array, according to their length (number of properties) and their depth in the original object.
                                    index (z)
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |                      depth (x)
                                         |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
                                        /_/_/_/_/_/_/_/_/_/
                                       /_/_/_/_/_/_/_/_/_/
                                      /_/_/_/_/_/_/...../
                                     /................./
                                    /.....            /
                                   /                 /
                                  /------------------
            object length (y)    /
*/
```

Following is the implementation:

```
function deepClone(obj) {
    var depth = -1;
    var arr = [];
    return clone(obj, arr, depth);
}

/**
 *
 * @param obj source object
 * @param arr 3D array to store the references to objects
 * @param depth depth of the current object relative to the passed 'obj'
 * @returns {*}
 */
function clone(obj, arr, depth){
    if (typeof obj !== "object") {
        return obj;
    }

    var length = Object.keys(obj).length; // native method to get the number of properties in 'obj'

    var result = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); // inherit the prototype of the original object
    if(result instanceof Array){
        result.length = length;
    }

    depth++; // depth is increased because we entered an object here

    arr[depth] = []; // this is the x-axis, each index here is the depth
    arr[depth][length] = []; // this is the y-axis, each index is the length of the object (aka number of props)
    // start the depth at current and go down, cyclic structures won't form on depths more than the current one
    for(var x = depth; x >= 0; x--){
        // loop only if the array at this depth and length already have elements
        if(arr[x][length]){
            for(var index = 0; index < arr[x][length].length; index++){
                if(obj === arr[x][length][index]){
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    arr[depth][length].push(obj); // store the object in the array at the current depth and length
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) result[prop] = clone(obj[prop], arr, depth);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: not working for my object, although my case is a little bit complex.

Answer (score 6):

Native JS:

```
const shallowClone = {...originalObj};
const deepClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObj));
```

Using Libraries:

```
// Lodash
const shallowClone = _.clone(originalObj);
const deepClone = _. cloneDeep(originalObj);

// JQuery
const shallowClone = jQuery.extend({}, originalObj);
const deepClone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, originalObj);

// Angular
const deepClone = angular.copy(originalObj);
```

Answer (score 5):

Jan Turoň's answer above is very close, and may be the best to use in a browser due to compatibility issues, but it will potentially cause some strange enumeration issues.  For instance, executing:

```
for ( var i in someArray ) { ... }
```

Will assign the clone() method to i after iterating through the elements of the array.  Here's an adaptation that avoids the enumeration and works with node.js:

```
Object.defineProperty( Object.prototype, "clone", {
    value: function() {
        if ( this.cloneNode )
        {
            return this.cloneNode( true );
        }

        var copy = this instanceof Array ? [] : {};
        for( var attr in this )
        {
            if ( typeof this[ attr ] == "function" || this[ attr ] == null || !this[ attr ].clone )
            {
                copy[ attr ] = this[ attr ];
            }
            else if ( this[ attr ] == this )
            {
                copy[ attr ] = copy;
            }
            else
            {
                copy[ attr ] = this[ attr ].clone();
            }
        }
        return copy;
    }
});

Object.defineProperty( Date.prototype, "clone", {
    value: function() {
        var copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime( this.getTime() );
        return copy;
    }
});

Object.defineProperty( Number.prototype, "clone", { value: function() { return this; } } );
Object.defineProperty( Boolean.prototype, "clone", { value: function() { return this; } } );
Object.defineProperty( String.prototype, "clone", { value: function() { return this; } } );
```

This avoids making the clone() method enumerable because defineProperty() defaults enumerable to false.

Answer (score 5):

Object copy using ( **...** )

```
//bad
const original = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const copy = Object.assign({}, original, { c: 3 }); // copy => { a: 1, b: 2,c: 3 }

//good
const originalObj = { id: 5, name: 'San Francisco'};
const copyObject = {...originalObj, pincode: 4444};
console.log(copyObject)  //{ id: 5, name: 'San Francisco', pincode: 4444 }
```

Same can be use for **copying array** from one to other

```
const itemsCopy = [...items];
```

Comment: Why is Object.assign way labeled as 'bad'? Could someone elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

Simple recursive method to clone an object. Also could use lodash.clone.

```js
let clone = (obj) => {
 let obj2 = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {};
 for(let k in obj) {
          obj2[k] = (typeof obj[k] === 'object' ) ? clone(obj[k]) :  obj[k];
        }
        return obj2;
    }

let w = { name: "Apple", types: ["Fuji", "Gala"]};
let x = clone(w);
w.name = "Orange";
w.types = ["Navel"];
console.log(x);
console.log(w);
```

Answer (score 4):

Consult http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#safe-passing-of-structured-data for the W3C's "Safe passing of structured data" algorithm, intended to be implemented by browsers for passing data to eg web workers. However, it has some limitations, in that it does not handle functions. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm for more information, including an alternative algorithm in JS which gets you part of the way there.

Comment: While this has some great links, it's not really an answer. If it was extended to include an implementation of the algorithms referenced it might be an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Clone an object based on a `template`. What do you do if you don't want an exact copy, but you do want the robustness of some kind of reliable clone operation but you only want bits cloned or you want to make sure you can control the existence or format of each attribute value cloned?

I am contributing this because it's useful for us and we created it because we could not find something similar. You can use it to clone an object based on a `template` object which specifies what attributes of the object I want to clone, and the template allows for functions to transform those attributes into something different if they don't exist on the source object or however you want to handle the clone. If it's not useful I am sure someone can delete this answer.

```
   function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
       var getType = {};
       return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
   }

   function cloneObjectByTemplate(obj, tpl, cloneConstructor) {
       if (typeof cloneConstructor === "undefined") {
           cloneConstructor = false;
       }
       if (obj == null || typeof (obj) != 'object') return obj;

       //if we have an array, work through it's contents and apply the template to each item...
       if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
           var ret = [];
           for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
               ret.push(cloneObjectByTemplate(obj[i], tpl, cloneConstructor));
           }
           return ret;
       }

       //otherwise we have an object...
       //var temp:any = {}; // obj.constructor(); // we can't call obj.constructor because typescript defines this, so if we are dealing with a typescript object it might reset values.
       var temp = cloneConstructor ? new obj.constructor() : {};

       for (var key in tpl) {
           //if we are provided with a function to determine the value of this property, call it...
           if (isFunction(tpl[key])) {
               temp[key] = tpl[key](obj); //assign the result of the function call, passing in the value
           } else {
               //if our object has this property...
               if (obj[key] != undefined) {
                   if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                       temp[key] = [];
                       for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
                           temp[key].push(cloneObjectByTemplate(obj[key][i], tpl[key], cloneConstructor));
                       }
                   } else {
                       temp[key] = cloneObjectByTemplate(obj[key], tpl[key], cloneConstructor);
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       return temp;
   }
```

A simple way to call it would be like this:

```
var source = {
       a: "whatever",
       b: {
           x: "yeah",
           y: "haha"
       }
   };
   var template = {
       a: true, //we want to clone "a"
       b: {
           x: true //we want to clone "b.x" too
       }
   }; 
   var destination = cloneObjectByTemplate(source, template);
```

If you wanted to use a function to make sure an attribute is returned or to make sure it's a particular type, use a template like this. Instead of using `{ ID: true }` we are providing a function which still just copies the `ID attribute` of the source object but it makes sure that it's a number even if it does not exist on the source object.

```
 var template = {
    ID: function (srcObj) {
        if(srcObj.ID == undefined){ return -1; }
        return parseInt(srcObj.ID.toString());
    }
}
```

Arrays will clone fine but if you want to you can have your own function handle those individual attributes too, and do something special like this:

```
 var template = {
    tags: function (srcObj) {
        var tags = [];
        if (process.tags != undefined) {
            for (var i = 0; i < process.tags.length; i++) {

                tags.push(cloneObjectByTemplate(
                  srcObj.tags[i],
                  { a : true, b : true } //another template for each item in the array
                );
            }
        }
        return tags;
    }
 }
```

So in the above, our template just copies the `tags` attribute of the source object if it exists, (it's assumed to be an array), and for each element in that array the clone function is called to individually clone it based on a second template which just copies the `a` and `b` attributes of each of those tag elements.

If you are taking objects in and out of node and you want to control which attributes of those objects are cloned then this is a great way of controlling that in `node.js` and the code works in the browser too.

Here is an example of it's use: http://jsfiddle.net/hjchyLt1/

Answer (score 4):

Use `deepcopy` from `npm`.  Works in both the browser and in `node` as an `npm module...`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepcopy

`let a = deepcopy(b)`

Answer (score 4):

**According to the [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#objects--rest-spread)** with 404 contributors:

> Prefer the object spread operator over Object.assign to shallow-copy
>   objects. Use the object rest operator to get a new object with certain
>   properties omitted.

```
// very bad
const original = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const copy = Object.assign(original, { c: 3 }); // this mutates `original` ಠ_ಠ
delete copy.a; // so does this

// bad
const original = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const copy = Object.assign({}, original, { c: 3 }); // copy => { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

// good
const original = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const copy = { ...original, c: 3 }; // copy => { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

const { a, ...noA } = copy; // noA => { b: 2, c: 3 }
```

**Also I'd like to warn you that even though Airbnb hardly recommends the object spread operator approach. Keep in mind that Microsoft Edge still does not support this 2018 feature yet.**

[ES2016+ Compat table >>](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/)

Answer (score 4):

Just as [this link](https://javascript.info/prototype-methods) says use this code:

```js
let clone = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj),
 Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
```

Comment: Answering questions here is good but this is an old question with many good answers. Any new answer should add significant new information and new insights into the topic. Your answer here is very brief and has no explanation, the link to an offsite page is useful but an answer should be self-contained and have enough detail if the link fails.

Comment: this is exactly the same as `Object.assign(newObj, obj)`, its a shallow copy

Answer (score 4):

Simple

```
var restore = { name:'charlesi',
age:9}
var prev_data ={
name: 'charles'
age : 10
}

var temp = JSON.stringify(prev_data)
restore = JSON.parse(temp)

restore = {
name:'charlie',
age : 12}
```

output prev_data:

```
{
name: 'charles'
age : 10
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my code I frequently define a `function (_)` to handle copies so that I can pass `by value` to functions. This code creates a deep copy but maintains inheritance. It also keeps track of sub-copies so that self-referential objects can be copied without an infinite loop. Feel free to use it.

It might not be the most elegant, but it hasn't failed me yet.

```
_ = function(oReferance) {
  var aReferances = new Array();
  var getPrototypeOf = function(oObject) {
    if(typeof(Object.getPrototypeOf)!=="undefined") return Object.getPrototypeOf(oObject);
    var oTest = new Object();
    if(typeof(oObject.__proto__)!=="undefined"&&typeof(oTest.__proto__)!=="undefined"&&oTest.__proto__===Object.prototype) return oObject.__proto__;
    if(typeof(oObject.constructor)!=="undefined"&&typeof(oTest.constructor)!=="undefined"&&oTest.constructor===Object&&typeof(oObject.constructor.prototype)!=="undefined") return oObject.constructor.prototype;
    return Object.prototype;
  };
  var recursiveCopy = function(oSource) {
    if(typeof(oSource)!=="object") return oSource;
    if(oSource===null) return null;
    for(var i=0;i<aReferances.length;i++) if(aReferances[i][0]===oSource) return aReferances[i][1];
    var Copy = new Function();
    Copy.prototype = getPrototypeOf(oSource);
    var oCopy = new Copy();
    aReferances.push([oSource,oCopy]);
    for(sPropertyName in oSource) if(oSource.hasOwnProperty(sPropertyName)) oCopy[sPropertyName] = recursiveCopy(oSource[sPropertyName]);
    return oCopy;
  };
  return recursiveCopy(oReferance);
};

// Examples:
Wigit = function(){};
Wigit.prototype.bInThePrototype = true;
A = new Wigit();
A.nCoolNumber = 7;
B = _(A);
B.nCoolNumber = 8; // A.nCoolNumber is still 7
B.bInThePrototype // true
B instanceof Wigit // true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use functional closure to gain all the benefits of a deep copy, without a deep copy. It's a very different paradigm, but works well. Instead of trying to copy an existing object, just use a function to instantiate a new object when you need one.

First, create an function that returns an object

```
function template() {
  return {
    values: [1, 2, 3],
    nest: {x: {a: "a", b: "b"}, y: 100}
  };
}
```

Then create a simple shallow copy function

```
function copy(a, b) {
  Object.keys(b).forEach(function(key) {
    a[key] = b[key];
  });
}
```

Create a new object, and copy the template's properties onto it

```
var newObject = {}; 
copy(newObject, template());
```

But the above copy step is not necessary. All you need to do is this:

```
var newObject = template();
```

Now that you have a new object, test to see what its properties are:

```
console.log(Object.keys(newObject));
```

This displays:

```
["values", "nest"]
```

Yes, those are the newObject's own properties, not references to properties on another object.
Let's just check:

```
console.log(newObject.nest.x.b);
```

This displays:

```
"b"
```

The newObject has acquired all of the template object's properties, but is free of any dependency chain.

http://jsbin.com/ISUTIpoC/1/edit?js,console

I added this example to encourage some debate, so please add some comments :)

Comment: Object.keys wasnt implemented until JavaScript 1.8.5, meaning it is not available in IE 8 and other legacy browsers. So while this answer will work great in Modern browsers, it will fail in IE 8.

So if you use this method, you must use a properly emulating Object.keys polyfill.

Answer (score 3):

I think, that **recurrence with caching** is the best what we can do it here without libraries.

And underestimated **WeakMap** comes to the problem of cycles, wherein storing  pairs of references to old and new object can help us to recreate pretty easily whole tree.

I prevented deep cloning of the DOM elements, probably you don't want to clone entire page :)

```
function deepCopy(object) {
    const cache = new WeakMap(); // Map of old - new references

    function copy(obj) {
        if (typeof obj !== 'object' ||
            obj === null ||
            obj instanceof HTMLElement
        )
            return obj; // primitive value or HTMLElement

        if (obj instanceof Date) 
            return new Date().setTime(obj.getTime());

        if (obj instanceof RegExp) 
            return new RegExp(obj.source, obj.flags);

        if (cache.has(obj)) 
            return cache.get(obj);

        const result = obj instanceof Array ? [] : {};

        cache.set(obj, result); // store reference to object before the recursive starts

        if (obj instanceof Array) {
            for(const o of obj) {
                 result.push(copy(o));
            }
            return result;
        }

        const keys = Object.keys(obj); 

        for (const key of keys)
            result[key] = copy(obj[key]);

        return result;
    }

    return copy(object);
}
```

Some tests:

```
// #1
const obj1 = { };
const obj2 = { };
obj1.obj2 = obj2;
obj2.obj1 = obj1; // Trivial circular reference

var copy = deepCopy(obj1);
copy == obj1 // false
copy.obj2 === obj1.obj2 // false
copy.obj2.obj1.obj2 // and so on - no error (correctly cloned).

// #2
const obj = { x: 0 }
const clone = deepCopy({ a: obj, b: obj });
clone.a == clone.b // true

// #3
const arr = [];
arr[0] = arr; // A little bit weird but who cares
clone = deepCopy(arr)
clone == arr // false;
clone[0][0][0][0] == clone // true;
```

NOTE: I'm using constants, for of loop, => operator and WeakMaps to create more essential code. This syntax (ES6) is supported by today's browsers

Answer (score 3):

The solution `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orig_obj)` as stated by many peers here for deep_cloning has several issues which I found, and they are listed below:

1. It discards the entries while copying whose values are `undefined` in the original object,
2. If there are some values like `Infinity`, `NaN` etc, they will be converted into `null` while copying,
3. If there is a `Date` type in the original object, it will be stringified in the cloned object (`typeof date_entry --> string`).

Found an effective way for cloning an object, and it worked well for me in all sort of scenarios. Please have a look at below code, as it has resolved all above mentioned pitfalls of `JSON.parse(...)`, yet resulting in proper deep-cloning:

```
var orig_obj = {
  string: 'my_str',
  number: 123,
  bool: false,
  nul: null,
  nested : {
    value : true
  },
  nan : NaN,
  date: new Date(), 
  undef: undefined,
  inf: Infinity,
}
console.log("original_obj before modification: ", orig_obj, "\n");
console.log(typeof orig_obj.date, "\n");

var clone_obj = Object.assign({}, orig_obj);

//this below loop will help in deep cloning and solving above issues
for(let prop in orig_obj) {
    if(typeof orig_obj[prop] === "object") {
        if(orig_obj[prop] instanceof Date)
            clone_obj[prop] = orig_obj[prop];
        else {
            clone_obj[prop] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orig_obj[prop]));
        }
    }
}

console.log("cloned_obj before modification: ", orig_obj, "\n");

clone_obj.bool = true;
clone_obj.nested.value = "false";

console.log("original_obj post modification: ", orig_obj, "\n");
console.log("cloned_obj post modification: ", clone_obj, "\n");
console.log(typeof clone_obj.date);
```

Comment: You check all the top level properties to see if they are Dates, but then you JSON stringify/parse them if they are not. What if the top level property is an object that contains a Date as one of its properties? Your solution needs to work recursively in order to catch all the possible cases of nested objects that can't be JSON.parsed.

Answer (score 3):

I have gone through all above solutions and they are quite well. However, there is another approach that you can use to clone object (with values not reference). [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
let x = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2'
}

let y = Object.assign({}, x)
y.a = "3"

console.log(x)
```

The output will be

```
{ a: '1', b: '2' }
```

Moreover, you can also clone array with the same approach.

```
clonedArray = Object.assign([], array)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this in the case of a scalar object and it works for me:

```
function binder(i) {
  return function () {
    return i;
  };
}

a=1;
b=binder(a)(); // copy value of a into b

alert(++a); // 2
alert(b); // still 1
```

Regards.

Comment: `a=1;b=a;alert(++a);alert(b); // still 1`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modern solution that doesn't have the pitfalls of `Object.assign()` (does not copy by reference):

```
const cloneObj = (obj) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((dolly, key) => {
        dolly[key] = (obj[key].constructor === Object) ?
            cloneObj(obj[key]) :
            obj[key];
        return dolly;
    }, {});
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [defaults](https://www.npmjs.com/package/defaults) (historically specific to nodejs but now usable from the browser thanks to modern JS):

```
import defaults from 'object.defaults';

const myCopy = defaults({}, myObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

To support a better understanding of copying of objects, [this illustrative jsbin may be of value](https://jsbin.com/sekarup/edit?js,console)

```
class base {
  get under(){return true}
}

class a extends base {}

const b = {
  get b1(){return true},
  b: true
}

console.log('Object assign')
let t1 = Object.create(b)
t1.x = true
const c = Object.assign(t1, new a())
console.log(c.b1 ? 'prop value copied': 'prop value gone')
console.log(c.x ? 'assigned value copied': 'assigned value gone')
console.log(c.under ? 'inheritance ok': 'inheritance gone')
console.log(c.b1 ? 'get value unchanged' : 'get value lost')
c.b1 = false
console.log(c.b1? 'get unchanged' : 'get lost')
console.log('-----------------------------------')
console.log('Object assign  - order swopped')
t1 = Object.create(b)
t1.x = true
const d = Object.assign(new a(), t1)
console.log(d.b1 ? 'prop value copied': 'prop value gone')
console.log(d.x ? 'assigned value copied': 'assigned value gone')
console.log(d.under ? 'inheritance n/a': 'inheritance gone')
console.log(d.b1 ? 'get value copied' : 'get value lost')
d.b1 = false
console.log(d.b1? 'get copied' : 'get lost')
console.log('-----------------------------------')
console.log('Spread operator')
t1 = Object.create(b)
t2 = new a()
t1.x = true
const e = { ...t1, ...t2 }
console.log(e.b1 ? 'prop value copied': 'prop value gone')
console.log(e.x ? 'assigned value copied': 'assigned value gone')
console.log(e.under ? 'inheritance ok': 'inheritance gone')
console.log(e.b1 ? 'get value copied' : 'get value lost')
e.b1 = false
console.log(e.b1? 'get copied' : 'get lost')
console.log('-----------------------------------')
console.log('Spread operator on getPrototypeOf')
t1 = Object.create(b)
t2 = new a()
t1.x = true
const e1 = { ...Object.getPrototypeOf(t1), ...Object.getPrototypeOf(t2) }
console.log(e1.b1 ? 'prop value copied': 'prop value gone')
console.log(e1.x ? 'assigned value copied': 'assigned value gone')
console.log(e1.under ? 'inheritance ok': 'inheritance gone')
console.log(e1.b1 ? 'get value copied' : 'get value lost')
e1.b1 = false
console.log(e1.b1? 'get copied' : 'get lost')
console.log('-----------------------------------')
console.log('keys, defineProperty, getOwnPropertyDescriptor')
f = Object.create(b)
t2 = new a()
f.x = 'a'
Object.keys(t2).forEach(key=> {
  Object.defineProperty(f,key,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(t2, key))
})
console.log(f.b1 ? 'prop value copied': 'prop value gone')
console.log(f.x ? 'assigned value copied': 'assigned value gone')
console.log(f.under ? 'inheritance ok': 'inheritance gone')
console.log(f.b1 ? 'get value copied' : 'get value lost')
f.b1 = false
console.log(f.b1? 'get copied' : 'get lost')
console.log('-----------------------------------')
console.log('defineProperties, getOwnPropertyDescriptors')
let g = Object.create(b)
t2 = new a()
g.x = 'a'
Object.defineProperties(g,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(t2))
console.log(g.b1 ? 'prop value copied': 'prop value gone')
console.log(g.x ? 'assigned value copied': 'assigned value gone')
console.log(g.under ? 'inheritance ok': 'inheritance gone')
console.log(g.b1 ? 'get value copied' : 'get value lost')
g.b1 = false
console.log(g.b1? 'get copied' : 'get lost')
console.log('-----------------------------------')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ways to Copy Objects in JavaScript**

1. Use the spread (`...`) syntax
2. Use the `Object.assign()` method
3. Use the `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` methods

```
const person = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
};

// using spread ...
let p1 = {
    ...person
};

// using  Object.assign() method
let p2 = Object.assign({}, person);

// using JSON
let p3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person));
```

Comment: the spread syntax is syntactical sugar (for Object.assign in this case). this answer is misleading.

Comment: For quick testing Object.assign({}, person); it's perfect

Answer (score 2):

Using the spread syntax performs a shallow copy of the object. This means that none of the nested object instances are cloned as you can see in the following example with the nested object `child`

```js
const user1 = { 
    name: 'Alex',
    address: '15th Park Avenue',
    age: 43,
    child:{
        name: 'John'
    }
}

const user2 = {...user1};

user1.child.name = 'chris';

console.log(user1);
console.log(user2);
```

To solve this nested object problem and perform a deep copy we can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObject))`

```js
const user1 = { 
    name: 'Alex',
    address: '15th Park Avenue',
    age: 43,
    child:{
        name: 'John'
    }
}

const user2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user1));

user1.child.name = 'chris';

console.log(user1);
console.log(user2);
```

Answer (score 2):

**The different**

Only copy top level: `{...object}` and `Object.assign({}, object)`

```js
let objA = {
  a: "keyA",
  b: {
    c: "keyC",
  }
}
let objB = Object.assign({}, objA); // or  {...objB}
// change objB
objB.a = "Change objA.a (top)"
console.log("objA.a (top) No Change:\n" + JSON.stringify(objA, false, 2));

objB.b.c = "change should be only for objB.b.c but it in objA.b.c"
console.log("objA.a.c second level has Change:\n" + JSON.stringify(objA, false, 2));
```

for deep copy use [`structuredClone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) 2022 or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` for old browser, easy without hack.

```js
let objA = {
  a: "keyA",
  b: {
    c: "keyC",
  }
}
let objB = typeof structuredClone == 'function' ?
  structuredClone(objA) : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objA));
// change objB
objB.a = "Change objA.a (top)"
objB.b.c = "change should be only for objB.c but it in objA.c"

console.log("objA has no Change:\n" + JSON.stringify(objA, false, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are no circular dependencies in your object, I suggest using one of the other answers or [jQuery's copy methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficent-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object/122704#122704), as they all seem quite effective.

If there are circular dependencies (i.e., two sub-objects link to each other), you are kind of screwed as there is (from a theoretical perspective) [no way to solve this issue elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/597726#597726).

Comment: Actually, Python's object serialization handles circular references by keeping track of nodes in the object graph that it has already processed. You could use that approach to implement a robust copy routine. It would be a little more work though!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which cases this doesn't work for, but it got me a copy of an array. I think its cute :) Hope it helps

```
copiedArr = origArr.filter(function(x){return true})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TypeScript, need to support older web browsers (and so can't use  `Object.assign`), and aren't using a library with a clone method build in, you can make yourself a `combine` helper in a few lines of code. It combines objects, and if you have only one, just clones it.

```
/** Creates a new object that combines the properties of the specified objects. */
function combine(...objs: {}[]) {
    const combined = {};
    objs.forEach(o => Object.keys(o).forEach(p => combined[p] = o[p]));
    return combined;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may clone your Object without modification parent Object -

```
    /** [Object Extend]*/
    ( typeof Object.extend === 'function' ? undefined : ( Object.extend = function ( destination, source ) {
        for ( var property in source )
            destination[property] = source[property];
        return destination;
    } ) );
    /** [/Object Extend]*/
    /** [Object clone]*/
    ( typeof Object.clone === 'function' ? undefined : ( Object.clone = function ( object ) {
        return this.extend( {}, object );
    } ) );
    /** [/Object clone]*/

    let myObj = {
        a:1, b:2, c:3, d:{
            a:1, b:2, c:3
        }
    };

    let clone = Object.clone( myObj );

    clone.a = 10;

    console.log('clone.a==>', clone.a); //==> 10

    console.log('myObj.a==>', myObj.a); //==> 1 // object not modified here

    let clone2 = Object.clone( clone );

    clone2.a = 20;

    console.log('clone2.a==>', clone2.a); //==> 20

    console.log('clone.a==>', clone.a); //==> 10 // object not modified here
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm providing an answer to this question, because I do not see any native, recursive implementations here that resolve the problem of `DOM` elements.

The problem there is that `<element>` has `parent` and `child` attributes, that link to other elements with `parent` and `child` values, which point back to the original `<element>`, causing either an **infinite recursive** or **cyclic redundancy**.

If your object is something safe and simple like

```
{
    '123':456
}
```

...then any other answer here will probably work.

But if you have...

```
{
    '123':<reactJSComponent>,
    '456':document.createElement('div'),
}
```

...then you need something like this:

```
    // cloneVariable() : Clone variable, return null for elements or components.
var cloneVariable = function (args) {
    const variable = args.variable;

    if(variable === null) {
            return null;
    }

    if(typeof(variable) === 'object') {
            if(variable instanceof HTMLElement || variable.nodeType > 0) {
                    return null;
            }

            if(Array.isArray(variable)) {
                    var arrayclone = [];

                    variable.forEach((element) => {
                            arrayclone.push(cloneVariable({'variable':element}));
                    });

                    return arrayclone;
            }

            var objectclone = {};

            Object.keys(variable).forEach((field) => {
                    objectclone[field] = cloneVariable({'variable':variable[field]});
            });

            return objectclone;
    }

    return variable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = {'e': 2, 'd': 8, 'b': 5};

const y = {};
for(let key in x) {
    y[key] = x[key];
}
console.log(y); // =>>> {e: 2, d: 8, b: 5}

const z = {};
Object.keys(x).forEach(key => {
    z[key] = x[key];
});
console.log(z); // =>>> {e: 2, d: 8, b: 5}

const w = {};
for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(x).length; i++) {
    w[Object.keys(x)[i]] = x[Object.keys(x)[i]];
}
console.log(w); // =>>> {e: 2, d: 8, b: 5}

const v = {};
for(let key of Object.keys(x)) {
    v[key] = x[key];
}
console.log(v); // =>>> {e: 2, d: 8, b: 5}

x['q'] = 100;   // Altering x will not affect the other objects

console.log(x); // =>>> {e: 2, d: 8, b: 5, q: 100}
console.log(y); // =>>> {e: 2, d: 8, b: 5}
console.log(z); // =>>> {e: 2, d: 8, b: 5}
console.log(w); // =>>> {e: 2, d: 8, b: 5}
console.log(v); // =>>> {e: 2, d: 8, b: 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rest operator to clone arrays or objects

```
let myObj = {1: 100, 'a': 200};

let clone = {...myObj}; 

clone.a = 300;

console.log(clone.a) // Output :- 300
console.log(myObj.a) // Output :- 200
```

Comment: Please note that this will only perform "shallow-cloning", https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals

Answer (score 1):

This makes **new copy** of your `obj` (not just reference).

```
let myCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

..Works much efficiently then the `_.cloneDeep(obj)`.

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet:

```
let clone = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj));
```

Demo:

```js
let obj = {a: 'b'};
let clone = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj));

clone.a = 'c';

console.log(obj, clone);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do is:

```
let newUser={...user};
```

Here, 'newUser' is a clone of the 'user' object.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple JavaScript Coding Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/ScriptingAutomation/Conceptual/JSCodingGuide/OOJavaScript/OOJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006539-SW3):

```
// Create an inner object with a variable x whose default
// value is 3.
function innerObj()
{
        this.x = 3;
}
innerObj.prototype.clone = function() {
    var temp = new innerObj();
    for (myvar in this) {
        // this object does not contain any objects, so
        // use the lightweight copy code.
        temp[myvar] = this[myvar];
    }
    return temp;
}

// Create an outer object with a variable y whose default
// value is 77.
function outerObj()
{
        // The outer object contains an inner object.  Allocate it here.
        this.inner = new innerObj();
        this.y = 77;
}
outerObj.prototype.clone = function() {
    var temp = new outerObj();
    for (myvar in this) {
        if (this[myvar].clone) {
            // This variable contains an object with a
            // clone operator.  Call it to create a copy.
            temp[myvar] = this[myvar].clone();
        } else {
            // This variable contains a scalar value,
            // a string value, or an object with no
            // clone function.  Assign it directly.
            temp[myvar] = this[myvar];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

// Allocate an outer object and assign non-default values to variables in
// both the outer and inner objects.
outer = new outerObj;
outer.inner.x = 4;
outer.y = 16;

// Clone the outer object (which, in turn, clones the inner object).
newouter = outer.clone();

// Verify that both values were copied.
alert('inner x is '+newouter.inner.x); // prints 4
alert('y is '+newouter.y); // prints 16
```

Steve

Comment: Object attributes which did not have a clone method would be shallow-copied by this code. Thus, changes to the original can affect the copy. So this will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//
// creates 'clone' method on context object
//
//  var 
//     clon = Object.clone( anyValue );
//
!((function (propertyName, definition) {
    this[propertyName] = definition();
}).call(
    Object,
    "clone",
    function () {
        function isfn(fn) {
            return typeof fn === "function";
        }

        function isobj(o) {
            return o === Object(o);
        }

        function isarray(o) {
            return Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === "[object Array]";
        }

        function fnclon(fn) {
            return function () {
                fn.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        }

        function owns(obj, p) {
            return obj.hasOwnProperty(p);
        }

        function isemptyobj(obj) {
            for (var p in obj) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function isObject(o) {
            return Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === "[object Object]";
        }
        return function (input) {
            if (isfn(input)) {
                return fnclon(input);
            } else if (isobj(input)) {
                var cloned = {};
                for (var p in input) {
                    owns(Object.prototype, p)
                    || (
                        isfn(input[p])
                        && ( cloned[p] = function () { return input[p].apply(input, arguments); } )
                        || ( cloned[p] = input[p] )
                    );
                }
                if (isarray(input)) {
                    cloned.length = input.length;
                    "concat every filter forEach indexOf join lastIndexOf map pop push reduce reduceRight reverse shift slice some sort splice toLocaleString toString unshift"
                    .split(" ")
                    .forEach(
                      function (methodName) {
                        isfn( Array.prototype[methodName] )
                        && (
                            cloned[methodName] =
                            function () {
                                return Array.prototype[methodName].apply(cloned, arguments);
                            }
                        );
                      }
                    );
                }
                return isemptyobj(cloned)
                       ? (
                          isObject(input)
                          ? cloned
                          : input
                        )
                       : cloned;
            } else {
                return input;
            }
        };
    }
));
//
```

Comment: Why would this answer be better than any of the other ones?

Comment: Did you get this from any framework or library, or did you create this?  I don't know, it just doesn't seem as readable to me.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this page due to the same question but I'm neither using JQuery and none of the clone-Methods worked for my own objects.

I'm aware my answer isn't related too strong to this question because it's a different approach. Instead of using clone-functions I use a create function. It worked for me for the following (unfortunately restricting) purposes:

1. I use mostly JSP-generated Javascript
2. I know in the beginning which Object must be generated (In my case it's Information from a Database which gets fetched once and needs to be deployed more often in the JS.

First I defined my Objects like this:

```
var obj= new Object();
obj.Type='Row';
obj.ID=1;
obj.Value='Blah blah';
```

Now I moved everything like:

```
function getObjSelektor(id_nummer,selected){
var obj = document.createElement("select");
obj.setAttribute("id","Selektor_"+id_nummer);
obj.setAttribute("name","Selektor");
obj.setAttribute("size","1");

var obj_opt_1 = document.createElement("option");
obj_opt_1.setAttribute("value","1");
if(1==selected)
    posopval_opt_1.setAttribute("selected","selected");
obj_opt_1.innerHTML="Blah blah";
obj.appendChild(obj_opt_1);

var obj_opt_2 = document.createElement("option");
obj_opt_2.setAttribute("value","2");
if(2==selected)
    obj_opt_2.setAttribute("selected","selected");
obj_opt_2.innerHTML="2nd Row";
obj.appendChild(obj_opt_2);

...

return obj;
}
```

And call the function in the regular code:

```
myDiv.getObjSelektor(getObjSelektor(anotherObject.ID));
```

As said this is a different approach which solved my issue for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you got an Object with Functions you can do it with JSONfn, see http://www.eslinstructor.net/jsonfn/.

```
var obj= {
    name:'Marvin',
    getName :  function(){
      return this.name;
    }
}
var cobj = JSONfn.parse(JSONfn.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with copying an object that, eventually, may point at itself, can be solved with a simple check. Add this check, every time there is a copy action. It may be **slow**, but it *should* work.

I use a **toType()** function to return the object type, explicitly. I also have my own **copyObj()** function, which is rather similar in logic, which answers all three Object(), Array(), and Date() cases.

I run it in NodeJS.

**NOT TESTED, YET.**

```
// Returns true, if one of the parent's children is the target.
// This is useful, for avoiding copyObj() through an infinite loop!
function isChild(target, parent) {
  if (toType(parent) == '[object Object]') {
    for (var name in parent) {
      var curProperty = parent[name];

      // Direct child.
      if (curProperty = target) return true;

      // Check if target is a child of this property, and so on, recursively.
      if (toType(curProperty) == '[object Object]' || toType(curProperty) == '[object Array]') {
        if (isChild(target, curProperty)) return true;
      }
    }
  } else if (toType(parent) == '[object Array]') {
    for (var i=0; i < parent.length; i++) {
      var curItem = parent[i];

      // Direct child.
      if (curItem = target) return true;

      // Check if target is a child of this property, and so on, recursively.
      if (toType(curItem) == '[object Object]' || toType(curItem) == '[object Array]') {
        if (isChild(target, curItem)) return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;     // Not the target.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle circular objects that that `JSON.stringify` can't handle, you can bring in a library called [JSOG](https://github.com/jsog/jsog), that serializes and deserializes arbitrary graphs into JSON format.

```
var clone = JSOG.parse(JSOG.stringify(original));
```

It might also be interesting to try patching JSOG for cloning with this trick (don't have time at the moment, but if someone wants to give it a shot...):

Serialize a simple function :

```
foo.f = function(a) { return a }
var stringForm = foo.f.toString() // "function (a) { return a }"
```

Deserialize a function :

```
eval("foo.f = " + stringForm)
```

Some conventions (probably in the name of the property) to identify functions vs regular strings would be needed (`@func_f` perhaps).

Of course if the function calls a second function the second function will need to exist just as it would for the original.

The above however is quite dangerous if you are to accept the serialized form from an untrusted source, but then accepting any function in any form from an untrusted source would be dangerous, so if you're interested in cloning functions trust must have already been established (or you're already intent on writing a security flaw!).

**Disclaimer:** I have not tested the speed of JSOG stringify/parse vs JSON stringify/parse, but It does work on the simple (circular) objects I tested it with.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this might be the very best option for shallow copying.  If follows the many examples using assign, but it also keeps the inheritance and prototype. It's so simple too and works for most array-like and Objects except those with constructor requirements or read-only properties. But that means it fails miserably for TypedArrays, RegExp, Date, Maps, Sets and Object versions of primitives (Boolean, String, etc..).

```
function copy ( a ) { return Object.assign( new a.constructor, a ) }
```

Where `a` can be any Object or class constructed instance, but again not be reliable for thingies that use specialized getters and setters or have constructor requirements, but for more simple situations it rocks.  It does work on arguments as well.

You can also apply it to primitives to get strange results, but then...  unless it just ends up being a useful hack, who cares.

results from basic built-in Object and Array...

```
> a = { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C', d: 'D' }
{ a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C', d: 'D' }
> b = copy( a )
{ a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C', d: 'D' }
> a = [1,2,3,4]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
> b = copy( a )
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

And fails because of mean get/setters, constructor required arguments or read-only properties, and sins against the father.

```
> a = /\w+/g
/\w+/g
> b = copy( a )  // fails because source and flags are read-only
/(?:)/
> a = new Date ( '1/1/2001' )
2000-12-31T16:00:00.000Z
> b = copy( a )  // fails because Date using methods to get and set things
2017-02-04T14:44:13.990Z
> a = new Boolean( true )
[Boolean: true]
> b = copy( a )  // fails because of of sins against the father
[Boolean: false]
> a = new Number( 37 )
[Number: 37]
> b = copy( a )  // fails because of of sins against the father
[Number: 0]
> a = new String( 'four score and seven years ago our four fathers' )
[String: 'four score and seven years ago our four fathers']
> b = copy( a )  // fails because of of sins against the father
{ [String: ''] '0': 'f', '1': 'o', '2': 'u', '3': 'r', '4': ' ', '5': 's', '6': 'c', '7': 'o', '8': 'r', '9': 'e', '10': ' ', '11': 'a', '12': 'n', '13': 'd', '14': ' ', '15': 's', '16': 'e', '17': 'v', '18': 'e', '19': 'n', '20': ' ', '21': 'y', '22': 'e', '23': 'a', '24': 'r', '25': 's', '26': ' ', '27': 'a', '28': 'g', '29': 'o', '30': ' ', '31': 'o', '32': 'u', '33': 'r', '34': ' ', '35': 'f', '36': 'o', '37': 'u', '38': 'r', '39': ' ', '40': 'f', '41': 'a', '42': 't', '43': 'h', '44': 'e', '45': 'r', '46': 's' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know it has many answers, but no one pointed out, EcmaScript5 has assign method, work on FF and Chrome, it copies enumerable and own properties and  Symbols.

[Object Assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: No support in IE :(

Comment: Why you need to support a browser that does not exist anymore? Seriously, you don't need to worry, at least is what we do here, just don't support and alert the user if he is using any IE version.

Comment: I simply switched to JSON.parse approach mentioned here instead. But yes, IE seems troublesome. I had to also change find and findIndex to lodash functions.

Comment: @Naomi Because IE does exists and is unfortunately still a popular enough browser even in 2017. Maybe not for tech-savy users like us, but people still use it. And considering it's not even supported in IE 11, that's a BIG drawback!

Answer (score 0):

If your object is a class (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```
var copiedObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, originalObject);
copiedObject.__proto__ = originalObject.__proto__;
```

Then in `copiedObject` you have a deep-copied instance of `originalObject` class with all its methods.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to clone object with functions (break multiple lines to easier understand):

```js
const clone = Object.assign(
    Object.create(
        Object.getPrototypeOf(originalObject)
    ),
    dataObject
);
```

Answer (score 0):

*To add*

- For **comparing** the result of 
  **`structuredClone() -- deep copy` & `Object.assign() -- shallow copy`** (&
  `Object.keys() -- shallow copy`) 
  -- to see **which level of the object** are copied 
  here is a **demo test case** -- with a depth of 4 lv::
- @code-ex::

  ```js
      // lv4
      class Material {
        /** @type {String} */ name;
        constructor(name) { this.name = name; } // prettier-ignore
      }
      // lv3
      class Ball {
        /** @type {String} */ name;
        constructor(name) { this.name = name; } // prettier-ignore
        /** @type {Material} */ material;
      }

      // lv2
      class NodeX {
        /** @type {String} */ name;
        constructor(name) { this.name = name; } // prettier-ignore
        /** @type {Ball} */ ball;
        /** @type {NodeX} */ node_next;
      }

      // lv1
      class ListX {
        /** @type {NodeX} */ node_head;
        /** @type {Number} */ length = 0;
      }

      const material_a = new Material('wood');
      const material_b = new Material('stone');
      const ball_a = new Ball('Ball_I');
      const ball_b = new Ball('Ball_II');
      ball_a.material = material_a;
      ball_b.material = material_b;

      const node_a = new NodeX('Alpha');
      const node_b = new NodeX('Beta');
      node_a.ball = ball_a;
      node_b.ball = ball_b;

      const list = new ListX();
      list.node_head = node_a;
      list.length++;
      node_a.node_next = node_b;
      list.length++;

      // #>> structuredClone() -- deep copy
      const list_clone = structuredClone(list); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object
      test_DeepCopy_compare(list_clone, list);

      // #>>#
      function test_DeepCopy_compare(list_clone, list) {
        expect(list_clone === list).toEqual(false); // the list is cloned - lv1
        expect(list_clone.length === list.length).toEqual(true);

        expect(list_clone.node_head === list.node_head).toEqual(false); // the node (list es property) is also cloned -- deep copy - lv2

        const node_a_clone = list_clone.node_head;
        expect(node_a_clone === node_a).toEqual(false); // ~rp
        expect(node_a_clone.name === node_a.name).toEqual(true);
        expect(node_a_clone.node_next === node_a.node_next).toEqual(false); // the node_next (node es property) is also cloned -- deep copy - lv3

        const node_b_clone = node_a_clone.node_next;
        expect(node_b_clone === node_b).toEqual(false); // ~rp
        expect(node_b_clone.name === node_b.name).toEqual(true);
        expect(node_b_clone.node_next === undefined && node_b.node_next === undefined).toEqual(true);

        expect(node_a_clone.ball === node_a.ball).toEqual(false); // aga, the ball (node es property) is also cloned -- deep copy - lv3
        expect(node_b_clone.ball === node_b.ball).toEqual(false);

        const ball_a_clone = node_a_clone.ball;
        const ball_b_clone = node_b_clone.ball;
        expect(ball_a_clone.material === ball_a.material).toEqual(false); // aga, the material (ball es property) is also cloned -- deep copy - lv4
        expect(ball_b_clone.material === ball_b.material).toEqual(false);
      }

      // #>> Object.assign() -- shallow copy
      const list_clone_ScOa = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(list)); // const list_clone_ScOa = {}; // https://stackoverflow.com/a/43935938/9549068
      Object.assign(list_clone_ScOa, list); // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#return_value
      test_ShallowCopy_compare(list_clone_ScOa, list); // Object.assign() & Object.keys() produce same test result

      // #>> Object.keys() -- shallow copy
      function shallowCopy_ObjectKeys(obj) {
        const obj_clone = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); // const obj_clone = {};
        for (const propName of Object.keys(obj)) {
          obj_clone[propName] = obj[propName];
        }
        return obj_clone;
      }

      const list_clone_ScOk = shallowCopy_ObjectKeys(list);
      test_ShallowCopy_compare(list_clone_ScOk, list);

      // #>>#
      function test_ShallowCopy_compare(list_clone_ScOkOa, list) {
        expect(list_clone_ScOkOa === list).toEqual(false); // the list is cloned - lv1
        expect(list_clone_ScOkOa.length === list.length).toEqual(true);

        expect(list_clone_ScOkOa.node_head === list.node_head).toEqual(true); // the node (list es property) is NOT cloned -- shallow copy - lv2

        const node_a_clone_ScOkOa = list_clone_ScOkOa.node_head;
        expect(node_a_clone_ScOkOa === node_a).toEqual(true); // ~rp
        expect(node_a_clone_ScOkOa.name === node_a.name).toEqual(true);
        expect(node_a_clone_ScOkOa.node_next === node_a.node_next).toEqual(true); // the node_next (node es property) is NOT cloned -- shallow copy - lv3

        const node_b_clone_ScOk = node_a_clone_ScOkOa.node_next;
        expect(node_b_clone_ScOk === node_b).toEqual(true); // ~rp

        expect(node_a_clone_ScOkOa.ball === node_a.ball).toEqual(true); // aga, the ball (node es property) is NOT cloned -- shallow copy - lv3
        expect(node_b_clone_ScOk.ball === node_b.ball).toEqual(true);

        expect(list_clone_ScOkOa instanceof ListX).toEqual(true);
      }
  ```
- @comment::

  for Es6 class, seems **`private / static members` are not copied**.

  maybe build yourself a own `clone()` method for your Es6 class is the best way

  For more, see: // https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546221/9549068 // https://stackoverflow.com/a/65024713/9549068

Answer (score -2):

My favorite & elegant JS objects **clone** solution is

```
function CloneObject() {}
function cloneObject(o) {
   CloneObject.prototype = o;
   return new CloneObject();
}
```

Use `cloneObject(object)` to get a clone of JS object.

Unlike many **copy** solutions this clone keeps prototype relationship in cloned object.

Comment: I think this not answer the question posted by the op.

`code` 
var o1 = {a: 1}
var o2 = cloneObject(o1)
o2.b = 2
console.log(o1) // will be {a:1, b:2}
`code`

Comment: This is the same as [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create "Object.create - JavaScript | MDN").

Comment: This is prototypal inheritance, not cloning.

Comment: @d13—for many, this is cloning. Copying properties is copying.

Comment: Can you be sure that the implementation will *always* copy the prototype reference into the instance right there at instantiation time? I am not claiming it won't, but I have doubt. Anyway, this is just making an empty object with the original as the prototype, which is not the same. If you were not going to modify anything, then you don't need to clone, and if you want to preserve a snapshot, it won't work either because the properties of the prototype are going to be changing because the prototype *is* the original object.

Comment: @RobG - as you say: "Copying properties is copying". Exactly...and this **doesn't** copy them. It just references the old ones...no copy is made. There's still only 1 property, and if you change it then you'll see that change in all locations that reference it too. That's why this is not cloning.

Comment: @JimboJonny—please read the OP, the term used is "clone", not "copy", hence the distinction. There is no definition of the term so it's just semantics anyway.

Comment: @RobG - Sorry for the lateness, never checked the response until now. To "clone" actually does have a definition. It is to create an exact replication of something. By no definition is simply referencing something considered a "clone" _or_ a "copy." If a replication does not exist (i.e. another distinct entity) then a cloning hasn't occurred. That is the definition of a "clone." The fact that you or others may have been looking for something other than replication when searching for "cloning" just means you were using the word wrong when searching, and doesn't change those facts.

Comment: @JimboJonny—yes a long time! My distinction is that a [*clone*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning) means a genetic copy, not an exact copy. Simply coping the enumerable properties of one object to another makes a copy in the same way `a = 'a'; b = a;` makes a copy of `'a'`. Setting two objects to have the same `[[Prototype]]` gives them the same genetic makeup, so a clone, in the same way identical twins have identical DNA, but are different entities and are not exact copies of each other (e.g. they usually have different personalities and are not exactly identical in appearance).

Comment: @RobG - You talk about how twins are "different entities." That's the issue with what you're saying. Setting the prototype does not make for a different entity. It just references the old one. *And* notice in the article you cite, that that type of "cloning" is just one type. In the first line of the article there is a link to disambiguation (the term "clone" existed before genetic cloning). In there is a link to the programming version of "clone," where it clearly states it is a copy, and even has a section about making pointers/references specifically to point out how that is not a clone.

Comment: @RobG - TL;DR version: "clone" is an actual computer science term with a specific meaning. It is not just a term we're borrowing for the sake of this question. One of the major points *of* that term is *specifically* to differentiate from pointers/references. Not to include them. From the article on cloning: _"The process of actually making another exact replica of the object instead of just its reference is called cloning."_

Answer (score -3):

```
function clone(obj)
{
    var cloneObj = Object.create(obj);

    return cloneObj;
}
```

In Javascript objects individually inherit another object (Prototypal inheritance). Object.create(obj) returns an object that is a sub-object or child object of obj. In the above function it will effectively return a copy of the object.

However, This is a very odd way to clone because I am not using inheritance for its real purpose.

Comment: This is prototypal inheritance, not cloning. The new object has none of it's own properties, it simply uses those on the prototype.

Comment: @d13 I dont need new properties on the new object, i just want properties of the parent object in the new one, so why not inherit?

Comment: that can be very useful, but it's not cloning, which is what this topic is about. Cloning is where you explcitly copy the properties of an object into another object so that the new object no longer references properties on a prototype. The reason for doing this is to prevent confusion about whether a property belongs to an object or its prototype. That confusion can lead to hard-to-diagnose bugs if you're not certain of this behaviour. [Check this JSBin example and explanation](http://jsbin.com/EKivInO/2/edit?js,console).

Comment: @Shuaib - because if you change the property values on the original object they'll change on the new object...they aren't separated...the new object doesn't "have" those properties, it's just referencing the old object.  ...  Which means you might as well just go `var cloned = otherObj;` and make a reference that way. In both cases the only reason the new variable has references to the old object is because it's literally a pointer to it. One's just the point itself while the other holds the pointer on the prototype.

Comment: @JimboJonny how about recursive Object.create() ?

Comment: @l00k - I'm not sure of the exact method you mean when talking about doing it recursively, but no matter what the result should be the same. `Object.create` makes a new object that references the object supplied to it as that new object's prototype. It doesn't clone stuff. Change the values of the old object and they will change in the prototype of the new one (because the prototype of the new one literally IS the old one, that's quite literally what `Object.create` is for).