# How do I keep a session variable from changing?

Tags: node.js, express

So I've got a session variable, req.session.user, that contains an object corresponding to a user account. When I do this,

```
var user = req.session.user;
var fakeUser = user;
fakeUser.username = 'bob';
```

user.username and req.session.user.username both get changed to 'bob' as well. How do I prevent this?

Comment: You mean you need a "copy of value" instead of "copy of reference"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone it

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `var fakeUser = user` you copy reference to the object user - `fakeUser` is still referencing the same object.

If you want copy the object, you have to clone it or copy only desired properties of the user: e.g.:

```
var fakeUser = {
  name: user.name,
  id: user.id
}
```

JS clonning is described in following answers:

[answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089081/2203164)
[answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089226/2203164)

You can also use a [clone method](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) of underscore library  (But be aware that it does just a shallow copy (not deep) - i.e. if user object contains some references, they are copied as references).

Simple method to clone object is to just serialize and deserilaze it (but this will not work on circular references - when object is referencing itself or it's part):

```
function clone(a) {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

Comment: Could you explain cloning?

Comment: i've added a link to a question about clonning. Clonning means that you copy all properties of the object as values (primitive types are copied this way using = ), not just reference (objects are copied this way using = ).

Comment: I know, but you will face problems if you are not the creator of the object. @zavg's answer is the right way to do. By explain I meant please say if there is a function to do that or you have to do it manually. Sorry, I wasn't clear.

Comment: I've added some links to answer.