# Javascript assigning an array object to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Today I have faced a new issue while coding in NodeJS I was fetching a record from DB which is an object which will contain an object array as well and I have assigned object array to a new variable lets call **arr** and I pushed a string into  **arr**. And for some strange reasons, my original record also affected not sure why it has happened. I know about changing/reassigning an object will affect the original object but in this case am not sure why it has happened.

```
let original = {
  a: 1,
  branchIds: [ {
    _id: "abc",
    name: "abc"
   }]
};
let arr = original.branchIds;
arr.push("sa");
console.log(original);
```

JsFiddle Link
http://jsfiddle.net/jdqmLzbv/4/

Comment: Your setting the variable `arr` to original.branchIds, so by calling `.push` on `arr` it's pushing another item into the array of variable `original`. What is unclear about this?

Comment: @RyanWilson am pushing a new item on arr not to the original that is what am unclear about

Comment: But it *is* the original. Just assigning it to the variable does nothing. The value of an object is its reference, so you're pushing to the same array.

Comment: @Kannan By setting `arr` = `original.branchIds` you are giving it a reference to the array held by `original` so any changes made affect the original, Zohaib's answer explains it along with a solution.

Comment: @RyanWilson got it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using same reference and actually pushing into same array. Make a copy of it and orignal will not get updated

```js
let original = {
  a: 1,
  branchIds: [ {
    _id: "abc",
    name: "abc"
   }]
};
let arr = original.branchIds.map(obj => ({...obj}));
arr.push("sa");
console.log(original);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: No, simple slice will use same objects inside and if one updates those objects, orignal array will get changed

Comment: I see, I overlooked that.

Comment: @Li357 it happens :)

Comment: What does the spread operator will do here? How it will solve this issue can you please explain?

Comment: You need to make a copy of contained objects, so either you can make a copy using spread operator or use `Object.assign({}, obj)` . I hope it answers your question

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz What about Xiaoy312 answer? That works as well

Comment: @Kannan Yeah it works in your scenario where you are not updating existing objects but if someones wants to update existing objects as well, he need to make a copy of all existing objects as well

Comment: Ok Thanks @ZohaibIjaz

Answer (score 3):

You need to a copy of the array before modifying it:

```
let arr = original.branchIds.slice();
```

Comment: Updating the already exiting items will update in orignal array as well

Comment: Indeed, as the new array still holds references to the very same object. If you need a deep copy, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089058/nodejs-how-to-clone-a-object

Comment: So what is the difference if i assign with .slice() method?. Could you please explain?

Comment: Try `arr[0].name = "qqq"` with both method and you will see the difference. This is because they references the same object: [Shallow copy VS Deep copy](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*6fjXVjxrpLWB_U3Gkz51MQ.png)