# Simple question about clone in javascript

Tags: javascript, clone, deep-copy

I have a Point

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};
```

As you see, it's mutable. So I can change it properties, like

```
 var p = new Point(2, 3);
 p.x = 6;
```

I want to add clone method so that expected behavior would be

```
 var p1 = new Point(2, 3);
 var p2 = p1.clone();
 p1.x = 6;

 assert p1 != p2;     //first assertion. pseudocode.
 assert p2.x == 2;    //second assertion. pseudocode.
```

For implementing `clone()` I rewrite Point in next way

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.clone = function () {
        function TrickyConstructor() {
        }
        TrickyConstructor.prototype = this;
        return new TrickyConstructor();
    };
};
```

But second assertion fails for my implementation. How should I reimplement it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Deep clone in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the properties are only `x` and `y`, I would do this:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Point.prototype.clone = function() {
    return new Point(this.x, this.y);
}
```

Note that I attach the `clone` method to `Point.prototype`. This is important for the next method to work:

If not, you would have to create a new instance and maybe copy all properties to the new instance:

```
Point.prototype.clone = function() {
    var clone = new Point(this.x, this.y);
    for(var prop in this) {
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            clone[prop] = this[prop];
        }
    }
    return clone;
}
```

but this will **not** deep copy properties. This only works for primitive values.

If you really want to *deep copy* properties, this can get much more complex. Luckily, this has already been asked before: [How to Deep clone in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)

---

Explanation of why your clone method does not work:

The prototype chain of `p2` will look like this:

```
 +-----------+      +-----------+
 |Instance p2|      |Instance p1|
 |           |----->|x=2        |
 |           |      |y=3        |
 +-----------+      +-----------+
```

so if you set `p1.x = 6` it will be:

```
 +-----------+      +-----------+
 |Instance p2|      |Instance p1|
 |           |----->|x=6        |
 |           |      |y=3        |
 +-----------+      +-----------+
```

As long as `p2` has no **own** `x` or `y` properties, they will always refer to the ones of the prototype which happens to be `p1`.

Comment: Thanks, but actually this question about general technique, not just solving this particular issue.

Comment: @StasKurilin: Then this question was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.clone = function () {
        var newPoint = {};
        for (var key in this) {
            newPoint[key] = this[key];
        }
        return newPoint;
    };
};
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/HPtmk/

Comment: Toss in a *if (typeof this[key] == 'function') continue;* No need to clone methods.

Comment: @amadeus - It's not cloning the fields, just assigning (and the assignment is necessary in this case, because `newPoint` does not start as a `Point` instance).  It behaves as a deep-copy in this case because the source object only has two primitive fields.  To do a proper deep copy it would need to check for `Object` and `Array` types and recurse through them.

Comment: You are right. But why would you start from a blank object. Wouldn't that be a waste of space if you had many Points each with many methods? Why can't I insert @aroth at the beginning of the comment?

Comment: @amadeus - Starting from the blank object uses no more space than starting from a `Point`.  The `clone` method is not copied, just the reference to it.  The same exact thing happens if you do `new Point(x, y)`, the new instance gets a copy of the reference to the original definition of `clone()`.  You can see this in the fiddle by testing if `p1.clone == p2.clone`, as shown here:  http://jsfiddle.net/HPtmk/1

Comment: @amadeus: Regarding the @ see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446 (2011-07-01)