# How to disable pointers usage in JS?

Tags: javascript, json, pointers, reference

Why is the result `{"a":"b","c":1}`?

```
var foo = {"a":"b","c":0};
var bar = foo;
bar.c++;
alert(JSON.stringify(foo));
```

How to disable this behavior?

Comment: What result are you expecting instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Deep clone in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)

Comment: @Quentin. I'm not sure it's a duplicated, though it answer his question.

Comment: @Quentin: That may be how to *answer* this question, but it's not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is making a second reference to an object but what it seems you want is a *copy* of that object instead.

If you want that functionality then you really want a copy function that copies all of the properties, one by one, into a new object:

```
// Take all the properties of 'obj' and copy them to a new object,
// then return that object
function copy(obj) {
  var a = {};
  for (var x in obj) a[x] = obj[x];
  return a;
}

var foo = {"a":"b","c":0};
var bar = copy(foo);
bar.c++;
alert(JSON.stringify(foo));
```

and you'll get `{"a":"b","c":0}`

Answer (score 4):

Both `foo` and `bar` variables reference the same object. It doesn't matter which reference you use to modify that object.

You cannot *disable* that behaviour, this is how JavaScript and many other major languages work. All you can do is to clone the object explicitly.

```
var foo = {"a":"b","c":0};
var bar = {"a":foo.a, "c": foo.c};
bar.c++;
```

Answer (score 3):

First, Javascript doesn't pass pointers, it passes references, slightly different. Secondly, **there's no way to modify Javascript's default behavior**, <strike>unfortunately</strike> fortunately.

What you might want to do is create a constructor and use that to create two similar, but separate instances of an object.

```
function Foo(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

var bar1 = new Foo(0, 0);
var bar2 = new Foo(0, 0);
bar2.b++;

console.log(bar1);
console.log(bar2);

>> {a:0, b:0};
>> {a:0, b:1};
```

Comment: in **this** case `unfortunately` => `fortunately`

Comment: Well, I agree with you, but it's unfortunate for the OP. Heh.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't disable the way javascript works.**

If you change a reference object, it effects all the object references...