# javascript delete keyword not working properly

Tags: javascript

This is really weird I think, I have this `json` being sent through http.

```
{
   "foo":"bar",
   "foo2":"bar2",
   "name":{
       "firstName":"Joff",
       "middleName":"Ramirez",
       "lastName":"Tiquez"
   }
}
```

On the server I was performing these commands:

```
var data = req.body; // the json from http
console.log('data', data); // the data now has the req.body's value 
delete data.name; // <-- here's the delete
console.log('data', data); // the name object will obviously be deleted
console.log('req.body', req.body); // the name on the req.body was deleted too. Wtf?
```

So when I tried to use the `req.body.name` on the other parts of my program, the `name` is now gone. Is that how `delete` is supposed to work?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference, `reqBody` is the same object as the `data`

Comment: WhyTH down vote? HAHA, It's a pretty valid question. lol

Comment: @Dellirium what do you mean "passed by reference"? So am not creating a new object when I passed req.body to data? Wow, my whole life was a lie. LOL

Comment: Thanks guys! This is really mind blowing. LOL

Comment: When you "set the value" of a variable to an object, what you are doing is setting a pointer to a location in memory. So if you have an object, and you set `reqBody` to be that object, you are only copying the `address`. Then later you copy the address into `data`. After that you access `data` and remove the `name` from that address, but `reqBody` is still REFERENCING the same location in memory. There is only 1 object in your memory, and 2 variables each holding the same address to that object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
delete data.name; // <-- here's the delete
```

Now when you do a

```
console.log('req.body', req.body); // This won't be deleted.
```

As pointed out by @Dellirium, **Objects are passed by reference, reqBody is the same object as the data**

Comment: Thanks for adding a alternative solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is that how delete is supposed to work?

Yes. `delete` deletes properties from objects.

… but that isn't where your confusion is coming from.

> ```
> var data = req.body;
> ```

The assignment operator copies the *value* of `req.body` and that value is a **reference** to an object (JS only ever gives you a reference to an object to play with).

When you copy that reference to `data` you have two references pointing to the **same object**. When you delete a property from the object, it is removed from the object and it doesn't matter which reference to that object you use.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript) for some information about making a deep copy of an object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save data in other variable 1 by 1 object if you want to delete in same way.

Because when you use any object to assign in other object then value assign by reference. for more please check-  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

For your problem solution put values 1 by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Delete keyword deletes the property of the instance itself.

EDIT: Objects are passed by reference. Consider copying the object, so the changes you do will only affect the object you're changing.