# Why does cloning JS objects more then 1 level deep break immutability in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Take the following example of a simple deep nested JS object:

```
customer: {
    email: '',
    address: {
        addressLines: [''],
        postcode: '',
        city: ''
    }
}
```

The following update does not trigger a state mutation in reduxImmutableStateInvariant:

```
let objectToUpdate =  {
  address: {
    addressLines: customer.address.addressLines,
    postcode: value,
    city: customer.address.city
  }
};
customer = Object.assign({}, customer, objectToUpdate);
```

Where as this update does trigger a state mutation error:

```
customer.address['postcode'] = value;
```

And one level deep does not:

```
customer['email'] = value;
```

When needing to preform updates to state that are more than 1 level deep the only approach is to use [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) or [immutable-js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) or to roll your own [comprehensive bespoke solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)?

Thanks

Comment: Because Object.assign only work on the current obj  not its nested objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.assign doesn't make deep copies. There are several alternatives you could consider, for example the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) mention https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper. There's also [object-assign-deep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign-deep)

Good article here: https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c#.awnjvns82