# clone a decoupled version of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to clone and object, then make changes to the original object and do some tests encase the test fails restore the clone back.

Currently I've tried `_.clone` (underscore), `angular.extend`, `angular.merge`, `angular.copy`, `Object.create`, `Object.assign`, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))`,  but somehow my changes in the original object gets reflected back into the clone.

Comment: Maybe you need a [deep clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)?

Comment: `_.clone` does shallow copy of the object, but you need a deep copy. Try `_.cloneDeep` instead.

Comment: unfortunately we are not using lodash, i've tried to use angular equivalent but all of them reflect the change

Comment: `var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))` may help?

Comment: @BenAston didnt :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shallow copy an object in vanilla JavaScript using `Object.assign`.

```js
// Shallow copy an object in vanilla JS
let oldObj = {
  name: 'Joe',
  favColor: 'Green',
}

// Shallow copy oldObj to the newObj using assign
var newObj = Object.assign({}, oldObj);

// Changes made to the new object are not reflected in the new object
newObj.favFood = 'pizza';
console.log(oldObj.favFood); // undefined
```

To perform a "deep copy", you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))`.

```js
let oldObj = {
  name: 'Joe',
  favColor: 'Green',
  favPizza: {
    cheese: true,
    pepperoni: false,
  },
};

// Deep copy an object using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj));

// Changes made to the new object are not reflected in the new object
newObj.favPizza.sausage = true;
console.log(oldObj.favPizza.sausage); //undefined
```

Reference:

- [Object.assign() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: I did { originalPizza : Object.assign({}, pizza) }, but when i made changes to pizza toppings it got reflected into original pizza.

Comment: @ArashKiani - I added an example for performing both a "shallow copy" and a "deep copy." I hope it helps!