# JavaScript scoping (copying one array to another)

Tags: javascript, arrays

In this code... `mapObj.fetchTimeObjs` should NOT change right?!?!
Somehow `mapObj.fetchTimeObjs` gets changed when this function is run:

```
function clockErasePast(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var tmpFetchTimeObjs = [];
    for(var i =0; i<mapObj.fetchTimeObjs.length; i++){
        tmpFetchTimeObjs.push(mapObj.fetchTimeObjs[i]);
        if(mapObj.fetchTimeObjs[i].start < now){tmpFetchTimeObjs[i].start = now;}
    }
    return tmpFetchTimeObjs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`tmpFetchTimeObjs[i]` 
will contain only reference to the `mapObj.fetchTimeObjs[i]`.

If you will change `tmpFetchTimeObjs[i]`, the `mapObj.fetchTimeObjs[i]` will be changed, because you will have only **one** object which has **two** references. And if it will changed from one reference, it will be changed for the second reference too.

Let's consider an object which has two references. Here I change the object from one reference, and get the update for the second reference, because they refer to the same object.

```js
var objA = { name: 'Bob', age: 25};
var objB = objA;

objB.age = 30;

console.log(objA.age);
```

To get independent object you need to create them. You can use `Object.assign()` function, which will copy any enumerable properties from into the **destination(first parameter)** object and returns it.

You can create with

```
var obj = Object.assign({}, mapObj.fetchTimeObjs[i]);
tmpFetchTimeObjs.push(obj);
```

Comment: ok... so how do I just make a copy of it... so I can change the tmp  and not mess with the original?

Comment: well, godbless testing with an old crappy ipod (Object.assign doesn't seem to work in older versions of safari).  This was the only solution that seems to work for everything: $.extend(true,[],mapObj.fetchTimeObjs)....  found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript

Comment: Yes with jquery

Answer (score 1):

The objects you `push` to the new array, are the same as the original array has, so if you mutate them, that mutation is visible to both arrays. This is what is called doing a *shallow* copy.

You could make a copy at one deeper level, where you would also create new objects and copy the original object's properties (like `start`) into those new objects. This you can easily do with `Object.assign`:

```
    tmpFetchTimeObjs.push(Object.assign({}, mapObj.fetchTimeObjs[i]));
```

If these objects themselves have nested objects, then the problem you had would occur at deeper levels. If this is an issue, then you should look to *deep* clone solutions, like provided in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the `TimeObjs`, since variables only keep the reference to the `TimeObjs`. We don't know the structure of your `TimeObjs`, so if the `TimeObjs` doesn't contain other objects, `Object.assign()` will work, otherwise maybe you need a deep clone method, such as `jQuery.extend()`.

Comment: yup!  $.extend was what worked for me.  array.slice() and array.splice(0) didn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript

Comment: @rikkitikkitumbo Nice, but $.extend will also fail if there are private variables in your objects.

Comment: @rikkitikkitumbo If you have the information or knowledge about how to instantiate the `TimeObjs`, you can write an custom cloner specialized in cloning the `TimeObjs`. In this way, you don't need import `jQuery` anymore.