# What should we do when we need to clone an object deeply

Tags: javascript, json, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, redux

According with what was sayed on another question:

> The spread operator is like Object.assign and does not deeply clone an
>   object. The reason the JSON thing worked is because you created a
>   whole new object which would pass the strict equality check, however
>   all your components would update needlessly because nothing will pass
>   a strict equality check now.
>
> Object.assign({}, ...prevState, ...newState) would create a new
>   top-level object, but it would not create a new object for any objects
>   nested in prevState or newState. However, you would have to carefully
>   update nested objects so as to avoid needless re-renders. This can get
>   tricky for deeply nested objects and arrays.

My question is.... what must we do when we need to return a new version of an object that have properties tha contains arrays? For example:

```
const foo = {
  myArray: [1, 2, 3],
  name: 'Hello world'
};

const clonedObj = { ...foo }
```

This will create a new object with a copy of name and it's content, a copy of myArray key BUT not with a copy of [1, 2, 3].

JSON.parse + JSON.stringify does the trick but don't look like a clean way.

What alternative do I have?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
const clonedObj = Object.assign({}, foo);
```

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Consider reading the question more closely before answering. Not only does it quite clearly discuss the need for a "deep" copy, it specifically calls out `Object.assign` as not working for deep copy (which it doesn't).