# Angular4 copy object without reference?

Tags: angular, object, reference, copy

Inside a component I tried to copy an object from a service that could be modified inside the component, but should stay in the service.

```
private test;

public ngOnInit(): {
  console.log(this.someService.test.someProperty) //'old'
  this.test = this.someService.test;

  //not working as well?!
  //this.test = Object.assign({}, this.someService.test);
  //this.test = Object.create(this.somerService.test);

  this.changeTest();
}

public changeTest(): void {
  this.test.someProperty = 'new';
}
```

after the init both, `this.test.someProperty` as well as `this.someService.test.someProperty` are changed to `new` even though the last should stay `old`?

Why is that happening, and how to only change properties of `this.test`

Comment: how are you getting this object from the service... is it an observable?\

Comment: no its a normal object defined like `public test: any = {...}`

Comment: maybe thats the issue, its passing the reference as well when you are assigning it to your local test. just a guess ...not sure, what you can do to avoid it to create a private subject in your service and expose public observable instead!

Comment: is there no way copying objects without a reference ?!

Comment: I think Object.create(obj) should work.. what about this.test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.someService.test));

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's because Object.assign is a shallow merge, it's only merging the top level, so the top level is referencing the same object in both the service and the component.

I personally use lodash's merge when I need to deep merge objects:

```
this.test = _.merge({}, this.someService.test)
```

Also see: [How to deep merge instead of shallow merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge)

You can also deep clone the object with:

```
this.test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.someService.test));
```

Also see: [How to Deep clone in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)

Comment: wow. thanks. this saves my day! (this.test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.someService.test));
)

Answer (score 17):

Actually Object assign works as in your example. [Created plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/056JeVC3roCAAGxIL0ho?p=preview) to prove it

```
  this.test = Object.assign({}, this.someService.test);
```

Also You can deep clone the object

```
  this.test = structuredClone(this.someService.test);
```

Comment: this is better than json stringify/parse method because it handles date construction

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to add a clone function in the class. It iterates through the object fields and assign the matching values.

```
export class Car {

    constructor(
        public id: number, 
        public name: String) { }

    clone(other : Car) : void {
        let k: keyof Car;
        for (k in other) {
            const v = other[k];
            (this[k] as (typeof v)) = v;
          }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
var car1 = new Car(1, "Amg");
var car2 = new Car(2, "205");
car1.clone(car2);
```

Comment: this is what I was planning to do but what if your object is too complex having a lot of interfaces.