# Clone Object with arrays using spread operator

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

How would one go about cloning an object that has arrays in it with the new spread operator?

Example Object:

```
vehicles: { 
  cars:  [1, 2],
  boats: [3, 4]
}
```

I want a new object with the arrays in it. In that new object I want to be able to change or add to an array without it referencing and effecting vehicles object.

Comment: Can you specify the content of your new object?

Comment: The spread operator makes shallow copies so any deep objects will still be referenced unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Deep clone in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object.assign and the spread operator create shallow clones, only one level deep, beyond that they are referenced. The best way I've found (Thanks [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone)) is to use JSON functions to create a true clone.

```js
let vehicles = { 
  cars:  [1, 2],
  boats: [3, 4],
};

let test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vehicles));

console.log(vehicles, test);

test.cars[0] = 5;
vehicles.cars[0] = 7;

console.log(vehicles, test);
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: What if you have large object? Will it handle in that situation?

Comment: I don't see why not, if you have a large single level object I would recommend using Object.assign, (personal opinion) I think it is better to use the built in language functions when they will do the job. For large multilevel objects this method will work fine.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for objects where deeper properties have arrays. The arrays are always blank

Comment: I just retested this in the console (chrome 67) with a deeply nested array and object and did not have this issue. Could you paste in your example object, and which os and browser you are using? :) Happy to help debug

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)) to deep copy and object is not the best way if you are looking for performance, rather use a deep copy like this:

```js
let x1 = {
  numbers: {
    number: 1
  }
}
let y1 = copy(x1)
x1.numbers.number++
  console.log(x1)
console.log(y1)

function copy(aObject) { // Deep Clone Object from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624648/16642626
  if (!aObject) {
    return aObject;
  }

  let v;
  let bObject = Array.isArray(aObject) ? [] : {};
  for (const k in aObject) {
    v = aObject[k];
    bObject[k] = (typeof v === "object") ? copy(v) : v;
  }

  return bObject;
}
```