# ES6 How to ensure updated clone properties doesn't effect original?

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class

I must be doing something wrong.

1. Instantiate Person class as Bob with name 'Bob'
2. Clone Bob as new var Alice
3. Rename Alice with name 'Alice'
4. Log names of Bob & Alice

I expect Bob's name will remain 'Bob', but it has updated to 'Alice', despite not updating Bob...?

```js
class Person {
  constructor(attr) {
    this.attr = attr;
  }

  talk() {
    console.log('My name is ' + this.attr.name);
  }
}

function clone(obj) {
  return Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)), obj);
}

var Bob = new Person({
  name: 'Bob'
});

var Alice = clone(Bob);
Alice.attr.name = 'Alice';

Alice.talk();
Bob.talk();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you cloning the object?

Comment: You only cloned `Bob`. You did not clone the `attr` object. Store values on the object itself, not in a nested object!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.assign` performs a shallow copy, so `Bob` and `Alice` will have their own copy of the `attr` reference, but they refer to the same nested object. `attr.name` is still a shared string.

You need to perform a deep(er) copy, or else reassign the `attr` property:

```
Alice.attr = { name: 'Alice' };
```

Comment: This insight is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Cloning is ambiguous when it comes to user defined objects, which may have parent-like references, or cyclic references, or functions, and getters which have side-effects, ...etc. See for instance [this answer I gave to a deep clone question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript/40294058#40294058).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for cloning is:

```
var cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectToClone));
```

But there is a catch in this solution, this will fail when your object's attribute value is a function.

```
var a = {name: 'a', exec: function() {return true;}};
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(b); // {name: 'a'}
```

for better insight on cloning, you can refer this article: [deep cloning](https://www.codementor.io/avijitgupta/deep-copying-in-js-7x6q8vh5d)