# Angular 4 instance variable changed with local variable

Tags: angular, instance-variables

When I change the **isPublish** property of localCampaign after copying the campaignData in that, the isPublish property of campaignData also get changed, "can see the comments in code below where this is happening"

```
export class CampaignNotificationDetailPage {
campaignData: any;

   publishCampaign() {
  let localCampaign = this.campaignData;
  localCampaign.isPublish = true;  //this also updates the this.campaignData.isPublish to true?
    }
   }
```

How to block the changes in campaignData and why this is happening?

Comment: make a copy of the this.campaignData and assign to let localCampaign. Here call by reference is happening. By default javascript objects and arrays work as call by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object in javascript are reference type , so you must find a way to apply clone the object , this is one way to solve this :

```
export class CampaignNotificationDetailPage {
 campaignData: any;

    publishCampaign() {
    let localCampaign = object.assign({},this.campaignData);
    localCampaign.isPublish = true; 
    }
   }
```

another way :

```
export class CampaignNotificationDetailPage {
  campaignData: any;

       publishCampaign() {
       let localCampaign  {...this.campaignData}
       localCampaign.isPublish = true; 
        }
       }
```

this answer give a good explanation [How to Deep clone in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `localCampaign` is assigned with `this.campaignData`. Now `this.campaignData` is pointing to on location say reference location

And when you say

```
localCampaign=this.campaignData;
```

You are nothing but pointing `localCampaign` to the reference location of `this.campaignData`

Hence when `this.campaignData` changes, `localCampaign` changed gradually as they are pointing to same reference location. This concept is called `call by reference`.

You can assign a cloned object to localCampaign

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Now you can use above method to clone this.campaignData

```
let localCampaign=clone(this.campaignData);
```

Comment: Looks too many options are there to achieve this, this also works

Answer (score 1):

```
let localCampaign = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.campaignData));
```

This will make a copy.

Comment: This is ok if your object has properts only not function

Comment: @MuhammadAlbarmawi Yeah true. I know that. But did'nt see any function in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It changes the `campaignData` value, even though the `let` is block scoped.

When we do

`let localCampaign = this.campaignData;`

`localCampaign` is pointing to  `this.campaignData`, and when you change values in `localCampaign`, it gets reflected in  `this.campaignData`.

And after the `publishCampaign`'s black (i.e. `{}`), the `localCampaign` will be removed from the memory.