# Copy and update an object with new value and storing to array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to clone and update an object to store in array as new instance. but not works.

any one help me to sort this out?

here is my try:

```
 public getAppPropeties(locales):Observable<any>{

        const msgParms = [];

        locales.forEach((locale, i) => {

            this.messageParam['bd']['locale']=String(locale);

            msgParms[i] = Object.assign({}, this.messageParam);    ;

        });

        console.log( 'msgParms', msgParms ); //getting last value

}
```

Comment: Your english, and therefore your question, is very unclear.

Comment: I am trying to clone and update some value in an existing object, and strong in to array as new objects..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Deep clone in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)

Comment: Use this.messageParam.bd.locale=String(locale)  and msgParam.push(Object.assign({},this.messageParam))

Comment: @Eliseo That does exactly the same thing as the OP's code.

Comment: then, the problem is that this.messageParam.db is null or undefined

Comment: @Eliseo Then it would throw an error. The real problem is that they keep adding the same object to the array.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this:

`msgParms[i] = Object.assign({}, this.messageParam,  {"bd" : { "locale" : locale }} );`

Works fine