# Unable access old value from watch properties in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, axios

For example, I want to access old data from watch properties in Vue.js. This is my example :

```
mounted(){
   axios.get(url).then(({data})=>{
     this.data = data //Initialize data to HTML. For example, username='A'
     Object.assign(this.oldValues, {data : data}) //Copying data to OldValues. Both object it should has same value
   })
},
data(){
  return {
    data : //data from mounted()
    oldValues : //Copied from data
  }
},
watch : {
  data : {
    handler : function(after, before){
       console.log(this.data) // show updated value 
       console.log(this.oldValues) // Expect : show copied value from first mounted()
    }
  }
}
```

When I edited the data using `v-model="data"` it triggers watch property successfully and showing a log like this.

```
<input v-model="data.username"> // 'AAA'
```

Log shown :

```
data.username = 'AAA' //From this.data
data.username = 'AAA' //From this.oldValues. Expect, keep show the first data. It should username = 'A'
```

So, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case should be using `Deep clone` method. There's any 2 way to do this.

#### 1. Lodash or Similiar library

```
this.oldValues = _.cloneDeep({data : data})
```

#### 2. JSON.Parse + JSON.stringify

```
this.oldValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({data : data})
```

Reference

- [How to Deep clone in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)
- https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/971

Answer (score 1):

With `Object.assign(this.oldValues, {data : data})` the `oldValues` is just a reference to the `data`. In this case the `oldValues` will updated when the `data` is changed.

With the following example you will get a real copy from `data`:

```
this.oldValues = Object.assign({}, this.oldValues, {data : data})
```

> In JavaScript objects are a reference type.

Learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_Objects

Comment: Sorry, I was marked done before. But actually, this way still won't work. I got a reference for why this happens and `Object.assign` is still copied as reference.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/971

It works when I'm using lodash `deepClone`. But, I'm still finding another way without lodash. If you had another answer, I'd glad to check it. Thanks