# Does spread operator return new object after operation?

Tags: typescript

As I know spread operator return a new object after operation:

```
let a = {a:1};
let b = {a: 2}
let a = {...a,...b}
```

So, last `a` is not referenced to `a`, it is a new object in memory.

Is it possible to use spread operator without changing initial object, I mean a reference in memory?

Comment: It's impossible - ES2018 guarantees it to always be a new object. PS: it's not operator, it's "spread syntax"

Comment: Is there alternative? Like this: `var obj = Object.assign(updatedObject);`

Comment: alternative to what?

Comment: I don't think there's a better way than `Object.assign(a, b)` to add the properties of `b` to the existing object `a`.

Comment: Alternative to modify current object and extend this by new properties

Comment: If you want to keep the same object - just assign manually to its properties

Comment: You mention wanting a reference, and mention adding properties, but your example is not at all clear, since both `a` and `b` have properties of the same name, and both properties are primitive values, which are not "passed by reference".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's guaranteed by the [12.2.6.7 Runtime Semantics: `Evaluation`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and [12.2.6.8 Runtime Semantics: `PropertyDefinitionEvaluation`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation) that the object returned from an object literal with "spread syntax" is always a new object.

Relevant parts of the spec:

> 1. Let `obj` be `ObjectCreate(%ObjectPrototype%)`.

and

> `PropertyDefinition:...AssignmentExpression`
>   1. Let `exprValue` be the result of evaluating `AssignmentExpression`.
>   2. Let `fromValue` be ? `GetValue(exprValue)`.
>   3. Let `excludedNames` be a new empty List.
>   4. Return `? CopyDataProperties(object, fromValue, excludedNames)`.

There is currently no other way to mutate the object other than just assigning its properties directly.

As [@Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) noted in the comments: the question is tagged as `typescript` while I'm answering about `javascript`. The thing is that TS compiler must retain the native js runtime semantics, so in this very case it's okay to refer to the ES2018 standard.

Comment: Note that the question is tagged `typescript`; the code given may or may not transpile into the spread syntax, depending on the transpilation target.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it must retain the spread syntax semantics though

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's interesting the TS spec does not mention object parameters spread syntax at all.

Comment: If you look at the transpiled code [at this playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20a%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A1%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%202%7D%0D%0Alet%20ab%20%3D%20%7B...a%2C...b%7D) (I changed the second `let a` to `let ab`) you can see they use `Object.assign` :(.

Comment: Your answers is spot on, by the way, just wanted to warn you about TypeScript's... quirks.

Comment: @HereticMonkey oh wow, even with `ES2018` as a target they still emit `Object.assign`, that's awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Spread operator only works on primitive types.

Here an example with primitive datatypes:

```js
let x = {
  number: 1
}
let y = { ...x
}
x.number++
  console.log(x)
console.log(y)
```

Non Primitive:

```js
let x1 = {
  numbers: {
    number: 1
  }
}
let y1 = { ...x1
}
x1.numbers.number++
  console.log(x1)
console.log(y1)
```

As you can see, the 2nd version still uses references, to bypass this use a deep clone function like this:

```js
let x1 = {
  numbers: {
    number: 1
  }
}
let y1 = copy(x1)
x1.numbers.number++
  console.log(x1)
console.log(y1)

function copy(aObject) { // Deep Clone Object from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624648/16642626
  if (!aObject) {
    return aObject;
  }

  let v;
  let bObject = Array.isArray(aObject) ? [] : {};
  for (const k in aObject) {
    v = aObject[k];
    bObject[k] = (typeof v === "object") ? copy(v) : v;
  }

  return bObject;
}
```

So if u truly want to keept the reference, you could nest the a and b in ur example so that the spread operator is not able to see the primitive types on the first layer