# Angular - modify object inside subscribe

Tags: typescript

I have the method getParameters() that returns a setting object, that contains a list of parameters, i implemented code inside subscribe and i added some items in the parameters list, when i display the new object i find that the list has the added items, but the problem is that when i display the returned object i find that it changed too

```
this.settingService.getParameters().subscribe((setting: Setting) => {
    const settingToSave = setting;

    this.parameters.forEach(element => {
       if (settingToSave.parameters.some(parameter => parameter.parameterId === element.parameterId)) {
          settingToSave.parameters = settingToSave.parameters.filter(parameter => parameter.parameterId != element.parameterId);
       }
        settingToSave.parameters.push(element);
     });

    console.log(settingToSave);
    console.log(setting); // same content as the object settingToSave

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many programming languages when you try to copy an **object** variable by doing A = B then you are copying the variable by reference and not by value. So any changes made in A will be applied to B and vice versa. If you want to copy an object variable and make changes to it without affecting its original declaration use this (ES6) :

> let newObj = Object.assign({}, originalObj);

or in your case replace the line:

> const settingToSave = setting;
>   with:
>   let settingToSave = Object.assign({}, setting);

Source used: [MDN Object assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Your explanation is correct, I just want to warn to be careful using `Object.assign` or the spread operator (`const noRealCopy = {...original};`): When you have objects as properties, they continue to be referenced rather than copied. Example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBOBLA5osBDANjAvDA3sABaKYAmA8gEYBWApsFAFwEBExpZACvCAA514UAJ6sW7EuQBqWAK51WAX0UBuGAChQkWKD7DcBAHTGEKNFlUbdwwx3LV6jW5O68BQ-XgDkYOgHcAYRcZTHkvNU1wCBBMOkNMEGQACmtnTgcGKDTyHn5BEVwcPFNUDExsylpMitz3EQBKFSA

Answer (score 1):

By `const settingToSave = setting`, you are creating a reference, not a copy. Hence, when you modify properties of `settingToSave`, you are modifying *the same object* as when modifying `setting` directly.

A simple example that shows the difference between a reference and a copy (in this case, I am creating a copy using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`, which I would not recommend for actual real-life projects):

```js
const original = {"property":"value"};
const reference = original;
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));

reference.property = "new value";

console.log(reference.property === original.property);
console.log(copy.property !== original.property);
```

See [How to Deep clone in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript/) for alternatives.