# Object inheritance / import issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inheritance, import

Im trying to wrap my head round this problem. Not sure its connected to Vue or imports or whatever.

Im importing two different objects (A & B) that import a mutual third object (C).
If I assign object A (that contains object C) to a variable New and add some properties to New, object B (that also contains object C) inherits those changes.

I cant figure out why since I havent changed object C..

Ive tried to make the smallest possible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-txdfb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the codesandbox the object C is referred to as `extra`.

You then have this line:

```js
this.componentConfig.extra.id.push(this.id);
```

The property `this.componentConfig.extra` is referring to the object `extra`. So C has been changed.

While the extra levels of wrapping and importing make it more difficult to see, what you've got is essentially just this:

```js
const c = { name: 'John' }

const a = { c }
const b = { c }

a.c.name = 'Emma'

console.log(b.c.name)
```

In the code above `a.c` and `b.c` are both pointing at the same object. There is no inheriting or copying going on.

Perhaps a diagram will help:

```
a                                       b
{                                       }
  c -------> { name: 'John' } <------- c
}                                       {
```

By way of an analogy, John Smith may be referred to as either John or Mr Smith. These two names refer to the same person. If John loses his hat then so does Mr Smith. You can't make a change to John without also changing Mr Smith because they are one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to either Vue or imports, but to JavaScript, and more broadly, storing variables.  In JavaScript (and other programming languages), variables are often either stored *by value* or *by reference*.

When stored by value, the address points to the actual value in memory, and this is how primitive values (Numbers, Strings, etc) are stored in JavaScript:

```
let x = 5; // Primitive, by value
```

By contrast, objects and arrays are stored by reference.  That means that when you set another variable equal to your object reference, it will point to the reference, not the value itself:

```
let x = {
  name: 'My Object'
}
let y = x;
console.log(x === y) // true
```

The `true` result of the strict equality operator means they are the exact same object, not an original and a clone.  Changing `x` anywhere will also change `y`, since they point to the same object.

Similarly, any code that imports an object will be importing a reference to it, and so will see any changes made to the object from elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are pointed to a reference of an object
You can make a shallow clone of the object and then change it and leave the original object as is

e.g.

```
const newObject = { ...originalObject }
```

Comment: You meant a deep clone?
Since my objects was quite simple the following solution worked:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222333/6839179