# Remove null entries from array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following array of objects below (components) and I want to remove all the null entries. How can I go about doing it? I am trying the following:

```
  static deleteNullComponents(components) {
    return components.filter(function (el) {
      return el['components'] != null;
    });
  }
```

but I get the error: `TypeError: components.filter is not a function`. How can I fix it?

```
[
  {
    "components": [
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "navbar-zJNm0HaP",
        "componentIndex": 1,
        "componentName": "app-builder-navbar",
      },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-MJU8gcYR",
        "componentIndex": 5,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features",
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-2hsUdwaT",
        "componentIndex": 7,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features",
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "footer-dLvoLZ16",
        "componentIndex": 9,
        "componentName": "app-builder-footer",
      },
      null
    ],
    "name": "Home"
  },
  {
    "components": [
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "navbar-UBdYplVp",
        "componentIndex": 1,
        "componentName": "app-builder-navbar",
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-mmEzByeO",
        "componentIndex": 3,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features"
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-GZKgh9lV",
        "componentIndex": 5,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features"
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "footer-IyrNODRQ",
        "componentIndex": 9,
        "componentName": "app-builder-footer",
      },
      null
    ],
    "name": "About"
  }
]
```

Comment: how are you calling `deleteNullComponents`

Comment: `pageComponents = MyService.deleteNullComponents(pageComponents);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`components` are an array property inside an array items in `pageComponents`

So you'll need two loops (forEach/map/filter etc are really just iterating through an array)

So, for each item in the `pageComponents` array, you want to filter values in the `components` property of that item

Also, in the filter function, you don't need to return the original array, since you are not altering the original array, you are altering a nested array within it

```js
class MyService {  
  static deleteNullComponents(components) {
    components.forEach(obj =>
      obj.components = obj.components.filter(item => item !== null)
    )
  }
}

let pageComponents = [
  {
    "components": [
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "navbar-zJNm0HaP",
        "componentIndex": 1,
        "componentName": "app-builder-navbar",
      },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-MJU8gcYR",
        "componentIndex": 5,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features",
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-2hsUdwaT",
        "componentIndex": 7,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features",
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "footer-dLvoLZ16",
        "componentIndex": 9,
        "componentName": "app-builder-footer",
      },
      null
    ],
    "name": "Home"
  },
  {
    "components": [
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "navbar-UBdYplVp",
        "componentIndex": 1,
        "componentName": "app-builder-navbar",
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-mmEzByeO",
        "componentIndex": 3,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features"
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-GZKgh9lV",
        "componentIndex": 5,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features"
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "footer-IyrNODRQ",
        "componentIndex": 9,
        "componentName": "app-builder-footer",
      },
      null
    ],
    "name": "About"
  }
]

MyService.deleteNullComponents(pageComponents)
console.log(pageComponents)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are running filter on the wrong object, try the following:

**NOTE**: This will also modify the original components array that is passed into the `deleteNullComponents`, so it is unnecessary to re-assign components after the method call. If you don't want this behavior, take a look at the following thread:

[How to deep clone an object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript)

```js
class MyService {  
  static deleteNullComponents(components) {
    return components.map(obj =>
      obj["components"].filter(item => item !== null)
    )
  }
}

let pageComponents = [
  {
    "components": [
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "navbar-zJNm0HaP",
        "componentIndex": 1,
        "componentName": "app-builder-navbar",
      },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-MJU8gcYR",
        "componentIndex": 5,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features",
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-2hsUdwaT",
        "componentIndex": 7,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features",
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "footer-dLvoLZ16",
        "componentIndex": 9,
        "componentName": "app-builder-footer",
      },
      null
    ],
    "name": "Home"
  },
  {
    "components": [
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "navbar-UBdYplVp",
        "componentIndex": 1,
        "componentName": "app-builder-navbar",
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-mmEzByeO",
        "componentIndex": 3,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features"
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "features-GZKgh9lV",
        "componentIndex": 5,
        "componentName": "app-builder-features"
      },
      null,
      {
        "componentId": "footer-IyrNODRQ",
        "componentIndex": 9,
        "componentName": "app-builder-footer",
      },
      null
    ],
    "name": "About"
  }
]

// no need to re-assign here, the original object is modified
pageComponents = MyService.deleteNullComponents(pageComponents)
console.log(pageComponents)
```

Comment: this changes the structure of `pageComponents` - is that what the OP wanted?

Comment: Right I was going to mention that, he does re-assign afterwards as per his comment, so I assume the answer is yes.

Comment: He assigns because he doesn't know what he's doing

Answer (score 1):

You're only stepping one layer into that object.  Assuming that you don't care about the name property you need something like:

```
// take the array of objects and iterate over them
firstLevelArray.map((secondLevelArray) => {
  // grab each components array in the array of objects, and filter it for null
  return secondLevelArray['components'].filter((possibleComponent) => {
    return possibleComponent != null;
  })
});
```

However you probably want to keep the name, and in any case this is a pretty rigid way to do things as you're assuming your current data structure.  Here's a quick and dirty recursive method, which should handle an arbitrary number of nestings... however recursion isn't fully properly implemented in javascript.  You SHOULD be using a library like underscore for deep comparison.  I wrote this up for fun and to be illustrative, as reading library code can be somewhat difficult if you're new to javascript (and even then for my little brain).

Though it's likely already clear, what we're doing here is stepping into each item in your json, checking if it's null, if not then if it's an array or an object: visit each item of that, and so on.

```
let deepRemoveNull = function(x) { 
    if (x === null) {
        return;
    } 
    if (Array.isArray(x)) {
        let arr = [];
        for (const i of x) {
            if (x !== null) {
                let result = deepRemoveNull(i);
                // get rid of undefined
                if (result) {
                    arr.push(result);
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    } else if (typeof x === 'object') {
        let obj = {};
        for (const key in x) {
            if (x[key] !== null) {
                let result = deepRemoveNull(x[key]);
                // get rid of undefined
                if (result) {
                    obj[key] = result;
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
    return x;
}
```

If you pass in your object to the function above it should work for you.  DO NOT USE THE ABOVE IN PRODUCTION CODE

Answer (score -2):

You could use a one-liner :

```
components = components.filter(function(el) { return el !== null });
```

Comment: This will cause SyntaxError

Comment: `delete el` - no that won't do anything, ever, at all ... and `components` in that case will be an array of `undefined` since you are (mis)using `.map`