# Object array returns undefined after filter is run on it

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array with the following structure

```
let pageComponents = { pages: [ { "components": [ ... ] }, { "components": [ ... ] } ] };
```

See [Remove null entries from array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60516345/436493) for the contents of `components`.

I've tried to run the following *filter* method on it, but the object array returns null afterwards. Any idea on how I can fix it?

```
  static deleteEmptyComponentsOnMultiplePages(components) {
    return components['pages'].forEach(obj => {
        obj['components'].filter(item => item !== null);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't return anything it just loops. Here you need to use `map()`.

You also need to use `return` inside the callback of `map()` otherwise you will get an array of `undefined`

```
static deleteEmptyComponentsOnMultiplePages(components) {
    return components['pages'].map(obj => {
        return obj['components'].filter(item => item !== null);
    });
}
```

You can exclude `{}` of `map()` and return implicitly

```
static deleteEmptyComponentsOnMultiplePages(components) {
    return components['pages'].map(obj => obj['components'].filter(item => item !== null));
}
```

You can use destructuring for more cleaner code

```
static deleteEmptyComponentsOnMultiplePages({pages}) {
    return pages.map(({components}) => components.filter(item => item !== null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ForEach` is iterator only and its return type is void. you need to use other iterator methods like `map`

```js
let pageComponents = {
  pages: [
  {
    "components": [1, 2, 4, null]
  }, 
  {
    "components": ['a', 'b', null, 'd']
  }
  ]
};

function deleteEmptyComponentsOnMultiplePages(components) {
    return components.map(obj => {
        return obj.components.filter(item => item !== null);
    });
}

console.log(deleteEmptyComponentsOnMultiplePages(pageComponents.pages))
```