# Javascript deep copy using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Is the below method a foolproof way of deep copying an object in Javascript i.e. even for very deeply nested objects/arrays ?

```
let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: No. It doesn't work for circular objects and everything that contains non-plain objects or arrays. And it might not work for really large objects.

Comment: But there is a solution how do it if circular exist. The question is understated in the status it makes no sense to answer

Answer (score 2):

As metioned in other answer JSON methods to deep copy is unreliable with non primitive data types. In modern JS we can find new method called **structuredClone()** for deep copy.

```
var obj = {name: {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}, age: 25 };
```

So to create copy of **obj** into **obj1**, We can do something like

```
var obj1 = structuredClone(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, this is a simple but unreliable deep copy that works for simple JavaScript objects. But it would likely fail for some non-primitive data types' properties.

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add(1);
set.add(2);

const map = new Map();
map.set('Jessie', {phone: "213-555-1234", address: "123 N 1st Ave"})

const obj = {
  foo: () => 'bar',
  date: new Date(),
  undefined,
  set,
  map,
}

console.log(obj);

let unreliableNewObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(unreliableNewObj); // some properties are lost, some properties are changed like set and map, can compare the result

// ES6 shallow copy that may help
let reliableNewObj = {
 ...obj,
}
console.log(reliableNewObj);

// 'real' deep copy from library
// https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep
let deepObj = _.cloneDeep(obj); // if _ is imported
console.log(deepObj)
```

For a reliable deep copy, alternatives are:

- libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep)
- implement by ourselves, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript), maybe quite complicated though.