# How to deep clone object with functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I need to "load" content from my `const` objects, but the problem is that when I use `content = levels[level]`, and then modify `content`, `levels[level]` is modified too, so if I load it again, nothing happens, because content is same as it. I search for a bit, and found a few ways:

1. `structuredClone()` - Error: Function object could not be cloned.
2. `{...levels[leve]}` - Doesn't not deep copy
3. `Object.assign({},levels[level])` - Doesn't not deep copy
4. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(levels[campaing][id]))` Doesn't copy functions
5. [How to Deep clone in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript) - does not copy functions

Looks like my problem is that my levels[level] is object with object, which are with arrays, and these arrays contain objects made from classes, and these objects may have anything (int, bool, string, function, object, array).
I don't need to copy `prototype`, but I need to use it (referencing it is fine).
How could I write correct function to copy objects?

Comment: No, I typed in in №5, it doesn't copy functions. (Or, at least prototypes.. let me check)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice it was exactly the same question I suggested in comment. When I read it, it was expected to clone the object entirely, functions included. To be sure I did a test right now that correctly clones also the functions. Anyway in all fairness, are you sure that's the better strategy to solve your problem?

Comment: I just checked too, yes it clones functions, but i also need to keep `prototype`.
What do you mean "are you sure that's the better strategy to solve your problem?"?

Comment: of course if you have multiple variables holding the reference to the same object, it will affect the same object when doing changes. I asked if you are sure just to make sure before taking that path... but yet if you really need the exact original copy of it because you are going to change it, I guess there's no other way

Comment: No?
Right now i need to understand how do i copy `prototype`, because when i tried `if(item.prototype) { result.prototype = item.prototype }` right before `return result;` in function from annwer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript , it didn't work. I added `console.log()`, and looks like it doesn't enter `if`.

Comment: try doing `Object.setPrototypeOf(clone, Object.getPrototypeOf(original));` ... anyway I must say there are probably some few missing feature in that clone function not dealing with every single possible option but yet good enough for most cases

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! Have a cool day!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of your code?

Comment: jabaa, i already got answer by Diego D (`Object.setPrototypeOf(clone, Object.getPrototypeOf(original));`), which works! Thanks for help, but question is closed (i can't close it without moderators help i think).

Comment: One could easily implement functionality that deeply copies data structures and functions/methods by creating a copy of each occurring function through `bind`ing  the currently processed object's reference to the former. Though this approach works for function statements and function expression it fails for any arrow function. First, there is a reason why modeling approaches separate pure data from method implementations, and second, this most probably also applies to `structuredClone` which even does raise exceptions when encountering functions. Thus the question is...Why does the OP want it?

Answer (score -2):

You could do it with a recursive function like this:

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
    // null, 0, false
    if (!obj) {
        return obj;
    }

    // Array
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.map(val => cloneObject(val));
    }

    // Object
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        const result = {};
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            result[key] = cloneObject(obj[key]);
        });
        return result;
    }

    // Anything else
    return obj;
}
```

But if you have class instances, you will lose the class.

Comment: Hi, i already got answer in comments (see comments to question), maybe someone will answer it, but anyway problem is solved. Thanks for help anyway :3

Comment: @Barnak This *does not clone functions*, which is what the question is about.