# How can I avoid mutating the original nested objects passed to Nuxt 3 component prop object?

Tags: javascript, object, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm passing a data object from component to component through props in Nuxt 3:

##### Parent component

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Tests :objParent="objParent" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const objParent = {title: {en:"title en", fr:"title fr"}}
</script>
```

##### Child component

```
<template>
  <div >
    <h1>objParent : {{ props.objParent.title.en }}</h1>

    <v-text-field label="label" v-model="objChild.title.en" />

    <h1>objChild : {{ objChild.title.en }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps(["objParent"]);
const objChild = ref({...props.objParent});
</script>
```

The problem is, if I mutate the nested objects from `objChild`, they will still be mutated in the original nested objects from the parent component.

I don't have the same problem passing an object without nested objects - e.g.:

```js
// title can be mutated without mutating the original object
const objParent = {title: "title en"}
```

I did some research and I found this solution:

```
const objChild = ref(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.objParent)));
```

Is it a valid solution?

Comment: Spread operator makes a shallow copy, not a deep one. Plenty of solutions for that, structuredClone() should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the comment by Emil, since your new object is created using the props from the original object directly (via [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator), every nested object will keep pointing to the ones nested in the original parent object.

This happens because in JavaScript objects differ from [primitive values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#primitive_values) as they are a [reference type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects#comparing_objects). When you assign an object to a variable, you assign a **reference** to the object - meaning if you keep assigning the same object in other places, it will *still be pointing to the original object*, and the same goes for all of its nested objects.

So:

```js
const x = { hello: 'world' };

const y = { x };

const z = { y };

z.y.x.hello = 'kitty';

// {hello: 'kitty'}
console.log(x);
```

As you pointed out yourself, one easy technique to produce [deep copies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy) in JavaScript would be serializing/deserializing it to and from a JSON string:

```js
const x = { hello: 'world' };

const y = { x };

const z = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ y }));

z.y.x.hello = 'kitty';

// {hello: 'world'}
console.log(x);

// {y: {x: {hello: 'kitty'}}}
console.log(z);
```

To answer your question - yes, it *is* a valid, working and widely used means of creating deep clones. Mind you, however, that **not everything can be serialized to JSON**, including Symbol-keyed properties, `BigInt` values and circular references. See caveats [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description).

If the data you expect to receive already comes from a REST API, it will most likely not contain any unserializable data.

You can find other alternatives (and their caveats) in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript).