# Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?

Tags: javascript

I've written the following JavaScript:

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var copyOfMyArray = myArray;
copyOfMyArray.splice(0, 1);
alert(myArray); // alerts ['b','c']
alert(copyOfMyArray); // alerts ['b','c']

var myNumber = 5;
var copyOfMyNumber = myNumber;
copyOfMyNumber = copyOfMyNumber - 1;
alert(myNumber); // alerts 5
alert(copyOfMyNumber); // alerts 4
```

This code declares a variable `myArray` and sets it to an array value.  It then declares a second variable `copyOfMyArray` and sets it to `myArray`.
It performs an operation on `copyOfMyArray` and then alerts both `myArray` and `copyOfMyArray`.  Somehow, when I perform an operation on `copyOfMyArray`, it appears that the same operation is performed on `myArray`.

The code then does the same thing with a number value:  It declares a variable `myNumber` and sets it to a number value.  It then declares a second variable `copyOfMyNumber` and sets it to `myNumber`.  It performs an operation on `copyOfMyNumber` and then alerts both `myNumber` and `copyOfMyNumber`.  Here, I get the expected behavior: different values for `myNumber` and `copyOfMyNumber`.

What is the difference between an array and a number in JavaScript that it seems changing an array changes the value of a copy of the array, where as changing a number does not change the value of a copy of the number?

I'm guessing that for some reason, the array is referred to by reference and the number by value, but why?  How can I know what behavior to expect with other objects?

Comment: Related: [How do you clone an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597588)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

An array in JavaScript is also an *object* and variables only hold a *reference* to an object, not the object itself. Thus both variables have a reference to *the same* object.

Your comparison with the number example is not correct btw. You assign a new value to `copyOfMyNumber`. If you assign a new value to `copyOfMyArray` it will not change `myArray` either.

You can create a copy of an array using [`slice` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var copyOfMyArray = myArray.slice(0);
```

But note that this only returns a *shallow* copy, i.e. objects inside the array will not be cloned.

Comment: +1 - just out of curiosity, is there any drawback by assigning `myArray.slice(0);` directly in that context ?

Comment: @Rice: No, I just edit to clarify. If you want a deep copy, you have to write something on your own. But I'm sure you will find a script that does this.

Comment: @FelixKling: I don't have an example. I was just asking because you applied the prototype method first.

Comment: @jAndy: Ah so you referred to that... I was just a bit confused and I just the other way more often recently ;)

Answer (score 28):

Well, the only possible answer — and the correct one — is that you're *not actually copying the array.* When you write

```
var copyOfArray = array;
```

you're assigning a *reference* to the same array into another variable. They're both pointing at the same object, in other words.

Comment: I'd say it you're not assigning exactly reference pointer, you're assigning like a copy of reference. Since if you pass obj to function and try to replace it with another new object inside the function, you won't change the original object.

Comment: @kashesandr yes, "assigning a reference" means "assigning a *copy* of a reference", that's true. However two equal references are always equal, just as two instances of the number `5` are always equal.

Answer (score 21):

So everyone here has done a great job of explaining **why** this is happening - I just wanted to drop a line and let you know ***how*** I was able to fix this - pretty easily:

```
thingArray = ['first_thing', 'second_thing', 'third_thing']
function removeFirstThingAndPreserveArray(){
  var copyOfThingArray = [...thingArray]
  copyOfThingArray.shift();
  return copyOfThingArray;
}
```

This is using the ... spread syntax.

[Spread Syntax Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

EDIT: As to the *why* of this, and to answer your question:

> What is the difference between an array and a number in JavaScript that it seems changing an array changes the value of a copy of the array, where as changing a number does not change the value of a copy of the number?

The answer is that in JavaScript, arrays and objects are *mutable*, while strings and numbers and other primitives are *immutable*. When we do an assignment like:

> `var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
>   var copyOfMyArray = myArray;`

copyOfMyArray is really just a reference to myArray, not an actual copy.

I would recommend this article, [What are immutable and mutable data structures?](https://benmccormick.org/2016/06/04/what-are-mutable-and-immutable-data-structures-2/), to dig deeper into the subject.

[MDN Glossary: Mutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Cloning objects -

A `loop / array.push` produces a similar result to `array.slice(0)` or `array.clone()`. Values are all passed by reference, but since most primitive data types are *immutable*, subsequent operations produce the desired result - a 'clone'. This is not true of objects and arrays, of course, which allow for modification of the original reference (they are mutable types).

Take the following example:

```
const originalArray = [1, 'a', false, {foor: 'bar'}]
const newArray = [];

originalArray.forEach((v, i) => {
    newArray.push(originalArray[i]);
});

newArray[0] = newArray[0] + 1;
newArray[1] = 'b';
newArray[2] = true;
newArray[3] = Object.assign(newArray[3], {bar: 'foo'});
```

The operations run on the newArray indices all produce the desired result, except the final (object), which, because it is copied by reference, will mutate the originalArray[3] as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/7ajz2m6w/

Note that `array.slice(0)` `and array.clone()` suffers from this same limitation.

One way to solve this is by effectively cloning the object during the push sequence:

```
originalArray.forEach((v, i) => {
    const val = (typeof v === 'object') ? Object.assign({}, v) : v;
    newArray.push(val);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e5hmnjp0/

cheers

Answer (score 5):

The issue with shallow copy is that all the objects aren't cloned, instead it get reference.So array.slice(0) will work fine only with literal array, but it will not do shallow copy with object array. In that case one way is..

```
var firstArray = [{name: 'foo', id: 121}, {name: 'zoo', id: 321}];
var clonedArray = firstArray.map((_arrayElement) => Object.assign({}, _arrayElement));  
console.log(clonedArray);
// [{name: 'foo', id: 121}, {name: 'zoo', id: 321}]  // shallow copy
```

Answer (score 4):

In JS, operator "=" copy the pointer to the memory area of the array.
If you want to copy an array into another you have to use the Clone function.

For integers is different because they are a primitive type.

S.

Answer (score 2):

Create a filter of the original array in the arrayCopy. So that changes to the new array won't affect original array.

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var arrayCopy = myArray.filter(function(f){return f;})
arrayCopy.splice(0, 1);
alert(myArray); // alerts ['a','b','c']
alert(arrayCopy); // alerts ['b','c']
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is copied by reference except primitive data types (strings and numbers IIRC).

Comment: That isn't true.  All assignments assign references.  Strings and numbers are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any copies.
You have multiple variables holding the same array.

Similarly, you have multiple variables holding the same number.

When you write `copyOfMyNumber = ...`, you're putting a new number into the variable.
That's like writing `copyOfMyArray = ...`.

When you write `copyOfMyArray.splice`, you're *modifying the original array*.
That isn't possible with numbers because numbers are immutable and cannot be modified,

Answer (score 0):

You can add some error handling depending on your cases and use something similar to the following function to solve the issue. Please comment for any bugs / issues / efficiency ideas.

```
function CopyAnArray (ari1) {
   var mxx4 = [];
   for (var i=0;i<ari1.length;i++) {
      var nads2 = [];
      for (var j=0;j<ari1[0].length;j++) {
         nads2.push(ari1[i][j]);
      }
      mxx4.push(nads2);
   }
   return mxx4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array, or an object in javascript always holds the same reference unless you clone or copy. Here is an exmaple:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Bqvsiddke27w9nLwYhcl?p=preview

```
// for showing that objects in javascript shares the same reference

var obj = {
  "name": "a"
}

var arr = [];

//we push the same object
arr.push(obj);
arr.push(obj);

//if we change the value for one object
arr[0].name = "b";

//the other object also changes
alert(arr[1].name);
```

For object clone, we can use .clone() in jquery and angular.copy(), these functions will create new object with other reference. If you know more functions to do that, please tell me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Arrays with objects you can change the use JSON.parse and JSON.strinigfy to change the type of the array to an object refrence to a string and then back to a array without having to worry about the original array

```js
var array = [{name:'John', age:34, logs:'[]'}, {name:'David', age:43, logs:'[3]'}];
  var array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)); // turn object to function output
  array2[0].age++;
  alert(JSON.stringify(array));
  alert(JSON.stringify(array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because** the way javaScript copies variables differ by data types:

- *primitive* are copied by **value**.
- *non primitive* are copied by **reference**.

JavaScript variables can hold either one of two value types (*primitive values* or *reference values*):
*Primitive values* are 6 data types: [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean), [`Null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/null), [`Undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol).
*Reference values* store the *non-primitive* data types like [`Arrays`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [`Objects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

When we copy a *primitive value* holding variable to a new variable, it is *copied by value*, that is the new variable holds the copy of the old variable.

```
const a = 2;
const b = a; //copied by value
b++;
a; // 2
b; // 3
```

**However**, Whenver we copy *a non-primitive reference* variable to a new variable, it is *copied by reference*, meaning that the new variable isn't a copy of the old variable, instead, it is another reference or name to the value inside. So, if we modify the old variable in the latter case, the new variable will also have its value updated and vice versa.

```
const c = [1,2,3];
const d = c; //copied by reference
d.push( 4 );
c; // [1,2,3,4]
d; // [1,2,3,4]
```