# Why splice() method changes the value of other array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have an array say

```
var list = ["first", "second"];
```

now I assign list to some other variable say

```
var temp = list;
```

Now when I use splice on **list** like

```
list.splice(0,1);
```

Now when I check the value of list it shows

```
list = ["second"]
```

Also when I check the value of temp then it says

```
temp = ["second"]
```

I want to know why is that so? Why the value of **temp** is changed?

Comment: Because `temp` is only a **pointer** to the actual array, it's not being copied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you do an assignment like `var temp = list` you're creating a reference `temp` to `list`. So since [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) changes `list` array in-place, you're also changing `temp`

Use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead which returns a copy of the array, like so

```
var temp = list.slice();
```

Comment: So how do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake in JS

This is a pointer, not a clone of the object:

```
var temp = list;
```

If you want to actually copy the object, there are a few ways.  The simplest is just to concat it with itself:

```
var temp = list.concat([]);
// or
var temp = list.slice();
```

Note that this is somewhat dangerous, it only gets the base values out of the array.  There are more advanced methods for cloning objects and creating 'perfect' array clones.

Answer (score 1):

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

should do the trick:

`var temp = list.slice(0);`

About object cloning, look here [How do you clone an Array of Objects in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prototype method to add this functionality.

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
  var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
  for (i in this) {
    if (i == 'clone') continue;
    if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
      newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
    } else newObj[i] = this[i]
  } return newObj;
};
```

Which then allows you to do this:

```
var a = [1,2,3];

var b = a.clone();

a[1] = 5;

console.log(a); //1,5,3
console.log(b); //1,2,3
```

Disclaimer: shamelessly borrowed from here (the whole article is worth a read): http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165