# Google Apps Script prototypes and inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, google-apps-script, prototype

I'm trying to understand how to use javascript prototypes and inheritance in Google Apps Script but apparently I'm still missing something.

Here is the structure I'm working on.

```
   function Father (  ) {
      this.init.apply ( this, arguments );
    }
    Father.prototype ={
      init: function  (  ) {
        var optns = arguments[0] || {};
        this.job = optns.job || "unemployed";
        this.cars = optns.cars || [];
      }
    }

    function Son (  ) {
      this.init.apply ( this, arguments );
    }
    Son.prototype = {
      init : function  (  ) {
        Father.prototype.init.apply (this, arguments);
        var optns = arguments[0] || {};
        this.computers = optns.tablets || [];
      }
    }
```

Son differs from Father just for the property to own computers.

```
function life() {
 var Tom = new Father({job:'carpenter', cars: ['fiat']});
 var Jim = new Son(Tom);
 Jim.computers.push('iMac');
 Jim.job = 'trader';
 Jim.cars.push('bmw');
 return
 }
```

Here I want the Son instance **Jim** to start with the same values as **Tom** (being a carpenter and owning a fiat) but then, as life goes on, I'm expecting **Jim**'s values to change *independently* from **Tom**. 
In fact, I can add a computer and change job to **Jim** without affecting **Tom** but when I add a car to Jim, 'bmw' is also added to Tom's cars. Why???

Note: the code works fine if I replace this line

```
var Jim = new Son(Tom);
```

with

```
var Jim = new Son({job:'carpenter', cars: ['fiat']})
```

but I don't get why.

Comment: I digged down the problem, the answer is here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array)