# javascript array object assigned to normal

Tags: javascript

I tried the following code

```
var foo = [1,2];
var bar = foo;
bar[0] = 9;
console.log(foo[0],bar[0]);    //the result is 9,9
```

How foo[0] can be 9?Please let me know this am stucked.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you expect it to be?

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are sharing the array.

Comment: I expect foo[0] be 1 as we did not assign any value to foo[0]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript, array are pass by reference. That means `bar` is a pointer to the same object that `foo` point to.

You need to add `clone` method when you want to assign the variable by passing its value like following code

```
var foo = [1,2];
var bar = foo.clone();
bar[0] = 9;
console.log(foo[0],bar[0]);    //the result is 1,9
```

Answer (score 1):

1. makes `foo` an array.
2. makes `bar` an reference to `foo`
3. changing `bar` will really change `foo`

Now `foo` IS `bar` ... and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Arrays, objects and functions are references in javascript while numbers and strings are values. Therefore when you do:

```
var foo = [];
var bar = foo;
```

The variable `bar` now points to `foo` and both `foo` and `bar` refer to the same array.

If you want to copy an array, use `Array.prototype.slice()`:

```
var bar = foo.slice();
```

Technically, the `.slice()` method is meant to be used to return a subarray of an array but if called without any arguments it returns the whole array. The important thing to realize is that `.slice()` returns a new array, not the original array. Which is why we use it to do a shallow copy of an array.

For objects you can use the `Objcet.create()` function:

```
var foo = {};
var bar = Object.create(foo);
```

---

### Additional notes:

It should be noted that both `.slice()` and `Object.create()` creates shallow copies of the original. That is, if the array or object contains other arrays or objects then the contents are still references:

```
var foo = [[1,2],3];
var bar = foo.slice();

bar[1] = 100;
console.log(bar[1]); // 100
console.log(foo[1]); // 3

bar[0][0] = 200;
console.log(bar[0][0]); // 200
console.log(foo[0][0]); // also 200
```

If you want to do a deep copy you need to write a recursive function to build another array/object based on the original. Or if you don't mind a bit of temporarily wasted RAM you can convert them to JSON and back again:

```
var bar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo));
```

Or use a library that provides a deep-copy function like jQuery.