# Updating object copy updates original

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an issue related to objects in javascript. I actually need to put the value of my original variable value in a temporary variable that I can refer later the perform a business logic.

The issue is that whenever I modify the original variable value the temporary gets updated too

**Putting the value in the temporary variable**

Here this.startingTime = 10:00

and this.endingTime = 12:00

```
this.startingTime = new Date(this.selectedAvailability.scheduleDate + ' ' + this.selectedAvailability.startTime);
this.endingTime = new Date(this.selectedAvailability.scheduleDate + ' ' + this.selectedAvailability.endTime);

this.tempStartTime = this.startingTime;
this.tempEndingTime = this.endingTime;
```

**Updating as follow update the original and the temp**

this.endingTime = 11:30

this.tempEndingTime = 11:30 (The temp variable gets updated also, but here what I want is the temp to stay 12:00)

```
this.endingTime.setMinutes(this.endingTime.getMinutes() - 30);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy a variable's value into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829099/copy-a-variables-value-into-another)

Comment: The line `this.tempStartTime = this.startingTime;` doesn't create a copy of the date object, it just makes both `this.tempStartTime` and `this.startingTime` both refer to the same date object. Details in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817770/why-is-a-copy-of-my-variable-being-changed-unexpectedly)'s answers. If you want to copy a date, the best way is `= new Date(+original)` (in particular, **don't** just do `= new Date(original)`, it's not reliable cross-browser).

Answer (score 0):

By doing this, you are giving the reference of your first variable to your temporary one, that's why they are updated together.

To prevent it, you should use something like `object.assign` or `cloneDeep` (this one is from `lodash`) to create a new reference.

Answer (score -1):

this.tempStartTime = angular.copy(this.startingTime);

this.tempEndingTime =  angular.copy(this.endingTime);

Try with this one