# typescript adding object to an array using push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

my data element contains:

```
{"records":[{"id":2463534,"token":"135","name":"MNC Rental","number":"0"},{"id":2463535,"token":"132","name":"ZNC Rental","number":"0"}]}
```

This is my code:

```
          var editableArray = [];
          var object = { i: 0, id: 0, number: "" };
          for(let i = 0 ; i < data.records.length ; i++) {
            object.i = i;
            object.id = data.records[i].id;
            object.number = data.records[i].number;
            console.log("object: " + JSON.stringify(object));
            editableArray.push(JSON.stringify(object));
          }
          console.log("array: " + JSON.stringify(editableArray));
```

Output:

```
object: {"i":0,"id":2463534,"number":"0"}
object: {"i":1,"id":2463535,"number":"0"}
array: ["{\"i\":0,\"id\":2463534,\"number\":\"0\"}","{\"i\":1,\"id\":2463535,\"number\":\"0\"}"]
```

So in the array there are a lot of backslashes and I dont know why. Anyone have an idea to avoid these backslashes?

If I remove the JSON.stringify in the push command, then it adds only the last object 2 times, this is the result:

```
array: [{"i":1,"id":2463535,"number":"0"},{"i":1,"id":2463535,"number":"0"}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a copy of my variable being changed unexpectedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817770/why-is-a-copy-of-my-variable-being-changed-unexpectedly)

Comment: Answer by JensV is the correct one, but if you're interested in something less verbose you can just use a one-liner that does the exact same thing: `const editableArray = data.records.map((record, index) => ({i: index, id: record.id, number: record.number}));`

Answer (score 4):

You're always pushing the same object into the array and then modifying it. You need to create a new object every time:

```
for(let i = 0 ; i < data.records.length ; i++) {
    // moved inside to create a new object instead of modifying the existing one
    var object = { i: 0, id: 0, number: "" };
    object.i = i;
    object.id = data.records[i].id;
    object.number = data.records[i].number;
    console.log("object: " + JSON.stringify(object));
    editableArray.push(object);
}
console.log("array:", editableArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jensv answer is totally correct, just want to add my solution.

It basically does the same things, it's just a little less verbose.

```js
const data = {"records":[{"id":2463534,"token":"135","name":"MNC Rental","number":"0"},{"id":2463535,"token":"132","name":"ZNC Rental","number":"0"}]}

const editableArray = data.records.map(({ id, number }, i) => ({ i, id, number: String(number) }));

console.log("array: " + JSON.stringify(editableArray));
```