# Javascript array strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, arrays

By js convention and as far as I know

> - Primitive datatypes are worked under pass by value and
> - complex datatypes are worked under pass by reference

If it so

```
var ary = [1,2,3];
var dupAry = ary;
//Now I am going to rewrite the ary variable as follows
ary = [3,4,5];
```

Now I log the values of ary and dupAry it logs different values. By its standard both array should return the vaues.

> 1. so why it return different array values?

Another scenario

```
    var ary = [1,2,3];
    var dupAry = ary;
    //No I gonna apply splice method to the ary.
    ary.splice(0,1);
```

Now both array return same values and it works fine with its standard.

> 2. Finally why its doesn't applied with first scenario?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array

Comment: When you make `ary = [3,4,5];`you assign a new array to ary and break the referral between `ary` and `dupAry`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> var dupAry = ary;
> ```

This assigns a reference to the array that `ary` points to to `dupAry`. Both `ary` and `dupAry` now hold a reference which points to the same array object. If you now assign something else to `ary`, then `dupAry` will continue to hold a reference which points to the array object, and `ary` will now hold some other value.

By assigning something to a variable, you're not modifying the object that variable already holds; you're modifying the object reference that variable holds.

> ```
> ary.splice(0,1)
> ```

This modifies the actual object that both variables points to, so both see the change.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
ary = [3,4,5];
```

... you aren't altering an array: you are destroying the previous reference and creating a brand new variable* with a brand new array. See the difference with:

```
ary.push(99);
```

(*) Well, not really a new variable, of course—I didn't know how to word it.