# Variable changes by itself

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a small problem trying to code a snake game in js.

I have this function:

```
function move() {

    var aux = [];
    aux = snake.position[snake.position.length - 1];
    console.log(aux);

    if (snake.direction == 'r') {
        snake.position[snake.position.length - 1][1] += 1;
    };

    console.log(aux);
    //updateSnake();
    snake.position[snake.position.length - 2] = aux;
    updatePosition(snake.position);
};
```

The problem is that aux is changing itself without me doing anything to it, as you can see. The value from the first console.log is different from the second one! It's not like I'm changing its prototype.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Isn't aux just snake.position[someindex] that you do change?

Comment: Well, yeah! But the thing is. The first time I log that aux, it prints me [10,12] - The value of snake.position[2]. After that if, the value of aux changes to [10,13]. But I don't change that aux anywhere. Only the snake.position[2] changes.Aux shouldn't

Comment: Please, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `aux` is just a reference to `snake.position[snake.position.length - 1]`, not a copy of the array: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6612385

Comment: `aux = snake.position[snake.position.length - 1]` doesn't create a new array, it's just create a reference to the `snake.position[snake.position.length - 1]` array.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! That helped a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (snake.direction == 'r') {
    snake.position[snake.position.length - 1][1] += 1;
}
```

The above line is what changes the array `aux`. The first `console.log()` returns `[10,12]` as stated in the above comments. After that, the if statement is incrementing `snake.position[snake.position.length - 1][1]`, which is the value of the variable. When calling `console.log()` for the second time, the variable aux is evaluated as `[10,12+1]`, equivalent to `[10,13]`, which is the expected result.