# What is the right way to create and access multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Simple issue I am facing.**

```
  arr = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]];
  x = arr[0];
  x[0] = 2; //x returns [2,2,3]
```

At the same time arr is also updated to [[2,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
How can I prevent this.I don't want arr to change and why does this happen?

Comment: If you dont want `arr` value to change than why are you assigning value `x[0]=2` since `x=arr[0]` is not copying but creating array by reference??

Comment: Use `x = arr[0].slice()`. You’re mutating the array by reference, because you don’t create a copy by assigning the array to a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**The = operator does not make a copy of the data.**

**The = operator creates a new reference to the same data.**

An easy fix would be to do the following when assigning the value of `x`:

`x = arr[0].slice();`