# Insert a new object in Array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have an Array List.

```
dataList = []
```

I want to insert object in array, So I tried this,

```
dataList.concat([{"name":"BOB", "value":"1"}])
// [{"name":"BOB", "value":"1"}]
```

but when I insert 2nd object in the same array.

```
dataList.concat([{"name":"Joe", "value":"2"}])
// [{"name":"Joe", "value":"2"},{"name":"Joe", "value":"2"}]
```

after inserting second array it replaces first object also.
where am I wrong?, Please help.

Comment: To insert a new value in array, use `Array.push`. `Array.concat` returns a new array

Comment: I have tried with push method also . It does the same in my case.

Comment: Do you have a variable that holds object or you have inline object?

Comment: i have inline array of object.
    dataList = [{"name":"BOB", "value":"1"}]
    newDataList = [{"name":"Joe", "value":"2"}]
    dataList.concat(newDataList)
    // [{"name":"Joe", "value":"2"},{"name":"Joe", "value":"2"}]

Comment: Looking at the behavior, you must have it in a variable. The issue is, objects are assigned using reference. So changing 1 variable will update value in all variables holding this reference

Comment: Your example doesn't do what you say. `concat` doesn't merge arrays in place, it returns a new array.

Comment: what output you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `push` function

```js
var dataList = [];
dataList.push({
  "name": "BOB",
  "value": "1"
});
//Pushing second object
dataList.push({
  "name": "Joe",
  "value": "2"
})
console.log(dataList)
```

Comment: If this is the ideal answer, should we not close it as dupe?

Comment: I just realized, OP has confirmed using `.push`. 2nd comment under question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

To push a value in an array, you will have to use `array.push`. `array.concat` does not adds new item. it merges 2 array and return a third array. So your code:

```
dataList.concat([{"name":"BOB", "value":"1"}])
```

does not do anything.

```js
var dataList = []
dataList.concat([{"name":"BOB", "value":"1"}])

console.log(dataList)
```

As per the behavior, your code should look something like this:

```js
var dataList = []
var obj = [{"name":"BOB", "value":"1"}];
dataList = dataList.concat(obj)
obj[0].value = 2;
dataList = dataList.concat(obj)
console.log(dataList)
```

The reason both the objects are being affected is because, objects are copied/assigned using reference. So a variable will hold a memory location and any changes to it will be reflected to this location. So if you have more than 1 variable holding this reference, it will also get updated.

---

**So how should you achieve this?**

```js
var dataList = []
var obj = {"name":"BOB", "value":"1"};
dataList = dataList.concat(obj)
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj)
obj2.value = 2;
dataList = dataList.concat(obj2)
console.log(dataList)
```

But still using Array.concat is wrong. It is not intended to be used like this.

```js
var dataList = []
var obj = {"name":"BOB", "value":"1"};
dataList.push(obj)
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj)
obj2.value = 2;
dataList.push(obj2)
console.log(dataList)
```

#### References:

- [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)
- [Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array)
- [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)
- [Object.assign - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: **Note:** Not closing as dupe as OP has confirmed he/she has tried using `.push` but it did not solve the issue. So thought of explaining what and why.