# Making changes to a copied array, updates the original?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
 let users = [{name: 'john', address: '10 king street'}, ....];
```

I copy this array via:

```
let usersCopy = users.slice(0);
```

Then if I do

```
usersCopy[0].name = jeff;
```

It also updated this on the original users array:

```
console.log(usersCopy[0].name) //jeff
console.log(users[0].name) //jeff
```

I'm expecting to see:

```
console.log(usersCopy[0].name) //jeff
console.log(users[0].name) //john
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array)

Comment: But Im changing the copy not the original.

Comment: Like said in the "duplicate", this is a "shallow copy".

In your array, you got another object (a json) who won't be cloned.

Comment: The duplicate talks about assigning the same array to a different variable, this is a different question.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `[].slice()` does a *shallow* copy, meaning you get a new array, but it doesn't clone the objects underneath. Therefore, `users[0] === usersCopy[0]`, as they are the same reference to the same object.

You will need to replace `usersCopy[0]` entirely. For example:

```
usersCopy[0] = {...usersCopy[0], name: 'jeff'}
```

Which would create a new object with everything from `usersCopy[0]` shallow-copied into it.

Comment: How can I not shallow copy the objects in the array?

Comment: You could use lodash's `_.cloneDeep` or some other method of deep cloning. But generally speaking, you should avoid deep cloning arbitrary objects, as it's rather expensive in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: As noted below this answer is not correct**

Here's an alternate way to create a separate array from the original so you can modify the `clone`

```js
const users = [{name: 'John', address: '10 king street'}];
const clone = new Array(users);

clone[0].name = 'Jeff';

console.log(clone[0].name) //jeff
console.log(users[0].name) //john
```

Comment: `clone` is now a nested array, with an additional property `name` which is equal to `Jeff`, if you try to log `clone[0].address` you'll see that it's undefined.