# Array.splice works on both state sub-arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my simple react component. I set `rooms` firstly in state in `componentWillReceiveProps` and then on `submit` I do set `rooms` to `data` in state as well.

Also on submit I do an api call by passing single object from the `rooms` and when response come then I do `slice` that object from the data (but not from `rooms`) until the `data` length is equal to **0**.

Now problem is when I do `slice` from the `data` then it `slices` the `rooms` elements as well.

```
class EditRoom extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      rooms: [],
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { fetchRooms } = this.props
    fetchRooms()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(np) {
    const { rooms, setNick, setNickName } = np
    if (this.props.rooms !== rooms) {
      console.log('ppppppppppppp')
      this.setState({ rooms })
    }
    if (setNick) {
      const data = this.state.data
      data.splice(0, 1)
      this.setState({ data }, () => {
        if (data.length === 0) {
          console.log('pppp542545455453864')
        } else {
          const room = _.first(this.state.data)
          setNickName(room)
        }
      })
    }
  }

  handleInputChange(e, i) {
    const { rooms } = this.state
    rooms[i].nickname = e.target.value
    this.setState({ rooms })
  }

  onSaveClick() {
    const { setNickName } = this.props
    this.setState({ data: this.state.rooms }, () => {
      const room = _.first(this.state.data)
      setNickName(room)
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { rooms } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <main id="EditRoom">
          {rooms &&
            rooms.map((room, i) => {
              return (
                <div className="barcode-box" key={i} style={{ backgroundColor: this.getRandomColor(i) }}>
                  <div className="edit-room-name">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}
                      name="cardNumber"
                      placeholder="Nickname"
                      value={_.get(room, 'nickname') || ''}
                      onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e, i)}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })}
        </main>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What I am missing here?

Thank you !!!

Comment: You _**should not**_ modify `this.state` directly e.g. using array mutating methods like `splice`. Instead clone `data` array from state, modify a copy and pass it to `setState()`

Comment: Could you please suggest by showing some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***should not*** modify `this.state` directly, e.g. using array mutating methods like [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Instead of this, make a copy from `this.state.data` sub-array, modify and pass it to `setState()`.

Something like this:

```
const data = this.state.data.slice() // make a copy of data
data.splice(0, 1) // modify a copy
this.setState({ data }, ...) // pass to setState
```

[***Update***] Explanation of why changing one sub-array of state affects on another:

Arrays (as all objects) in JS are passed by ***reference***. So if you do a simple assignment like `arr2 = arr1`, `splice` method will mutate the original array too. That's also true for nested arrays (objects) like in your case. `data` sub-array is stored with `rooms` together in `state`. So mutating data will affect `rooms` sub-array too.

Comment: Could you please just explain why does this happen

Comment: Arrays (and all objects) in JS are passed by reference. So if you do a simple assignment like `arr2 = arr1`, `splice` method will mutate the original array too. That's also true for nested arrays (objects) like in your case. `data` sub-array is stored with `rooms` together in `state`. So mutating `data` will affect `rooms` too. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array).