# How can i push item on an array without change the initialised array

Tags: javascript, node.js

THis is my code

```js
let a = ["a","b","c"]
let b = "dd"
let c = a
c.push(b)

console.log(a);
console.log(c);
```

But i want that when i log "a" it returns ["a","b","c"]
And when i log "c" it returns ["a","b","c", "d"]

Comment: Assigning an array reference to a different variable does not make a copy of the array.

Comment: Your statements are wrong: It does not log `["a","b","c"]` for `a` and neither `["a","b","c", "d"]` for `c`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I think that last sentence means that that's what the OP *wants*.

Comment: Why would it ever log `["a","b","c", "d"]` when you're pushing `"dd"` to the array?

Comment: I would have said this is a dupe of [Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6612385/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array/object values are copied by reference instead of by value. So, if you do `let c = a` the `c` points to the same array object as `a`

You can use Spread Operator (Shallow copy) to make a new copy of the array.

```js
let a = ["a","b","c"]
let b = "dd"
let c = [...a]
c.push(b)

console.log(a);
console.log(c);
```

Be aware this does not safely copy multi-dimensional arrays.

```js
let a = [["a"],["b"]]
let c = [...a]
let b = "dd"
c[0].push(b)

console.log(a);
console.log(c);
// [["a", "dd"], ["b"]]
// [["a", "dd"], ["b"]]
// They've both been changed because they share references
```

Comment: It's helpful to explain *why* your solution achieves the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this to make new ref

```
let a = ["a","b","c"]
let b = "dd"
let c = [...a]
c.push(b)

console.log(a);
console.log(c);
```