# Javascript push function doesn't seem to work correctly in code

Tags: javascript, arrays

Problem statement :
Clean the room function: 
Input 
`[1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20]`, 
make a function that organizes these into individual array that is ordered. 
For example answer(ArrayFromAbove) should return:

```
 [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2], 4,5,10,[20,20], 391, 392,591].
```

My Code:

```
const arrNum = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20] ;

function org(arr) {
    let finalarr = [];
    let arrnew = [];
    let val = 0;
    arr.sort((function(a, b){return a-b}));
    //console.log(arr);
    for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] != 0) {
            val = arr[i];
            arrnew.length = 0;
            arrnew.push(arr[i]);
            arr[i] = 0;
            for (j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
                if (arr[j] == val && arr[j] != 0) {
                    arrnew.push(arr[j]);
                    arr[j] = 0;
                }
            }
            finalarr.push(arrnew);
            console.log(arrnew);
        }
    }
    return finalarr;
    console.log(finalarr)
}

org(arrNum)
```

But this doesn't seem to give desired answer :
Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have found the other solutions but I need to know what is wrong in my code please.

Comment: Describe what you think your code does (in your post, not as a comment), and then look at your code again: is that really what it does?

Comment: You might wanna check this function :https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: in arr.sort no need to give comparator function

Comment: My only problem is while returning the final array, it just appends the last item of the original array mutliple times. Everything seems to be fine till then but the return is not giving the desired values. If I do finalarr = finalarr.concat(arrnew) , I get all the elements in order but as individual elements in final array. I need to have array of 1, array of 2 etc inside the final array.

Comment: The problem isn't with `finalarr`, but with `newarr`.  You are putting the same mutable array in `finalarr` several times.  You need to create a new array each time through your loop.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array.

Comment: @LukeWoodward , thanks a ton... have my answer finally :) , worked when I put the newarr inside the loop. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Objects and arrays are pushed as a pointer to the original object . Built-in primitive types like numbers or booleans are pushed as a copy.

In your code your are pushing `arrnew` in `finalarr`

```
finalarr.push(arrnew);
```

Which means reference of `arrnew` is pushed in `finalarr`.

So after first iteration of `for` loop:

```
finalarr = [[1,1,1,1]]
arrnew = [1,1,1,1]
```

Here  element of array `finalarr` is acutally pointer to array `arrnew`.

So, In the second iteration the statement

```
arrnew.length = 0
```

Will empty the array `arrnew`, as array `finalarr` have pointer to array it also gets modified:

```
finalarr= [[]]
```

Then inner `for` loop will push three `2` in array `arrnew` = `[2,2,2]`, so `finalarr` become `[[2,2,2]]`.

At the end of second iteration `finalarr.push(arrnew);` will push one new reference of `arrnew` in `finalarr`. So `finalarr` will become

```
finalarr = [[2,2,2], [2,2,2]]
```

So at the end of all iterations, `finalarr` will have 9 pointers, all pointing to `arrnew` and the final value in `arrnew` is [591].

```
finalarr = [[591],[591],[591],[591],[591],[591],[591],[591],[591]]
```

You can update you code, just replace `arrnew.length = 0` with `arrnew = []`