# Why does _.remove delete items from an original array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, lodash

I have a useState array that is being set with an array received from the backend. I am creating a new array equal to it and using `_.remove` to delete items from it. However, the original useState array is also having items deleted from it. I cannot figure out why this is the case

```
const [backendArray, setBackendArray] = useState([{some values}])

const newArray = backendArray;


useEffect(() => {
const arrayForPurpose1 = _.remove(newArray, function (n) {
      return n.value != null;
    }), [backendArray]};
```

Both `arrayForPurpose1` and `backendArray` have item.values equalling `null`. Why is that the case? I created `newArray` thinking that would sever connection between the `_.remove` and `backendArray` but it didn't.

Comment: From the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#remove): *'**Note:** Unlike `_.filter`, this method mutates array. Use `_.pull` to pull elements from an array by value.'* Also `const newArray = backendArray;` doesn't create a copy of the array it just assigns a reference to the same array to `newArray`. see: [Fastest way to duplicate an array in JavaScript - slice vs. 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-in-javascript-slice-vs-for-loop)

Comment: @pilchard I'm sorry. I've bothered you twice today -- I did read that, but I'm pretty new to coding in general and "mutate" has a different meaning to my mind. But still, I would have thought initializing a new constant and basing the _.remove on it would have prevented it?

Comment: `const newArray = backendArray;` does not clone the array. Just makes another label to the same array.

Comment: Just saw your edit - OK, that's what I didn't grasp. That's a big learning point for me in general.

Comment: Also: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: No, it's a fine question, and object referencing is one of the biggest pitfalls in learning the language and in dealing with state so the links to duplicates or relevant answers are useful going forward. (you would have been downvoted if it wasn't useful)

Comment: My God, I would have saved so much time if the docs referenced using `_.clone.` In summary, `_.pull` doesn't work because it doesn't work with an array of objects. The only way, without a lot of vanilla code, is to initialize a new array as I did but to divorce it entirely from the array it equals. Luckily lodash provides `_.clone` and `_.cloneDeep` to do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612385/why-does-changing-an-array-in-javascript-affect-copies-of-the-array)