# Array returns to starting values when pushed into another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, recursion

I have this simple recursion

```
function solve(matrix, pieces) {
    // Get next -1
    let nextEmpty = getNextEmtpy(matrix);
    if (!nextEmpty) {
        console.log(matrix)
        solutions.push(matrix);
    }
    let row = nextEmpty.row;
    let col = nextEmpty.col;
    // Try all pieces that are not in the matrix
    for (let i = 1; i < pieces.length; i++) {
        if (matrix.flat().includes(i)) continue;
        for (let r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
            let fit = rotatePiece(pieces[i]);
            if (col == 0) {
                if (fit[0] != 0) continue;
            }
            if (row == 0) {
                if (fit[1] != 0) continue;
            }
            if (col == matrix[0].length - 1) {
                if (fit[2] != 0) continue;
            }
            if (row == matrix.length - 1) {
                if (fit[3] != 0) continue;
            }
            // If the piece is not in a border
            if (col > 0) {
                if (fit[0] != pieces[matrix[row][col - 1]][2]) continue;
            }
            if (row > 0) {
                if (fit[1] != pieces[matrix[row - 1][col]][3]) continue;
            }
            // Add the piece to the matrix
            matrix[row][col] = i;
            // Update pieces
            pieces[i] = fit;
            // Recurse
            let solution = solve(matrix, pieces);
            // Reset the value 
            matrix[row][col] = -1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which should print and add to the variable solutions the same values. However it prints correctly:

```
[
  [ 25, 1, 17, 24, 7 ],
  [ 19, 16, 23, 8, 15 ],
  [ 12, 14, 4, 2, 21 ],
  [ 5, 9, 11, 6, 18 ],
  [ 10, 13, 22, 20, 3 ]
]
```

But when adding this matrix into solutions which is [] it adds:

```
  [
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ],
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ],
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ],
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ],
    [ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ]
  ]
```

Which is the starting value of matrix.
¿Why could this be happening?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Can you update the code to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem so we can also observe it?  Additionally, this is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: You aren't storing a COPY of the matrix.  There is exactly one 5x5 matrix in your program, and you are just saving multiple references to that one matrix.  By the time the program ends, that matrix contains all -1.  You need to investigate how to clone the matrix.

Comment: Thanks David for the tip and Tim, it was a problem of memory. Matrix was changed but when pushing it into an array it doesn't copy the current values but the original ones. Creating a copy did solve this.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why does changing an Array in JavaScript affect copies of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6612385) | [How do you clone an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597588)

Comment: Related: [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution, as in the comments is said, was to actually copy matrix into solutions instead of referencing it directly.

```
    if (!nextEmpty) {
    let copy = matrix.map((row) => row.slice());
    solutions.push(copy);
}
```