# How to save new array?

Tags: javascript

I am have an array:

```
var data = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
```

And if I run my code this array changes to something like:

```
var data = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
];
```

And my question: How to save or copy this new array?

Comment: That's not very specific. Save it *where*? localStorage? Make an AJAX call?

Comment: Something like output this to <textarea>

Comment: Check the answer about printing to `<textarea>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was very detailed dicussion about related topic. You can found here details: [How do you clone an Array of Objects in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

And probably the most clear answer you can found here [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object/122704#122704) from John Resig

About saving issue - more details needed where exactly you want to save it.

**Print data to `<textarea>`**

script

```
var data = [
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
            ];

$(document).ready(function () {
    var printData = '';
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        printData += '[';
        $.each(value, function (index, value) {
            printData += value + ','
        });
        printData += ']\r\n';
    });

    $('#console').val(printData);
});
```

html

```
<textarea id="console"></textarea>
```

Comment: Also not to mention that above code uses jquery and not plain javascript.

Comment: Why not just use `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Yes, it can be used, but in this case the presentation will be not so clear (without line breaks)