# How to create multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Can anyone give me a sample/example of JavaScript with a multidimensional array of inputs? Hope you could help because I'm still new to the JavaScript.

Like when you input 2 rows and 2 columns the output of it will be 2 rows of input and 2 columns of input.

Like this:

```
[input][input]                
[input][input]
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'inputs'? An `<input>` element or just some variable?

Comment: yes sir.. an <input type = "text">

Comment: For those looking to make multidimensional arrays with arbitrary sizes and number of dimensions, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588618/javascript-n-dimensional-array-creation/32759574#32759574).

Answer (score 336, accepted):

```
var numeric = [
    ['input1','input2'],
    ['input3','input4']
];
numeric[0][0] == 'input1';
numeric[0][1] == 'input2';
numeric[1][0] == 'input3';
numeric[1][1] == 'input4';

var obj = {
    'row1' : {
        'key1' : 'input1',
        'key2' : 'input2'
    },
    'row2' : {
        'key3' : 'input3',
        'key4' : 'input4'
    }
};
obj.row1.key1 == 'input1';
obj.row1.key2 == 'input2';
obj.row2.key1 == 'input3';
obj.row2.key2 == 'input4';

var mixed = {
    'row1' : ['input1', 'inpu2'],
    'row2' : ['input3', 'input4']
};
mixed.row1[0] == 'input1';
mixed.row1[1] == 'input2';
mixed.row2[0] == 'input3';
mixed.row2[1] == 'input4';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4Un3/

And if you're wanting to store DOM elements:

```
var inputs = [
    [
        document.createElement('input'),
        document.createElement('input')
    ],
    [
        document.createElement('input'),
        document.createElement('input')
    ]
];
inputs[0][0].id = 'input1';
inputs[0][1].id = 'input2';
inputs[1][0].id = 'input3';
inputs[1][1].id = 'input4';
```

Not real sure how useful the above is until you attach the elements. The below may be more what you're looking for:

```
<input text="text" id="input5"/>
<input text="text" id="input6"/>
<input text="text" id="input7"/>
<input text="text" id="input8"/>    
var els = [
    [
        document.getElementById('input5'),
        document.getElementById('input6')
    ],
    [
        document.getElementById('input7'),
        document.getElementById('input8')
    ]
];    
els[0][0].id = 'input5';
els[0][1].id = 'input6';
els[1][0].id = 'input7';
els[1][1].id = 'input8';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4Un3/3/

Or, maybe this:

```
<input text="text" value="4" id="input5"/>
<input text="text" value="4" id="input6"/>
<br/>
<input text="text" value="2" id="input7"/>
<input text="text" value="4" id="input8"/>

var els = [
    [
        document.getElementById('input5'),
        document.getElementById('input6')
    ],
    [
        document.getElementById('input7'),
        document.getElementById('input8')
    ]
];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    result[result.length] = els[0][i].value - els[1][i].value;
}
```

Which gives:

```
[2, 0]
```

In the console. If you want to output that to text, you can `result.join(' ');`, which would give you `2 0`.

http://jsfiddle.net/z4Un3/6/

**EDIT**

And a working demonstration:

```
<input text="text" value="4" id="input5"/>
<input text="text" value="4" id="input6"/>
<br/>
<input text="text" value="2" id="input7"/>
<input text="text" value="4" id="input8"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/>

// This would just go in a script block in the head
function add() {
    var els = [
        [
            document.getElementById('input5'),
            document.getElementById('input6')
        ],
        [
            document.getElementById('input7'),
            document.getElementById('input8')
        ]
    ];

    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        result[result.length] = parseInt(els[0][i].value) - parseInt(els[1][i].value);
    }

    alert(result.join(' '));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4Un3/8/

Comment: can i know how thus this work sir.. im kinda confuse of Javascript

Comment: What is it you're confused about?

Comment: about is it like im going to make an HTML file where there is two inputs and it is the inputs of Rows and Columns or something else?

Comment: I'm not really following what you're saying. What are you trying to with your array? (Also, see my last edit.)

Comment: in array im going to input a number of rows and columns with a unique name or ID..and another rows and columns with a unique name or ID where the the first array of inputs rows and columns will be subtracted to the 2nd inputs of R and C..

Comment: Ok, see my very last edit. Note, you need `console` open to see the result (Chrome, Firefox w/Firebug, IE9). Also, this is running `onDOMReady`; your actual script would need to run at least after the elements were parsed into the DOM, but not before.

Comment: Nice answer, but I can see where the OP is coming from. Advanced answer for people who don't yet have an understanding of JS to appreciate the content provided above.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Correct me if I'm wrong but if you use the obj syntax or mixed you can still do `obj['Value']` or `var ValueVariable = 'Value'; obj[ValueVariable]` instead of `obj.Value` to get or set values. Right?

Comment: @Dan - Yes that would work. Any place where a variable will be interpreted as a string in that situation would work.

Answer (score 31):

Quote taken from [Data Structures and Algorithms with JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IV3J23Y)

> The Good Parts (O’Reilly, p. 64). Crockford extends the JavaScript
>   array object with a function that sets the number of rows and columns
>   and sets each value to a value passed to the function. Here is his
>   definition:

```
Array.matrix = function(numrows, numcols, initial) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numrows; ++i) {
        var columns = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < numcols; ++j) {
            columns[j] = initial;
        }
        arr[i] = columns;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Here is some code to test the definition:

```
var nums = Array.matrix(5,5,0);
print(nums[1][1]); // displays 0
var names = Array.matrix(3,3,"");
names[1][2] = "Joe";
print(names[1][2]); // display "Joe"
```

We can also create a two-dimensional array and initialize it to a set of values in one line:

```
var grades = [[89, 77, 78],[76, 82, 81],[91, 94, 89]];
print(grades[2][2]); // displays 89
```

Answer (score 17):

Declared without value assignment.

2 dimensions...

```
var arrayName = new Array(new Array());
```

3 dimensions...

```
var arrayName = new Array(new Array(new Array()));
```

Comment: Both of these examples seem to only produce 1x1 & 1x1x1 arrays (respectively), maybe properly called single dimension nested arrays. As an example `var test=new Array(new Array());test[0][0]='1';test[0][1]='2';test[1][0]='3';` errors with message `Exception: test[1] is undefined`

Comment: This seems wrong. When I try the code I get a 1x1x0 array. http://jsfiddle.net/zU8SB/1/ How has it gotten 13 upvotes?

Comment: Insert with ['Array.push'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 14):

I know this is ancient but what about...

4x4 example `(actually 4x<anything>)`:

```
var matrix = [ [],[],[],[] ]
```

which can filled by:

```
for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
   for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = i*j;
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps might make it more obvious that nothing "outside" 1x4 (so not matrix[3][3] being the 4th row, 4th column) is declared (i.e., accessible) with this var declaration. Also, the example setting element [0][1] to 5 skips the first element. Using [0][0] instead, could be useful to demonstrate an important point of arrays in a lot of programming languages.

Answer (score 9):

Hope the following code suits your requirement

```
var row= 20;
var column= 10;
var f = new Array();

for (i=0;i<row;i++) {
 f[i]=new Array();
 for (j=0;j<column;j++) {
  f[i][j]=0;
 }
}
```

Comment: YES!! Been struggling with this forever! The secret is creating the extra array at the row column (or if iterating through a grid, the height)

Answer (score 8):

```
function Array2D(x, y)
{
    var array2D = new Array(x);

    for(var i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++)
    {
        array2D[i] = new Array(y);
    }

    return array2D;
}

var myNewArray = Array2D(4, 9);

myNewArray[3][5] = "booger";
```

Answer (score 8):

very simple

```
var states = [,];
states[0,0] = tName; 
states[0,1] = '1';
states[1,0] = tName; 
states[2,1] = '1';
```

.
.
.

```
states[n,0] = tName; 
states[n,1] = '1';
```

Comment: This does not seem to work when I test it in the console. It seems that the old values get deleted when I write to say a[0,1] and a[1,1], the second deletes a[0,1]...

Answer (score 4):

```
var size = 0;   
 var darray = new Array();
    function createTable(){
        darray[size] = new Array();
        darray[size][0] = $("#chqdate").val();
        darray[size][1]= $("#chqNo").val();
        darray[size][2] = $("#chqNarration").val() ;
        darray[size][3]= $("#chqAmount").val();
        darray[size][4]= $("#chqMode").val();
    }
```

increase size var after your function.

Answer (score 4):

So here's my solution.

A simple example for a 3x3 Array. You can keep chaining this to go deeper

```
Array(3).fill().map(a => Array(3))
```

Or the following function will generate any level deep you like

```
f = arr => {
    let str = 'return ', l = arr.length;
    arr.forEach((v, i) => {
        str += i < l-1 ? `Array(${v}).fill().map(a => ` : `Array(${v}` + ')'.repeat(l);
    });
    return Function(str)();
}
f([4,5,6]) // Generates a 4x5x6 Array
```

http://www.binaryoverdose.com/2017/02/07/Generating-Multidimensional-Arrays-in-JavaScript/

Answer (score 2):

you can create array follow the code below:

```
var arraymultidimensional = []
    arraymultidimensional = [[value1,value2],[value3,value4],[value5,value6]];
```

Result: 
 [v1][v2] position 0 
 [v3][v4] position 1 
 [v5][v6] position 2

For add to array dinamically, use the method below:

```
//vectorvalue format = "[value,value,...]"
function addToArray(vectorvalue){
  arraymultidimensional[arraymultidimensional.length] = vectorvalue;
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've created an [npm module](https://github.com/arjunmehta/multidimensional) to do this with some added flexibility:

```
// create a 3x3 array
var twodimensional = new MultiDimensional([3, 3])

// create a 3x3x4 array
var threedimensional = new MultiDimensional([3, 3, 4])

// create a 4x3x4x2 array
var fourdimensional = new MultiDimensional([4, 3, 4, 2])

// etc...
```

You can also initialize the positions with any value:

```
// create a 3x4 array with all positions set to 0
var twodimensional = new MultiDimensional([3, 4], 0)

// create a 3x3x4 array with all positions set to 'Default String'
var threedimensionalAsStrings = new MultiDimensional([3, 3, 4], 'Default String')
```

Or more advanced:

```
// create a 3x3x4 array with all positions set to a unique self-aware objects.
var threedimensional = new MultiDimensional([3, 3, 4], function(position, multidimensional) {
    return {
        mydescription: 'I am a cell at position ' + position.join(),
        myposition: position,
        myparent: multidimensional
    }
})
```

Get and set values at positions:

```
// get value
threedimensional.position([2, 2, 2])

// set value
threedimensional.position([2, 2, 2], 'New Value')
```

Answer (score 1):

Create uninitialized multidimensional array:

```
function MultiArray(a) {
  if (a.length < 1) throw "Invalid array dimension";
  if (a.length == 1) return Array(a[0]);
  return [...Array(a[0])].map(() => MultiArray(a.slice(1)));
}
```

Create initialized multidimensional array:

```
function MultiArrayInit(a, init) {
  if (a.length < 1) throw "Invalid array dimension";
  if (a.length == 1) return Array(a[0]).fill(init);
  return [...Array(a[0])].map(() => MultiArrayInit(a.slice(1), init));
}
```

Usage:

```
MultiArray([3,4,5]);  // -> Creates an array of [3][4][5] of empty cells

MultiArrayInit([3,4,5], 1);  // -> Creates an array of [3][4][5] of 1s
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  I think you  should push for your MultiArrayInit  function to be added to ECMA2023.  It is sorely lacking in js.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

```js
let rows = 5;
let cols = 4;
let defaultValue = 0;

Array(rows).fill([]).map((x) => x = Array(cols).fill(defaultValue));
```

resulting into

```
(5) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]
1: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]
2: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]
3: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]
4: (4) [0, 0, 0, 0]
length: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a one linear for this:

```
[1, 3, 1, 4, 1].reduceRight((x, y) => new Array(y).fill().map(() => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))), 0);
```

I feel however I can spend more time to make a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`-free version which is used for [cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597588) here.

Btw, have a look at my another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951704).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is something to try:
Make your multidimensional array, and place it inside an html tag.
This way you can precisely aim your array'd input:

```
//Your Holding tag for your inputs!
<div id='input-container' class='funky'></div>

<script>
    //With VAR: you can seperate each variable with a comma instead of:
    //creating var at the beginning and a semicolon at the end.
    //Creates a cleaner layout of your variables
    var
        arr=[['input1-1','input1-2'],['input2-1','input2-2']],
        //globall calls these letters var so you dont have to recreate variable below
        i,j
    ;

    //Instead of the general 'i<array.length' you can go even further
    //by creating array[i] in place of 'i<array.length'
    for(i=0;arr[i];i++){
    for(j=0;arr[i][j];j++){
        document.getElementById('input-container').innerHTML+=
            "<input class='inner-funky'>"+arr[i][j]+"</input>"
        ;
    }}
</script>
```

Its simply a neater way to write your code and easier to invoke.  You can check my demo [here!](https://jsfiddle.net/NitroXAce/d1qro5g3/114/)

Comment: you can go bolder by making `document.querySelectorAll();` to get classes, ids, and even elements!