# How to use multidimensional array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list item with heading in my page. I want push heading text in one array and then create a new array and push list item to them on click event like. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mepSr/).

Expected result:

```
Arr = ['small alpha', 'big alpha', 'number'];
Arr['small alpha'] = ['a','b','c'];
```

Code:

```
var Arr = [];
$('a').click(function() {
    Arr.push($(this).closest('ul').find('h2').text());
    alert(Arr['small alpha'])
    Arr[0].push($(this).closest('ul').find('li').text());
    console.log(Arr)    
});
```

Comment: Please describe the problems you're having with your code. Also, your HTML is invalid as you can only have `li` elements as direct children of `ul`.

Comment: I want Expected result: from the code

Comment: It is easy to do. But if i click single `a` do you want to get all `ul` and their `li`'s

Comment: @user10: If we click single a it should add their respective ul

Comment: respective `ul` in one array and their `li`'s in another array. correct? and if i click `a` again and again, it should have only one `ui` for that. correct?

Comment: i answered you. Is that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Turning `Arr[0]` into an array

The initial problem with what you're trying to do here is that `Arr[0]` isn't an array. If your code was working correctly (by pulling the "small alpha" `h2` element into your `Arr` element at position 0), `Arr[0]` would be a string.

```
Arr[0] === "small alpha";
```

Therefore, when calling `Arr[0].push()` you're attempting to call an array method on a string. This throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object small alpha has no method 'push'

To rectify this, we need to turn `Arr[0]` into an array simply by declaring `Arr[0] = []`:

```
...
Arr[0] = [];
Arr[0].push($(this).closest('ul').find('li').text());
...
```

---

### Fixing your code

Firstly you'll want to store your `h2` text into a reusable variable:

```
var key = $(this).closest('ul').find('h2').text();
```

*It's well worth noting at this point that `h2` elements aren't allowed to be children of `ul` elements, so your HTML isn't valid in its current state. You'll need to fix this yourself and come up with a different selector, but for the remainder of this answer I'll work with what is currently there.*

As we're using this as a key, we don't need to push this value into the array, so we drop the first `push()` call altogether.

Rather than then using `Arr[0]` to reference your key, we can instead use `Arr[key]`. We now need to create your inner array and push the `li` text into it:

```
Arr[key] = [];
Arr[key].push($(this).closest('ul').find('li').text());
```

Altogether, your code will now look like this:

```
var Arr= [];
$('a').click(function(){
    var key = $(this).closest('ul').find('h2').text();
    Arr[key] = [];
    Arr[key].push($(this).closest('ul').find('li').text());
    console.log(Arr)    
});
```

The result of this is:

> [small alpha: Array[1](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/mepSr/5/)]
>   --- 0: "abC"

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/mepSr/5/).

---

### Pushing each `li` text into your array separately

The problem with the above code is that all of your `li` values are condensed into one: `Arr['small alpha'] === ["abC"]`. To fix this, we can introduce the [jQuery `map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Rather than calling `...find('li').text()`, we're now going to use `map()` to map each `li`'s text into an array:

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('li').map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get()
```

Collectively your code now looks like this:

```
var Arr= [];
$('a').click(function(){
    var key = $(this).closest('ul').find('h2').text();
    Arr[key] = [];
    Arr[key].push($(this).closest('ul').find('li')
        .map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get());
    console.log(Arr)    
});
```

The result of this is:

> [small alpha: Array[1](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/mepSr/5/)]
>   ... 0: "a"
>   ... 1: "b"
>   ... 2: "C"

---

### [**Final JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/mepSr/13/).

---

If you were to then click on all three "get" links, you'd end up with:

```
Arr
    ['small alpha']
        ['a', 'b', 'C']
    ['big alpha']
        ['A', 'B', 'C']
    ['number']
        [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @user10 nothing at all, but that's not what the question asks for.

Comment: :) but. i prefer this kind of things in object. Anyway, if he prefers that, that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript objects

http://javascript.ru/Object

Answer (score 0):

use the logic Something like.

```
var arr = [
    ['member1','member2'],
    ['member3','member4']
];

arr [0][0] == 'member1';
arr [0][1] == 'member2';
arr [1][0] == 'member3';
arr [1][1] == 'member4';
```

See the Answer 
  [JavaScript multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mepSr/6/)

```
var Arr= [], Arr2 = {};


$('a').click(function(){
var ht = $(this).closest('ul').find('h2').text(), a = [];

Arr.push(ht);

    $(this).closest('ul').find("li").each(function () {
        a.push($(this).text());
    })

Arr2[ht] = a;

console.log(Arr);
console.log(Arr2);
})
```

Comment: `Arr2["your header text"]` will give you the value.