# Adding multiple answers to quiz

Tags: javascript

I need to add multiple questionnaires to use the same code. How can I do this?

```
// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = ["Apple", "Test"] ;
answers[1] = "Dynamic HTML";
answers[2] = "Netscape";
answers[3] = "Common Gateway Interface";
```

As you can see Ive just tried adding my other answer onto the code for a different quiz but it does not recognise. What is the best way of doing this? (is there an "or" command or something like that?

Here is my whole code:

```
// Insert number of questions
var numQues = 4;

// Insert number of choices in each question
var numChoi = 3;

// Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
var answers = new Array(4);


// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = ["Apple", "Test"] ;
answers[1] = "Dynamic HTML", "Test";
answers[2] = "Netscape",  "Test";
answers[3] = "Common Gateway Interface", "Test";

// Do not change anything below here ...
function getScore(form) {
var score = 0;
var currElt;
var currSelection;
for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
currElt = i*numChoi;
for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
  currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
  if (currSelection.checked) {
    if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
      score++;
      break;
    }
  }
 }
}
score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
form.percentage.value = score + "%";
var correctAnswers = "";
for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
}
form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
} 
//  End -->
```

Comment: please more detail version of the question need ? very ambigous queston ?

Comment: Added whole code: please read my comments below aswell

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `Object literal` notation

```
var answers = {
    0: ["Apple", "Test"],
    1: "Dynamic HTML",
    2: "Netscape",
    3: "Common Gateway Interface"
};
```

You can acess your answers with answers[0], answers[1],...

Do you mean this ?

Comment: I dont want to repeat the whole code for multiple quiz's. I want to use the same code just pick from  a diffrerent list of answers

Answer (score 0):

You need a multidimensional array concept to give more flexible option to answers as follow :

```
var answers = [
    ['Apple','Test'],
    ['Dynamic HTML','DHTML']
    ['Netscape',''], //you can live this blank
    ['Common Gateway Interface','CGI']
];
```

//how to access answers like you wanted it more values to compare

```
if((answers [0][0] == 'Appel')||(answers[0][1] == 'Test')) {
   alert('Correct Answer');
}
```

**option two:**
For more Please refer this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array)  and let me know.

[Tested Here See result](http://jsfiddle.net/ytq2X/)