# Javascript multidimensional array returning wrong dimension

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I initialize an array as such:

```
    imgArray = [];
    imgArray[0,0] = "image1";
    imgArray[1,0] = "image2";
    imgArray[0,1] = "image3";
    imgArray[1,1] = "image4";
    imgArray[0,2] = "image5";
    imgArray[1,2] = "image6";
```

When I do an alert for imgArray[0,2], I get image6.  When I do an alert for      imgArray[0,1], I get image4.  When I do an alert for imgArray[1,1], I get image4 which is correct.

It appears that the imgArray is totally ignoring my 0 dimension.

Comment: There are no multi-dimensional arrays in JavaScript. Use an array of arrays instead.

Comment: Your problem comes from the comma operator that gets applied to your two indices (Javascript only supports one). See [JavaScript multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array).

Comment: i think syntex is wrong

Comment: @user, on the contrary, the syntax is valid, but `imgArray[1, 0]` is evaluated as `1; imgArray[0]` because of the comma operator.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi this sounds interesting, can you tell us more about what is happening here and how is this syntaxically correct?

Comment: @GôTô, yes. The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates its operands from left to right and returns the value of its last operand. Only a single array index is supported, so `imgArray[1, 0]` applies the comma operator to `1` and `0` and uses the result (`0`) as the array index. There could be anything instead of `1`, it would not matter (to be specific, only the side effects of that expression would matter).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thank you, sounds very useful (and quite obscure) to understand js. Got burnt by visiting your wife's site btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multidimensional Arrays in Javascript are written in seperate brackets:

```
imgArray = [];
imgArray[0] = [];
imgArray[1] = [];
imgArray[0][0] = "image1";
imgArray[1][0] = "image2";
imgArray[0][1] = "image3";
imgArray[1][1] = "image4";
imgArray[0][2] = "image5";
imgArray[1][2] = "image6";
```

Comment: Tried code change above, get undefined error when trying to access imgArray[1,2]. I have tried every example in all the previous posts about this same topic and they all ignore my left dimension.

Comment: Don't try to get `imgArray[1,2]` (read the answers instead). The correct use is `imgArray[1][2]`

Comment: That worked.  After so many hours looking at this BS, I guess I overlooked the details in the comments.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
imgArray = [];
imgArray[0] = ["image1", "image2"];
```

Multidimensional arrays in JavaScript are simply nested arrays.

Comment: Tried this imgArray[0]=["image1.jpg","image3.jpg","image5.jpg"];
imgArray[1]=["image2.jpg","images4.jpg","image6.jpg"]; and for imgArray[0,1] I get returned everything in 1,0 which is image2, image4, image6.