# How to create multi dimensional javascript object in php?

Tags: javascript, php, object

How to create multi-dimensional javascript object in php?

I want to create javascript object from below php array,

```
$arrCat = array();
$arrCat['vehicles']['id'][0] = 2;
$arrCat['vehicles']['name'][0] = 'cars';
$arrCat['vehicles']['id'][1] = 3;
$arrCat['vehicles']['name'][1] = 'bikes';
$arrCat['property']['id'][0] = 5;
$arrCat['property']['name'][0] = 'house';
$arrCat['property']['id'][1] = 6;
$arrCat['property']['name'][1] = 'apartments';
```

Please help!

Comment: does `json_encode($arrCat)` not work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array

Comment: yes that did work, but how can i loop through that object in javascript,

    var obj = {"vehicles":{"id":[2,3],"name":["cars","bikes"]},"property":{"id":[5,6],"name":["house","apartments"]}}

Comment: You'll loop through it using `jQuery.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

for single dimension use it.

```
 looping through as :-   
     $arrCat = array(); 
        $dat = array();//a dummy array
        foreach($your_array as $val)
                            {
                                $dat['id'] = $val['value'];
                                $dat['name'] = $val['value'];
                                $arrCat [] = $dat;
                            }
        echo json_encode($arrCat );
        die;
```

for multidimensional change $arrCat['your_parent_array_name']['index'][] = 'your_value'  ;
        i hope this will help you.