# Convert Text FIle to Associative Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, replace, associative-array

I been given the a text file, and I want to convert it to an associative array so I can use a plugin and to convert the data into a table. The smartest way to do this I believe is to make it into an assoc. array, but everything i been trying gets me nowhere. Originally the file only have the IDs, not the names and yes I could manually erase the names and just used the numbers but it just seems counterproductive.

Here is the text file **users.txt**

```
Person_1    USERID_1
Person_2    USERID_2
Person_3    USERID_3
Person_4    USERID_4
Person_5    USERID_5
Person_6    USERID_6
Person_7    USERID_7
Person_8    USERID_8
Person_9    USERID_9
Person_10   USERID_10
```

Here is how my code was to read the original file that just had the numbers, **users.js**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var userArray = [];
    $.get('../users.txt', function(data){
        userArray = data.split('\n');
        console.log(userArray);
        var barChartData = {
             labels : ["User 1","User 2","User 3","User 4","User 5","User 6","User 7","User 8","User 9","User 10"],
             datasets : [
                {
                    label: "Number of CD's Bought",
                    fillColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(222,222,222,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(222,222,222,1)",
                    data : [userArray[0],userArray[1],userArray[2],userArray[3],userArray[4],userArray[5],userArray[6],userArray[7],userArray[8],userArray[9]]
                }
            ]
        };
```

How can I update my code so I can have `User[0][0]` to be `Person_1` and `User[0][1]` to be `USERID_1` and so on for the other. I tried to replace the newline `\n` but it only does it in the first line and the remaining newlines are `↵` in the console. Any ideas?

*Just as note I originally get and XML file from a Query as A Web Service but that one has been even more troublesome*

Comment: What are the delimiting characters between data elements? Is that white-space or tabs `\t` between `Person` and `USERID`? Are there new lines `\n` or carriage returns `\r` (or both) at the end of each line?

Comment: Visit this stackoverflow post on [JavaScript multidimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array)
it is very helpful!

Comment: Yes there is a tab between between `Person` and `USERID`. As for the new line I am not certain if is just `\n`, `\r` or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
var userArray =data.split('\n');
for(i=0;i<userArray .length;i++){
    var u=userArray [i];
    var t=[];
    var temp=u.split(/\s+/g);

    t.push(temp[0]);
    t.push(temp[1]);
    userArray [i]=t;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/4sk387bw/2/)

Comment: I tried your approach but when I tried `t.push(temp[0]);` I get `P` isntead of `Person_1` and when I tried `t.push(temp[1]);` I get `e` instead of `USERID_1`, I think the issue there is the the file that is being read

Comment: that means temp is not splitting correctly, could you see what temp has after initialized?

Comment: This is the console entry when i did `console.log('This is temp ' + temp);` each of the entries for each of the lines.
`This is temp Person_1,USERID_1
This is temp Person_2,USERID_2
This is temp Person_3,USERID_3
This is temp Person_4,USERID_4
This is temp Person_5,USERID_5
This is temp Person_6,USERID_6
This is temp Person_7,USERID_7
This is temp Person_8,USERID_8
This is temp Person_9,USERID_9
This is temp Person_10,USERID_10`

Comment: and `t.push(temp[0])` just pushes P?

Comment: I get this `This is t after t.push(temp[0]) Person_1` So its pushing `Person_1`??

Comment: There was an error in my code. This is the solution! Thank you so much @depperm!