# How to create multidimensional array for each row?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

For a website I used a grid layout. What I want is to store all items per row inside a row.

I have an overall array that is calling `arrWrap = [];`. Now I want to create for each row an new array, where I store each time 4 items. So a new array should be created after the third item in a row.

How do I achieve this?
I use Javascript for this project.

```
   var arrPos = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) { 

            arrPos[i] = i;
            console.dir(arrPos[i]);

            if (arrPos[i] > 3) {
                alert(arrPos[i]);

            };
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Javascript Multidimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrWrap = [];
var steps = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i=i+steps) { 
    arrWrap.push(elements.slice(i,i+steps));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: elements.slice is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
var cIndex= 0;
var data=[];
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "a", "v", "c", "q"];
for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
  cIndex = cIndex + 3;
  var row = cars.slice(cIndex -3,cIndex );
  data.push(row);
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This proposal feature the `Array.prototype.reduce` and offers two solutions:

1. Grouped by consecutive elements `dataGroupedA`

> ```
> [
>     [  0,  1,  2 ],
>     [  3,  4,  5 ],
>     [  6,  7,  8 ],
>     [  9, 10, 11 ],
>     [ 12, 13, 14 ]
> ]
> ```

2. Grouped by the 5th element `dataGroupedB`

> ```
> [
>     [ 0, 5, 10 ],
>     [ 1, 6, 11 ],
>     [ 2, 7, 12 ],
>     [ 3, 8, 13 ],
>     [ 4, 9, 14 ]
> ]
> ```

The calculation of `index` is the important part. The rest is standard default assignment and pushing the actual element.

```js
var data = Array.apply(Array, { length: 15 }).map(function (_, i) { return i; }),
    dataGroupedA = data.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var index = i / 3 | 0;
        r[index] = r[index] || [];
        r[index].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []),
    dataGroupedB = data.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var index = i % 5;
        r[index] = r[index] || [];
        r[index].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(dataGroupedA, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(dataGroupedB, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```