# insert values to a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to insert/push values into a blank multidimensional array.

I am having trouble doing it. My code is

```
var online = [];
//already used the  = new Array();

//My Method 1:
online.push({'1921020309','ALLIED BANK','Savings Account'});

//My Method 2:
online[0][0] = '1921020309';
online[0][1] = 'ALLIED BANK';
online[0][2] = 'Savings Account';

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = online;
```

What I am doing wrong here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Method 2 looks good.  Does it give an error?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yup dude it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Do either of these help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: In method 1, your syntax is wrong, array literals use square parenthesis: `['1921020309','ALLIED BANK','Savings Account']`. Curly braces are for Object literals: `{key:value,...}`.

Comment: Just found the right codes. 

`var online = new Array(2);
online[0] = new Array('1921020309', 'ALLIED BANK', 'Savings Account');
online[1] = new Array('028-00-000831-3', 'Bank of Commerce', 'Auto Transfer Account');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = online;`

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks for the Hint.

Comment: @LeeBalino—you don't need to set the length when creating an array, it's self–adjusting. It is generally preferred to use an array literal (e.g. `[valu0, value1, ...]`) rather than the using the Array constructor: `new Array(value0, value1, ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a new array for every dimension:

```
online[0] = []; // <-
online[0][0] = '1921020309';
online[0][1] = 'ALLIED BANK';
online[0][2] = 'Savings Account';
```

Comment: Tried this man but it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Comment: I assumed that you still have `var online = [];` at the top and nothing else.

Comment: No dude I change that to what you have gave `online[0] = [];`

Comment: Just already found the right combination of codes `var online = new Array(2);
online[0] = new Array('1921020309', 'ALLIED BANK', 'Savings Account');
online[1] = new Array('028-00-000831-3', 'Bank of Commerce', 'Auto Transfer Account');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = online;`

I am putting it to the answers. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the right answer to my question

```
var online = new Array(2);
online[0] = new Array('1921020309', 'ALLIED BANK', 'Savings Account');
online[1] = new Array('028-00-000831-3', 'Bank of Commerce', 'Auto Transfer Account');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = online;
```

Now all works fine.