# JavaScript loops and Arrays Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have the following codes which I am unable to understand. I have just started to learn JavaScript. Please can someone describe this code snippet.

```
function cyst(data, options) {  
    var uniq_nds = fast(sumer),
              id = [];

            for(var x = 0 ; x < uniq_nds.length; x++) {
                id[id.length] = uniq_nds[x]['data']['id'];          
            }
}
```

The code for the `fast` method:

```
function fast(a) {
    var seen = {};
    var out = [];
    var len = a.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var item = a[i]['data']['id'];
        if (seen[item] !== 1) {
            seen[item] = 1;
            out[out.length] = a[i];
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Especially I want to know about this line.
            `id[id.length] = uniq_ndes[x]['data']['id'];`

Comment: what is `fast` function stand for

Comment: That line is just JavaScript’s bracket notation.

Comment: It's just adding a value to the "id" array.

Comment: fast is a function that returns a data

Comment: With this we cannot give you a clear explanation, a lot of data that helps us to understand what you don't understand ins't there, think of sample data structures like the result of the `fast` function and the arguments to the `cyst` function (What is `data` and what is / are `options`)?

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand Explain me `id[id.length] = uniq_ndes[x]['data']['id'];`

Comment: Post a minimal but complete set of data for the `uniq_ndes` variable please, I'm asking for clarification from your side, not what you'd like me to explain ;)

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand Here is the function fast

` function fast(a) {
  var seen = {};  
  var out = []; 
  var len = a.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var item = a[i]['data']['id'];
    if(seen[item] !== 1) {                 
       seen[item] = 1;  
       out[out.length] = a[i]; 
    }
  }
  return out;
 }`

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand Please help bro

Comment: `id[id.length] = something;` stores a value just past the existing end of the `id` array and is equivalent to calling the Array's push method,  `id.push( something);`

Comment: I've added an answer *trying to explain* what you're doing and how you're doing it, I hope it's clear for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a *complex* data structure that you want to filter the ID's out of.

So you have a nested array (the *complex* structure) like this:
*( **NOTE: This is an example structure** )*

```
uniq_nds = [
    {
        data: {
            id: 1,
            other: '...'
        }
    },
    {
        data: {
            id: 2,
            other: '...'
        }
    },
    {
        data: {
            id: 1,
            other: '...'
        }
    },
]
```

With some duplicate `id` fields deeply nested.
These get filtered by your `fast` method which will only return data that hasn't already been identified through the `id` field.

Therefore your array will only contain unique ID's:

```
uniq_nds = [
    {
        data: {
            id: 1,
            other: '...'
        }
    },
    {
        data: {
            id: 2,
            other: '...'
        }
    }
]
```

Then comes the part where you essentially [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the ID's to an array using a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) loop.

Your loop however looks a bit different from the usual loop you'd see as you're using the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of the `id` array that you're continuously filling with elements, that means that if the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) is `0`, your first element will be placed in `id[0]`. When assigning an element to `id[0]` the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property changes and increments by `1` (you're adding 1 item to the array) so the next time you loop the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property on the `id` array will return `1` therefore setting the next item in the array.

In the end this will cause you to end up with an array filled with ID's.

Now for the assignment part of your operation, e.g.

```
id[id.length] = uniq_nds[x]['data']['id']
```

Here you're looping with the variable `x`, which happens to also automatically get incremented by the [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) loop every time it runs.

This means that the first time your loop runs, it will fetch index `0` of array `uniq_nds`. The result of that is an object:

```
console.log(uniq_nds[0]);
=>  {
        data: {
            id: 1
        }
    }
```

You can then use the bracket notation to access the `data` property of `uniq_nds[0]` which will return another object e.g.

```
console.log(uniq_nds[0]['data']);

=>  {
        id: 1
    }
```

And when you've done that you can now *finally* access that `id` that you want to have in your array e.g.

```
console.log(uniq_nds[0]['data']['id']);

=> 1
```

Now the entire explanation here might be a bit tough to chew on as a beginner but I hope I explained it well enough for you.

All that you're doing is assigning an array index to a value so that you can call / loop through them later with more [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) loops or using functions like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

You're doing this in a bit of a complex way too, you don't need to do:

```
id[id.length] = uniq_nds[x]['data']['id'];
```

In your loop at all, instead you can use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) which will dynamically *append* the item at the **end** of the array:

```
id.push(uniq_nds[x]['data']['id']);
```

This will get rid of the `id.length` usage which doesn't really explain what you're doing like `push` does (pushing an element into an array).

Also, the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function I keep mentioning can be used to do this in one line.

```
id = uniq_nds.map(function(obj) { return obj.data.id; });
```

Since `uniq_nds` returns an array, it can be looped over using `map`, which runs the provided callback function (`function(obj) { return obj.data.id; }`) for every item in that array, returning an array of values returned by the callback.

This allows you to easily transform your complex data structure to a simple array of ID's.

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much @Sidney

Answer (score 1):

the object uniq_nds is an array of objects, and he is trying to extract all id's from this initial array structure to an array with only the id's not the full object. Is a little bit confusing because is using different index in the array/matrix. Would be the same if use this:

```
for(var x = 0 ; x < uniq_nds.length; x++) {
            id[x] = uniq_nds[x]['data']['id'];          
}
```

An example to accomplish this situation would be something like this:

```
function test () {
    var id = {id:'12'}
    var object = {name:"Fiat", data:{id:'12', name:'another detail'}}; 
    var array=[];
    array[0]=object;
    array[1]=object;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var id = array[i]['data']['id']
        var name = array[i]['data']['name']
        console.log(id + " " + name);
    }
}

test();
```

Comment: Its very confusing. First time I've encountered that. Can you show me an example?

Comment: An example of an array of arrays?

Comment: Sorry the delay, but when i was writing the example i figured out was not possible the structure of array of matrix, what is really is an array of objects, i will edit my response with an example

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Much appreciated. 

Can you tell me the difference between `var a = { }; and var a = [];` ?

Answer (score 0):

`uniq_ndes` looks like a multi-dimensional array. This line:

```
id[id.length] = uniq_ndes[x]['data']['id'];
```

appears to be assigning the contents of a location in `uniq_ndes` to a location in the `id` array.

See similar question here: [JavaScript multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array), or just google "javascript multi-dimensioal array".